# What does 'const static' mean in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c

```
const static int foo = 42;
```

I saw this in some code here on StackOverflow and I couldn't figure out what it does. Then I saw some confused answers on other forums. My best guess is that it's used in C to hide the constant `foo` from other modules. Is this correct? If so, why would anyone use it in a C++ context where you can just make it `private`?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

It has uses in both C and C++.

As you guessed, the `static` part limits its scope to that [compilation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c). It also provides for static initialization. `const` just tells the compiler to not let anybody modify it. This variable is either put in the data or bss segment depending on the architecture, and might be in memory marked read-only.

All that is how C treats these variables (or how C++ treats namespace variables). In C++, a member marked `static` is shared by all instances of a given class. Whether it's private or not doesn't affect the fact that one variable is shared by multiple instances. Having `const` on there will warn you if any code would try to modify that.

If it was strictly private, then each instance of the class would get its own version (optimizer notwithstanding).

Comment: The original example is talking about a "private variable".  Therefore, this is a mebmer and static has *no* affect on the linkage.  You should remove "the static part limits it's scope to that file".

Comment: The "special section" is known as the data segment, which it shares with all the other global variables, such as explicit "strings" and global arrays.  This is opposing to the code segment.

Comment: @Richard - what makes you think it's a member of a class? There's nothing in the question that says it is. *If* it's a member of a class, then you're right, but if it's just a variable declared at global scope, then Chris is right.

Comment: The original poster mentioned private as a possible better solution, but not as the original problem.

Comment: @Graeme, OK so it's not "definitely" a member - however, this answer is making statements which only apply to namespace members and those statements are wrong for members variables.  Given the amount of votes that error may confuse someone not very familiar with the language - it should be fixed.

Comment: @Richard, I concur, and updated it based on your concerns. I'm a C programmer, and wasn't thinking about the meaning in Object scope.

Answer (score 263):

A lot of people gave the basic answer but nobody pointed out that in C++ `const` defaults to `static` at `namespace` level (and some gave wrong information). See the C++98 standard section 3.5.3.

First some background:

*Translation unit:* A source file after the pre-processor (recursively) included all its include files.

*Static linkage:* A symbol is only available within its translation unit.

*External linkage:* A symbol is available from other translation units.

#### At `namespace` level

*This includes the global namespace aka global variables*.

```
static const int sci = 0; // sci is explicitly static
const int ci = 1;         // ci is implicitly static
extern const int eci = 2; // eci is explicitly extern
extern int ei = 3;        // ei is explicitly extern
int i = 4;                // i is implicitly extern
static int si = 5;        // si is explicitly static
```

#### At function level

`static` means the value is maintained between function calls.
The semantics of function `static` variables is similar to global variables in that they reside in the [program's data-segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93039/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-cc) (and not the stack or the heap), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246564) for more details about `static` variables' lifetime.

#### At `class` level

`static` means the value is shared between all instances of the class and `const` means it doesn't change.

Comment: At function level: static is not reduntant with const, they can behave differently `const int *foo(int x) {const int b=x;return &b};` versus `const int *foo(int x) {static const int b=x;return &b};`

Comment: The question is about both C and C++ so you should include a note about `const` only implying `static` in the latter.

Comment: @Motti: Great answer. Could you please explain what makes what redundant on a function level? Are you saying `const` declaration implies `static` there as well? As in, if you cast `const` away, and modify the value, all values will be modified?

Comment: @Cookie, I'm not sure if `const` implies `static` at function level but, in any case, casting away the `const` is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) so it doesn't matter how the program behaves after you do so :)

Comment: Hmm... So not quite redundant in that case either then. I am just wondering whether to no longer write `static const` on a function level, but I think I'll continue. Makes it clearer I think.

Comment: @Motti `const` doesn't imply static at the function level, that would be a concurrency nightmare (const != constant expression), everything at the function level is implicitly `auto`. Since this question is tagged [c] as well, I should mention that a global level `const int` is implicitly `extern` in C. The rules you have here perfectly describe C++, however.

Comment: @RyanHaining, do you have a reference for function level consts not implying static? Is there a semantic difference between a static and non-static const?

Comment: I don't know where it is in the standard but that's the behaviour I've observed (I'll have a look later). Non-static const has the typical extern linkage semantics (visible from another TU)

Comment: @RyanHaining but function level variables are never visible from other TUs anyway, right?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. If you had something like `void f(const char *str) { const size_t len = strlen(str); }` having `len` be static would make `f` not thread safe

Comment: @RyanHaining, do'h of course you're right, I'll update my answer

Comment: And in C++, in all three cases, `static` indicates that the variable is static duration (only one copy exists, which lasts from the program's beginning until its end), and has internal/static linkage if not otherwise specified (this is overridden by the function's linkage for local static variables, or the class' linkage for static members).  The main differences are in what this implies in each situation where `static` is valid.

Answer (score 45):

That line of code can actually appear in several different contexts and alghough it behaves approximately the same, there are small differences.

## Namespace Scope

```
// foo.h
static const int i = 0;
```

'`i`' will be visible in every translation unit that includes the header.  However, unless you actually use the address of the object (for example. '`&i`'), I'm pretty sure that the compiler will treat '`i`' simply as a type safe `0`.  Where two more more translation units take the '`&i`' then the address will be different for each translation unit.

```
// foo.cc
static const int i = 0;
```

'`i`' has internal linkage, and so cannot be referred to from outside of this translation unit.  However, again unless you use its address it will most likely be treated as a type-safe `0`.

One thing worth pointing out, is that the following declaration:

```
const int i1 = 0;
```

is **exactly** the same as `static const int i = 0`.  A variable in a namespace declared with `const` and not explicitly declared with `extern` is implicitly static.  If you think about this, it was the intention of the C++ committee to allow `const` variables to be declared in header files without always needing the `static` keyword to avoid breaking the ODR.

## Class Scope

```
class A {
public:
  static const int i = 0;
};
```

In the above example, the standard explicitly specifies that '`i`' does not need to be defined if its address is not required. In other words if you only use '`i`' as a type-safe 0 then the compiler will not define it.  One difference between the class and namespace versions is that the address of '`i`' (if used in two ore more translation units) will be the same for the class member.  Where the address is used, you must have a definition for it:

```
// a.h
class A {
public:
  static const int i = 0;
};

// a.cc
#include "a.h"
const int A::i;            // Definition so that we can take the address
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that static const is same as just const in namespace scope.

Comment: There is actually no difference between placing in "foo.h" or in "foo.cc" since .h is simply included when compiling translation unit.

Comment: @Mikhail:  You're correct.  There is an assumption that a header can be included in multiple TUs and so it was useful to talk about that separately.

Answer (score 30):

It's a small space optimization.

When you say

```
const int foo = 42;
```

You're not defining a constant, but creating a read-only variable. The compiler is smart enough to use 42 whenever it sees foo, but it will also allocate space in the initialized data area for it. This is done because, as defined, foo has external linkage. Another compilation unit can say:

extern const int foo;

To get access to its value. That's not a good practice since that compilation unit has no idea what the value of foo is. It just knows it's a const int and has to reload the value from memory whenever it is used.

Now, by declaring that it is static:

```
static const int foo = 42;
```

The compiler can do its usual optimization, but it can also say "hey, nobody outside this compilation unit can see foo and I know it's always 42 so there is no need to allocate any space for it."

I should also note that in C++, the preferred way to prevent names from escaping the current compilation unit is to use an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace {
    const int foo = 42; // same as static definition above
}
```

Comment: ,u mentioned without using static "it will also allocate space in the initialized data area for it". and by using static "no need to allocate any space for it".(from where the compiler is picking the val then ?)
can you explain in term of heap and stack where the variable is getting stored .Correct me if I am interpretting it wrong .

Comment: @N.Nihar - The static data area is a fixed size chunk of memory which contains all data which has static linkage. It's "allocated" by the process of loading the program into memory. It's not part of the stack or heap.

Comment: What happens if I have a function return a pointer to foo? Does that break the optimization?

Comment: @nw: Yes, it would have to.

Comment: In c++ const values have internal linkage as well and can be used in headers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/const-cpp?view=msvc-170. After some experimentation it seems that there is not much difference with or without static but the const is essential to get the compiler using the direct value.

Answer (score 10):

It's missing an 'int'.  It should be:

```
const static int foo = 42;
```

In C and C++, it declares an integer constant with local file scope of value 42.

Why 42?  If you don't already know (and it's hard to believe you don't), it's a refernce to the [**Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_to_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything).

Comment: Thanks... now everytime... for the rest of my life...when I see 42, I will always thing about this. haha

Comment: This is proof-positive that the universe was created by being with 13 fingers (the question and answer actually match in base 13).

Comment: Its the mice.  3 toes on each foot, plus a tail gives you base 13.

Comment: You don't actually need the 'int' in a declaration, though it's definitely good taste to write it out.  C always assumes 'int' types by default.  Try it!

Comment: "with local file scope of value 42" ?? or is it for the whole compilation unit?

Answer (score 9):

**C++17 `inline` variables**

If you Googled "C++ const static", then this is very likely what you really want to use are [C++17 inline variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline).

This awesome C++17 feature allow us to:

- conveniently use just a single memory address for each constant
- store it as a `constexpr`: [How to declare constexpr extern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208685/how-to-declare-constexpr-extern)
- do it in a single line from one header

main.cpp

```
#include <cassert>

#include "notmain.hpp"

int main() {
    // Both files see the same memory address.
    assert(&notmain_i == notmain_func());
    assert(notmain_i == 42);
}
```

notmain.hpp

```
#ifndef NOTMAIN_HPP
#define NOTMAIN_HPP

inline constexpr int notmain_i = 42;

const int* notmain_func();

#endif
```

notmain.cpp

```
#include "notmain.hpp"

const int* notmain_func() {
    return &notmain_i;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -c -o notmain.o -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic notmain.cpp
g++ -c -o main.o -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp
g++ -o main -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.o notmain.o
./main
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/tree/085c4b22b1b290a6d033a44958d05054e7e303c7/cpp/inline_variable).

See also: [How do inline variables work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work)

**C++ standard on inline variables**

The C++ standard guarantees that the addresses will be the same. [C++17 N4659 standard draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4659.pdf) 
10.1.6 "The inline specifier":

> 6 An inline function or variable with external linkage shall have the same address in all translation units.

cppreference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline explains that if `static` is not given, then it has external linkage.

**GCC inline variable implementation**

We can observe how it is implemented with:

```
nm main.o notmain.o
```

which contains:

```
main.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U _Z12notmain_funcv
0000000000000028 r _ZZ4mainE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
                 U __assert_fail
0000000000000000 T main
0000000000000000 u notmain_i

notmain.o:
0000000000000000 T _Z12notmain_funcv
0000000000000000 u notmain_i
```

and `man nm` says about `u`:

> "u" The symbol is a unique global symbol.  This is a GNU extension to the standard set of ELF symbol bindings.  For such a symbol the dynamic linker will make sure that in the entire process
>                  there is just one symbol with this name and type in use.

so we see that there is a dedicated ELF extension for this.

**Pre-C++ 17: `extern const`**

Before C++ 17, and in C, we can achieve a very similar effect with an `extern const`, which will lead to a single memory location being used.

The downsides over `inline` are:

- it is not possible to make the variable `constexpr` with this technique, only `inline` allows that: [How to declare constexpr extern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208685/how-to-declare-constexpr-extern)
- it is less elegant as you have to declare and define the variable separately in the header and cpp file

main.cpp

```
#include <cassert>

#include "notmain.hpp"

int main() {
    // Both files see the same memory address.
    assert(&notmain_i == notmain_func());
    assert(notmain_i == 42);
}
```

notmain.cpp

```
#include "notmain.hpp"

const int notmain_i = 42;

const int* notmain_func() {
    return &notmain_i;
}
```

notmain.hpp

```
#ifndef NOTMAIN_HPP
#define NOTMAIN_HPP

extern const int notmain_i;

const int* notmain_func();

#endif
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/tree/085c4b22b1b290a6d033a44958d05054e7e303c7/cpp/extern_const).

**Pre-C++17 header only alternatives**

These are not as good as the `extern` solution, but they work and only take up a single memory location:

A `constexpr` function, because [`constexpr` implies `inline`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391272/does-constexpr-imply-inline) and `inline` [allows (forces) the definition to appear on every translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517546/how-can-a-c-header-file-include-implementation):

```
constexpr int shared_inline_constexpr() { return 42; }
```

and I bet that any decent compiler will inline the call.

You can also use a `const` or `constexpr` static variable as in:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass {
    static constexpr int i = 42;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << MyClass::i << std::endl;
    // undefined reference to `MyClass::i'
    //std::cout << &MyClass::i << std::endl;
}
```

but you can't do things like taking its address, or else it becomes odr-used, see also: [Defining constexpr static data members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109036/defining-constexpr-static-data-members/50111847#50111847)

**C**

In C the situation is the same as C++ pre C++ 17, I've uploaded an example at: [What does "static" mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-c/14339047#14339047)

The only difference is that in C++, `const` implies `static` for globals, but it does not in C: [C++ semantics of `static const` vs `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709207/c-semantics-of-static-const-vs-const/54377560#54377560)

**Any way to fully inline it?**

TODO: is there any way to fully inline the variable, without using any memory at all?

Much like what the preprocessor does.

This would require somehow:

- forbidding or detecting if the address of the variable is taken
- add that information to the ELF object files, and let LTO optimize it up

Related:

- [C++11 enum with class members and constexpr link-time optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090583/c11-enum-with-class-members-and-constexpr-link-time-optimization)

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10, GCC 8.2.0.

Answer (score 6):

According to C99/GNU99 specification:

- `static`

  - is storage-class specifier
  - objects of file level scope by default has **external** linkage
  - objects of file level scope with static specifier has **internal** linkage
- `const`

  - is type-qualifier (is a part of type)
  - keyword applied to immediate left instance - i.e.

    - `MyObj const * myVar;` - unqualified pointer to const qualified object type
    - `MyObj * const myVar;` - const qualified pointer to unqualified object type
  - Leftmost usage - applied to the object type, not variable

    - `const MyObj * myVar;` - unqualified pointer to const qualified object type

**THUS:**

`static NSString * const myVar;` - constant pointer to immutable string with internal linkage.

Absence of the `static` keyword will make variable name global and might lead to name conflicts within the application.

Answer (score 4):

In C++,

```
static const int foo = 42;
```

is the preferred way to define & use constants. I.e. use this rather than

```
#define foo 42
```

because it doesn't subvert the type-safety system.

Answer (score 4):

To all the great answers, I want to add a small detail:

If You write plugins (e.g. DLLs or .so libraries to be loaded by a CAD system), then *static* is a life saver that avoids name collisions like this one:

1. The CAD system loads a plugin A, which has a "const int foo = 42;" in it.
2. The system loads a plugin B, which has "const int foo = 23;" in it.
3. As a result, plugin B will use the value 42 for foo, because the plugin loader will realize, that there is already a "foo" with external linkage.

Even worse: Step 3 may behave differently depending on compiler optimization, plugin load mechanism, etc.

I had this issue once with two helper functions (same name, different behaviour) in two plugins. Declaring them static solved the problem.

Comment: Something seemed odd about the name collisions between the two plug-ins, which led me to examine the link map for one of my many DLLs that defines m_hDfltHeap as a handle with external linkage. Sure enough, there it is for all the world to see and use, listed in the linkage map as _m_hDfltHeap. I'd forgotten all about this factoid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it hides a variable in a module from other modules. In C++, I use it when I don't want/need to change a .h file that will trigger an unnecessary rebuild of other files. Also, I put the static first:

```
static const int foo = 42;
```

Also, depending on its use, the compiler won't even allocate storage for it and simply "inline" the value where it's used. Without the static, the compiler can't assume it's not being used elsewhere and can't inline.

Answer (score 2):

This ia s global constant visible/accessible only in the compilation module (.cpp file). BTW using static for this purpose is deprecated. Better use an anonymous namespace and an enum:

```
namespace
{
  enum
  {
     foo = 42
  };
}
```

Comment: this would force the compiler to not treat foo as a constant and as such hinders optimization.

Comment: enums values are always constant so I don't see how this will hinder any optimizations

Comment: ah - true.. my error. thought you've used a simple int-variable.

Comment: Roskoto, I'm not clear what benefit the `enum` has in this context. Care to elaborate? Such `enums` are usually only used to prevent the compiler from allocating any space for the value (though modern compilers don't need this `enum` hack for it) and to prevent the creation of pointers to the value.

Comment: Konrad, What exactly problem you see in using an enum in this case? Enums are used when you need constant ints which is exactly the case.

Comment: How is using static in this way 'deprecated'?  I would definitely prefer the example in the question over doing it with an enum.  Also, this way only works for integer values.

Comment: ok, look like we have to separate the arguments on two:
1) using anonymous namespace instead of static
2) enum vs const int

My answers:
1) http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=261
2) jonner, what is the problem to use an enum in this case?

Comment: Doh - otherway round...deprecated for objects, not functions.

Comment: Roskoto, it's not a problem exactly, it just doesn't semantically match what I'm trying to do.  I'm not creating an enumeration, i'm creating a single named constant.  Also, I can't use the same method for floats, so I'd rather be consistent and just use `static const` in both cases.

Comment: the static has nothing to do with the const thing. You can always have: 
namespace
{
  const float foo = 42.0;
}

Comment: You asked about the problem with enum, not static. In any case, an anonymous namespace is not exactly equivalent to static.  It makes the name inaccessible to other translation units, but I believe a variable in an anonymous namespace still has external linkage.

Comment: Of course they are not equivalent that's why static is deprecated in favor of anonymous namespaces. And yes they have external linkage but with a random name assigned from the compiler so you can never guess or match it incidentally.

Comment: @Roskoto Static has been UN depreciated for several years now; might want to fix your answer. Anonymous namespaces are complementary to static, not a full replacement for it.

Answer (score 1):

Making it private would still mean it appears in the header. I tend to use "the weakest" way that works. See this classic article by Scott Meyers: http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401197 (it's about functions, but can be applied here as well).