# Design a class/type with only 1 possible instance - C++

Tags: c++, class, types

I would like to have a `class T` that can generate only 1 instance in the whole program.

Now i know about `std::unique_ptr` but there are 2 problems:

- it's limited to a scope ( but it's not a big issue ... )
- it needs to be explicitly used, meaning that it's not part of the class or the type, it's just and handler and a special pointer, but it does not modify the design of my class.

now i would like to have `class T` designed in a way that not even by mistake the user can declare 2 instances in the same program and i can't rely on the fact that my user will declare an `std::unique_ptr` for `T` because i want to solve this by design.

right now i'm only thinking about how to make an implicit use of an `unique_ptr` in an elegant way, the problem is that i do not have any clue at the moment.

the other way around is to check if this class is handled by an `unique_ptr` but this check will make me lose an edge in terms of performances.

since having only 1 instance is really important, i see only 2 options in my case: 1) trying to solve this by design 2) throwing errors at compile time with some sort of check/macro.

I know that this looks trivial but with a design approach it's not, at least for me, so please help.

Comment: The word you look for is `singleton`.

Comment: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Singleton.html

Comment: You are looking for singleton, but probably more proper and modern way would be to use static class (as in: class with only static members) or just namespace.

Comment: Why do you want just *one* object of that type? What would be the problem with having multiple ones?

Comment: @Xeo it's an object that will contain vital settings for the app, it must be unique to avoid runtime errors or user frustration when dealing with multiple objects for the same settings.

Comment: @Xeo:  The question of why having multiple instances is bad is not the important question.  There are many legitimate reasons why an app should never have more than once instance of certain types of objects.  For example, expensive resources, connections, etc.  The *real* question is:  why should you have to reply on engineering tricks to ensure your clients don't do stupid stuff?

Comment: @JohnDibling, there are no; if the class shouldn't have more than *one* instance, it should have *no* instances and you would get the same functionality with less ugly syntax (something::get_singleton()->do_something() vs something::do_something(); I prefer the latter).

Comment: 1275 possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+singleton

Comment: @Griwes:  I don't rightly understand what you're saying.

Comment: @JohnDibling, read also my previous comment.

Comment: @Griwes:  Ah, I see.  Yes, valid point.  Yet another reason why a Singleton is an anti-pattern.  Just to play Devil's Advocate though, it's possible that one would need RAII type functionality that doesn't rely on calling a `disconnect()` type method at shut-down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern, and while it is widely considered by many (myself included) to be an [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern), I will nonetheless show you the basic elements needed to build one.

Basically what you need to do is provide three things:

1. A `static` method which "gets" the one and only instance
2. A `private` constructor, so that nobody can ever instantiate it
3. (optional) A means by which the one and only instance is created before `main` starts

Here's the essential code:

```
class Singleton
{
public:
  Singleton&  get() 
  { 
    static Singleton me_;
    return me_;
  }
private:
  Singleton() {};
};
```

I leave it to you to discover how to implement #3 above, and why you shouldn't be using a Singleton in the first place -- there are many reasons.

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about caring when the only instance gets created, and since singleton also does not care when the creation occurs, only that it must occur before it is given to anyone, I don't see why you put #3 in your list at all...

Comment: The explicit conditional and dynamic allocation is a bit silly. You get the exact same behaviour from a `static` variable (including thread-safety).

Comment: @Cdaragorn:  Completeness.  Keep in mind that my answer isn't just for the benfit of the person who asked the question, but for all future visitors as well.

Comment: I was thinking of a block-static variable actually, because that also gives you definite initialization order.

Comment: static Singleton me_; is not allowed in header file as per MISRA C++ rules. We need to use below solution in this case.

Answer (score 3):

This is typically referred to as a Singleton.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

The typical trick in C++ is to have a function which returns the singleton instance by reference, and make the constructor private.

Something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
private:
  Foo() : a(3) { a++; }
  static Foo singleton;
  int a;
public:
  static Foo& getFoo() { return singleton; }
  void doStuff() { cout<<"My a is: "<<a<<endl; }
};

Foo Foo::singleton;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Foo::getFoo().doStuff();
  Foo &foo = Foo::getFoo();
  foo.doStuff();

  //uncomment below to cause compile error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  //Foo foo2;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

Note that in real code you'll split this up into a header and a cpp file.  In that case the

```
Foo Foo::singleton;
```

part must go in the cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

You could have at least

```
 static int count;
 assert(count == 0);
 count++;
```

in the constructor(s) of the singleton class. This don't ensure at compile time that your class is singleton, but at least it checks that at runtime.

And you could also make the constructor private, and have a static member function returning (once) a pointer to your instance, perhaps something like

```
 class Singleton {
 private:
    Singleton() {
      static int count;
      assert(count == 0);
      count++;
    };
    Singleton(Singleton&) = delete;
 public:
    static Singleton* the_instance() {
      static Singleton* it;
      if (!it) it = new Singleton();
      return it;
    }
 };
```

Comment: so you are going for the runtime check basically ? The problem is that after an X amount of time spent with your compiler, if your code will not work you probably will be pissed off with the creator of the library ...

Comment: you should disable default copy constructors and alike as well. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/271104/1025391