# Passing constructor to shared pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Thanks to anyone willing to help:

I am trying to create a Singleton class in C++ and I am new to the language. My scrum team methods say we should only use shared pointers. However, when I am trying to pass constructor into my Singleton object (shared pointer) I am getting error such as "binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right hand operand...". Basically non-compatible type conversion. Providing necessary code below:

```
//Singleton getter class
std::shared_ptr<LibMouse3d::LibCoreMouse3d::DeviceHandle> LibMouse3d::LibCoreMouse3d::DeviceHandle::getInstance(){

    if(device == NULL){

        //trying pass constructor into shared pointer object
        device = LibMouse3d::LibCoreMouse3d::DeviceHandle();
    }

    return device;
}
```

This is my constructor:

```
LibMouse3d::LibCoreMouse3d::DeviceHandle::DeviceHandle() {

    this->InitDevice();
}
```

And the object in header file

```
//singleton object - device
std::shared_ptr<DeviceHandle> device;
```

Thanks for any effort and sorry if I forgot something or added non-relevant info. This is my first question here, I could not google myself into answer for some time and I don't want my scrum master to be worried about my progress.

Comment: Well, if it's a _singleton_ you don't ever need to have a _shared_ pointer

Comment: Think of a singleton as a global variable with a delayed construction.

Comment: Withholding my opinion on the use of `shared_ptr`, you should not be using `NULL`. Use `nullptr` if you need a null value, but with smart pointers (and raw pointers), `if (!device)` is fine.

Comment: This should probably return `weak_ptr` rather than `shared_ptr`.  Or use `unique_ptr` and return reference.

Comment: [Singleton does not require pointers.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/271104/315052)

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing the constructor. In fact, there is currently no way to pass a constructor in C++. You're assigning a temporary `DeviceHandle` object to `device`. However, [some documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D) makes it apparent that there is no assignment operator taking a `T`. For that matter, it also doesn't have an assignment operator that would take a function-like thing (like a constructor).

Instead, smart pointers have `reset`:

```
device.reset(new DeviceHandle());
```