# Use of deleted copy constructor in the singleton

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton, c++14

I've implemented the singleton pattern like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270947/can-any-one-provide-me-a-sample-of-singleton-in-c/271104#271104), there is my code:

**header file:**

```
class Settings_manager{
public:
    static Settings_manager& get_instance();

    void operator=(Settings_manager const&) =delete;
    Settings_manager(Settings_manager const&) =delete;
...

private:
    Settings_manager();
};
```

**implementation:**

```
Settings_manager& Settings_manager::get_instance()
{
    static Settings_manager instance;
    return instance;
}

Settings_manager::Settings_manager()
{
    read_file();
}
```

When I try use `get_instance` function in `main` like this:

```
Settings_manager set = Settings_manager::get_instance();
```

or `Settings_manager set = std::move(Settings_manager::get_instance());`

I get

```
error: use of deleted function 'Settings_manager::Settings_manager(const Settings_manager&)'
 Settings_manager set = Settings_manager::get_instance();
```

Can somebody tell, what's wrong and explain it? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider what you're trying to do here:

```
Settings_manager set = Settings_manager::get_instance();
```

You have your singleton, `get_instance()`, and you're trying to copy it? That would kind of defeat the purpose of singleton if you could just... create two of them right?

You want to take a *reference*:

```
Settings_manager& set = Settings_manager::get_instance();
```

This way, `set` *is* the singleton instance. Not a copy of it.

Answer (score 6):

`get_instance` returns a reference to your singleton, which you then store in a local `Settings_manager` variable, which needs to make a copy.  `set` should be a reference variable:

```
Settings_manager &set = Settings_manager::get_instance();
```