# Namespace or class with one member?

Tags: c++, class, oop, namespaces, encapsulation

I'm making a small game in the console and have come across a small problem. Let's say I have a class named `Canvas`:

**canvas.h**

```cpp
class Canvas final {

public:
  // Constructor
  Canvas(unsigned width = 10, unsigned height = 30);

  unsigned outerWidth, outerHeight;

}
```

**canvas.cpp**

```cpp
#include "canvas.h"

Canvas::Canvas(unsigned width, unsigned height) {
  outerWidth = width;
  outerHeight = height;

  // I draw a box (canvas)'s border here
}
```

Now in the `main.cpp` file I declare an instance of the class:

```cpp
#include "canvas.h"

// The program starts here
int main() {
  Canvas myCanvas;
  return 0;
}
```

First of all, I would like to only have 1 member of the `Canvas` class, because that's how my program is designed to be. However, when I make an instance of that class, it gets a name (`myCanvas` in this example). Then if I want another class (let's say, `Entity`) that uses the canvas, I have to say `myCanvas.outerWidth`, which is dependent on the object's name. Also, I don't think the `myCanvas` variable would be available in the scope of such class anyway.

On the other hand, when I use namespaces, I lose some benefits of using classes (encapsulation (private properties), constructors). So what do I do? Make a static class or namespace or what? I've heard that there isn't a thing called a static class in C++; there are only static properties or methods. I guess putting the `static` keyword everywhere isn't good practice. Or is it?

Comment: Create a header file, don't use `class`, use a `namespace` and in addition use an anonymous namespace to make things that you want to be `private` have internal linkage.

Comment: If you need only one instance of a `class`, you can use [singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270947/can-any-one-provide-me-a-sample-of-singleton-in-c/271104#271104).

Comment: When you want to use `myCanvas` object in scopes other than `main` you should pass a reference to this object there. There is no need to pop global or static member variables all of it sudden.

Comment: @VTT Yeah but  I don't like passing a variable to every function I use with the canvas

Comment: @mrazimi consider some examples of using `static` methods from singleton class implenentation. Do they remind you of something? Yes, the syntax is **exactly the same** as one used when you use namespaces rather than classes. Thus I believe one should not use singleton classes at all in C++, but rather  use namespaces if the singleton-like behaviour is desired.

Comment: @Fureeish No, syntax is not the same. In-class declarations allow different access control levels. Also singleton is still a singleton regardless of whether it employs free functions or member functions of some class.

Comment: @VTT I should've specified that I was referring to calling syntax. And they are the same, essentially.

Comment: Yeah but how do I make a readonly variable inside a namespace (read access outside of file, read & write access inside file)? I need to make a constant `width` variable that can be only inititialized once. I don't see any simple way to do that using namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a single instance (i guess you want a single instance, not a single member, as a member is one of the component fields of the class, and as such, your class has two member fields now)  you are probably talking about the **singleton pattern** (a class with only one instance and no means to instantiate another).

Just declare the constructor `private` or `protected`, so client code cannot make a second instance of that object.  In that case, you can only use instances already generated for client code, and client code cannot get a new instance (by means of `new` operator or declaring an instance in `main()` as you do).

```
class Canvas final {

  // Constructor now is private
  Canvas(unsigned width = 10, unsigned height = 30);

public:
  unsigned outerWidth, outerHeight;

}
```

I'd recommend you also to declare `outerWidth` and `outerHeight` as `const` if they are to be exposed publicly by the class, so you cannot modify them (making the instance immutable) or declare accessor methods to access those fields and declare  a `public` and `static` field `instance` (or `theCanvas`), as in:

```
class Canvas final {

  // Constructor
  Canvas(unsigned width = 10, unsigned height = 30);

public:
  unsigned outerWidth, outerHeight;
  static Canvas instance;  // we have a static instance defined elsewhere

}
```

you can instantiate it in a `.cc` file with:

```
#include <canvas.h>
...
Canvas Canvas::instance;  // by default 10 by 10, this is the public available instance declared above.
...
```

in this way, you can use `Canvas::instance` everywhere, that will be an instance of your `Canvas` class.  It will be visible from any source that includes the `"canvas.h"` include file, and not only in your `main()` routine, as it is in the sample snippet you post.

By the way, there's no much sense in declaring a constructor with parameters if you are only using it once and in your private code.   Also no need to declare default parameter values, but you are in your way.  You decide.

## Note

As it is not fully clear what you are attempting, I could have misunderstood your intentions, so please, don't blame me if this is not what you want, and edit your question to make your target clearer.  You have declared `outerWidth` and `outerHeight` as non-`const` and so, they are modifiable by any code that has access to them. It's not clear if you want your instance immutable (not modifiable once it has been instantiated) nor if they have to take their values from some external code.

Comment: About the outerWidth and outerHeight variables, I want them to be constant but declared later (when drawing the canvas in the constructor). Is there a way to do that? Also, about the constructor, in the main function I would like to specify the width and height and then copy them in a class method to the outerWidth and outerHeight variables. Basically I want all (or most) of the Canvas properties not modifiable from the outside but defined in the Canvas::draw() function as constants or something

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I think it's gonna work. I'll mark this answer correct anyway

Comment: I'm sorry, but as you posted only partial code, it has been impossible for me to supply the missing code, without also incurring in misinterpreting your intentions... next time post a complete and verifiable example, and so the answer will be.