# Destructor for static fields. Singleton realization

Tags: c++, design-patterns, static, singleton

So, classic simple Singleton realization is following:

```
class Singleton
{
private:
    static Singleton* singleton;
    Singleton() {}
public:
    static Singleton* getInstance();        
};
```

**cpp-file**:

```
Singleton* Singleton::singleton = 0;

Singleton* Singleton::getInstance()
{
    if (!singleton)
    {
        singleton = new Singleton;
    }

    return singleton;
}
```

I see memory leak here - 'cos there is no *delete* for the *new*. But in C++ there isn't static destructor, so we just don't care about this memory leak?

Comment: Singletons are expected to be useful for the whole life of the program.

Comment: See [C++ Singleton design pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern) (or just search for singleton on SO, you will find a lot of info)

Comment: This looks as rewritten Singleton implementation in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx But in C# "new" does not require "delete".

Comment: @SChepurin This example is from GoF book

Comment: @Hate.Nothing's perfect. There is a lot to be discussed about Singleton's deletion "How does a Singleton ever get deleted?": http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/to_kill_a_singleton

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A memory leak is more than just an allocation with no matching free.  It's when you have memory that could be reclaimed because the object is no longer in use, but which doesn't ever actually get freed.  In fact, many memory leaks are cases where there is code in the program to deallocate memory, but for whatever reason it doesn't get called (for example, a reference cycle).  There's a lot of research on how to detect these sorts of leaks; **[this paper](http://www.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs295/cs295.1086/papers/p156-hauswirth.pdf)** is an excellent example of one such tool.

In the case of a singleton, we don't have a leak because that singleton exists throughout the program.  Its lifetime is never intended to end, and so the memory not getting reclaimed isn't a problem.

That said, the code you have above is not how most people would implement a singleton.  The canonical C++ implementation would be something like this:

```
class Singleton
{
private:
    /* No instantiation. */
    Singleton() {}

    /* Explicitly disallow copying. */ 
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator= (const Singleton&) = delete;

    /* In C++03, the above would be written as
     *
     *    Singleton(const Singleton&);
     *    Singleton& operator= (const Singleton&);
     * 
     * and you'd just leave the methods unimplemented.
     */
public:
    static Singleton& getInstance();        
};
```

.cpp file:

```
Singleton& Singleton::getInstance() {
    /* Have a static local variable representing the unique instance.  Since
     * it's static, there is only one instance of this variable.  It's also only
     * initialized when getInstance is called.
     */
    static Singleton theInstance;
    return theInstance;
}
```

Now there's no dynamic allocation at all - the memory is allocated by the compiler and probably resides in the code or data segment rather than in the heap.  Also note that you have to explicitly disallow copying, or otherwise you could end up with many clones of the singleton.

The other advantage of this is that C++ guarantees that at program exit (assuming the program terminates normally), the destructor for `theInstance` will indeed fire at the end of the program.  You can thus define a destructor with all the cleanup code you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: what is = delete; and aren't you declaring new static theInstance every time you call the getInstance()?

Comment: @Hate- `= delete;` is a new C++11 syntax for explicitly marking that a function does not exist and cannot be called.  In C++03, you'd just declare these functions but not implement them.  Also, the reason you don't get a new copy of the instance each time is that the local variable is marked `static`, which means that only one copy of this variable exists and it persists across function invocations.  Does that answer your question?  Or is there something else I can clarify?

Comment: I see that  static Singleton theInstance; create static variable, and I know that static vars exits all the time program run. But when you call this function for second time, won't it be willing on creating new static variable theInstance and it will be no redefinition error?

Comment: @Hate- Nope.  Static local variables are similar to static global variables in that only one copy actually exists.  If you call the function multiple times, it always refers to the same static local variable.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246564/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-static-variable-in-a-c-function for more details.

Comment: when I write in main class Test {}; static Test test; static Test test; it gets me an error of test redefinition..

Comment: That's correct - there's a difference between creating two different static global variables and having just one static local variable invoked twice.  One is at a syntactic level and is illegal, while the other is a consequence of the runtime.

Comment: I don't get why it happens so, why there is no redefinition error when it's static Singleton theInstance; in function that is called many times and it is an error when this line is several time in function that is called once..

Comment: A redefinition error is a *syntactic* issue - you cannot declare the same variable twice.  There is no redefinition in this case because there is just one definition.  Calling a function with a static variable does not constitute a definition.  Try writing this code for yourself to see what I mean - it should take about five minutes and will hopefully clear up the distinction.

Comment: I wrote it by myself, still it isn't all clear to me.. I always thought that such line is a definition and can be only one in program..

Comment: @templatetypedef - this sort of thinking makes it difficult to detect unwanted leaks because the "who cares" leaks create so much noise when running a program under tools with instrumentation.

Comment: @Hate: 1. Your function (getInstance) is called: theInstance is initialized, to 0 in this case. 2. Your function is called again: When we pass the "static Singleton theInstance;" line, it is not a new definition. It is the exact same definition we passed before. Definition and initialization of statics happens only once. You can consider the line skipped.
This is why statics are different from locals. All references to a static variable in the same scope refer to a single place in memory. You can not "redefine" any existing variable. Local variables refer to different memory per call.

Answer (score 4):

#### Why you should avoid such code, when there is no matching `delete` for `new`

While there is no actual *memory leak* (in most modern operating systems), worse thing is that your `Singleton` destructor doesn't get called. And if you acquire some resources, they propbably *would* leak.

#### What can be done here

Use smart pointer to store instance, consider `std::unique_ptr` (with C++11) or `boost::auto_ptr`

Comment: @Lol4t0- The version in my code is also lazily initialized; `static` local variables are only initialized when the function containing them is first called.

Comment: @templatetypedef, you defined it inside function, ok then.

Comment: @Lol4t0: You and templatetypedef gave two contradicting statements: you say that the Singleton destructor does not get called, whilst they say that the destructor gets fired when the program is finished.
Since this is exactly what I came here to find out, would you mind confirming or denying your statement?

Comment: @Larry: it depends on Singleton implementation. The implementation in the body of the question does not fire destructior, but templatetypedef's implementation does.

Comment: @Lol4t0 Thank you! So it seems dynamic memory is not destroyed, only deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

When a variable local to a function is declared "static", it means that it isn't allocated on the stack - and that its value persists from one call to the next.