# Question About Static Initialization Fiasco (Confusion in isocpp FAQ)

Tags: c++, static-initialization, static-order-fiasco

There is a great [FAQ(isocpp)](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) just demonstrates why we potentaily cannot we use static object instead of static pointer to avoid Fiasco problem. I came across a sentence in the answer that gave me a headache

> .... By changing the declaration from `static X* xp = new X();`
> to `static X xp;`, we still correctly handle the initialization
> situation but we no longer handle the deinitialization situation. For
> example, **if there are 3 static objects, say a, b and c, that use ans
> during their destructors, the only way to avoid a static
> deinitialization disaster is if `xp` is destructed after all three.**

**main.cpp**

```
#include "x.h" // struct X { X(int); void f(); };

X& x(int i) 
{  
  static X xp{ i }; 
  return xp; 
}
struct Y 
{ 
  Y(int); 
  private: int m_y; 
};
Y::Y(int i) { 
  x(i).f(); 
}
```

**other.cpp**

```
Y y{ 20 };

struct X { 
    X(int); 
    void f(); 
    private: int m_x; 
};
X::X(int j): m_x(j) {};

void X::f() { std::cout << m_x << std::endl; }
```

Then they continue with:

> **The point is simple: if there are any other static objects whose
> destructors might use `xp` after `xp` is destructed, bang, you’re dead.**

I just cannot understand how this problem can happen. I need a practical example that demonstrates how this problem can occur.

Comment: By definition, it is hard to provide a reproducible case of UB, as the exact results depends on the compile/linker. Can you alter the question to include the environment you are using?

Comment: The link to FAQ(isocpp) seems to be broken?

Comment: By using new the object never gets destructed since there is no matching delete call anywhere in the code. Which means the object "survives" in memory until the program terminates and its destructor gets never called. Still not what I'd want though.

Comment: This might also be an interesting read for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242063/destruction-order-of-meyers-singletons

Comment: Add `Y::~Y() {x(5).f();}` and now you've got a problem if the Y object gets destroyed after the X object has been destroyed :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, Can you answer the question? I can't get the destruction order in your case.  if I made this `Y::~Y() {x(5).f();}` Now which object is destroyed first?. I already know the destruction order is the inverse of the construction but I can't map this with my example.

Comment: @AccessDenied that's the problem -- destruction order of static-objects across compilation units isn't well-defined; it could happen in one order on one compiler, and a different order on another compiler.  Or in one order on Monday, and a different order on Tuesday.  You can't rely on any particular order being chosen.

Comment: Excuse me, bro. If I have, `Y::~Y() { auto xo = x(100) ; xo.f(); };`, Now the scope of `xo` ends once the control exits `Y::~Y()` and You said: "I will get a problem if object Y gets destroyed after object X which is `xo`" and that's not happening here, `xo` not yet destroyed, so where's the problem?

Comment: `x()` is returning a reference to the static object `xp`.  If `xp` has already been destroyed, then the returned reference is a reference-to-an-invalid object, and any attempt to use that reference invokes undefined behavior.  If (on your system, using your current compiler and current build settings) `xp` is getting destroyed after `~Y()` is called rather than before, that's just your luck (good or bad, depending on how you look at it); there's no guarantee it will happen in the same order on another system/compiler/day-of-the-week.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner. Great clarification, thanks bro I got it