# life time of a static variable in a function

Tags: c++, lifetime, static-variables

see the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct T
{
    ~T()
    {
        cout << "deconstructor calling\n";
    }
};
static T& get1()
{
    static T x;
    return x;
}
static T& get2()
{
    static T& x = *new T;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    get1();//calls the deconstructor 
    get2();  //dosent call the deconstructor 
}
```

why `get1` calls the deconstructor but `get2` doesn't? as far as I know the static variables destroy when you terminate the program ! but why after calling `get1` program calls the deconstrucor of the static variable?

I have a read similar the post at :

[What is the lifetime of a static variable in a C++ function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246564/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-static-variable-in-a-c-function)

somebody says there that :"The lifetime of function static variables begins the first time[0] the program flow encounters the declaration and it ends at program termination."

this doesn't seem to be true here!

Comment: Why would the second one ever call the destructor. It's created using new, with no corresponding delete. It's a memory leak! You are also assigning the newed object to a reference, meaning it's no longer possible to get it's address to call delete.

Answer (score 6):

`get1()` is not calling `~T()`. The simple way of proving it is calling `get1()` multiple times:

```
int main()
{
    get1();
    get1();
    get1();
    get2();  
    get2();  
    get2();  
}
```

The above code snippet will only display `"deconstructor calling"` once.

[**coliru example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0010c99597f2d024)

---

> why `get1` calls the deconstructor but `get2` doesn't?

The destructor call you're seeing happens at the end of the program, when the `static T x` defined in `get1()` gets destroyed.

The `x` defined in `get2()` does not get destroyed automatically because it is *heap-allocated*. You need to `delete` it or, better yet, use an `std::unique_ptr`.

[**coliru example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac6976326fa78dca)

---

BTW, the correct term is **"destructor"**.

Comment: by why it is calling the deconstructor only once? why get2 is not calling it?

Answer (score 3):

> why `get1` calls the deconstructor but `get2` doesn't?

Note the difference between `get1()` and `get2()`. The static variable in `get1()` is of type `T`, when it is destructed at program termination, the destructor of `T` will be invoked.

The static viariable in `get2()` is of type `T&` (i.e. a reference to `T`) and initialized from an object constructed via `new`. When it's destructed at program termination, the destructor of `T` won't be invoked. This is not special for static variable, it's true for local variable too. The destruction timings are different but the behaviors are same; the constructed object is leaked.