# C++ singleton - when is the destructor called?

Tags: c++, singleton

The following seems to be the recommended way to define a singleton in C++:

```
class Singleton {
private:

    Singleton();

public:
    static Singleton & get_instance() {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }

     ~Singleton() {
        // destructor
     }

    Singleton(Singleton const&) = delete;
    void operator=(Singleton const&) = delete;
}
```

Now, take this function:

```
void foo() {
   Singleton & s = Singleton::get_instance();
}
```

I expected the destructor to be called when the singleton instance goes out of scope in that function, but it's not. When does the destructor get called?

Comment: Why would a destructor be called here? You just created a reference which then got destroyed. References are not proper objects and don't have destructors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246564/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-static-variable-in-a-c-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the destructor won't be called since `get_instance()` returns a reference of the `Singleton` object, that reference is saved into `s`, another reference. Both of these references point to a static Singleton object, namely:

```
static Singleton instance;
```

So, there's only 1 object being worked on here, `instance`. Passing around references does not create new objects and thus does not invoke the destructor.

The object `instance` will be destroyed, and thus, it's destructor will get called at program termination (because it's `static`).

Comment: Specifically; the destructor will run after control flow leaves `main()` - but one should be aware that *order* of destruction is only well defined between statics within a single translation unit (see also: [What’s the “static initialization order fiasco”?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) since the same applies to order of destruction).  Singletons are *evil*.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to C++. Let's say I have that singleton inside a HTTP server. What kind of interrupt should I send to my process for the destructor to fire?