# Smart pointer in global scope

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have this smart pointer in top of my cpp file (Global variable):

```
std::unique_ptr<DATA_READ> smartPT(new DATA_READ);
```

What happens if smart pointer declares in global scope? I know smart pointer in a function automatically deletes and release memory after the function ends but How about Global Scope Smart Pointer which used in multiple functions?

Comment: A global smart pointer will release the memory at the end of the program. Very much like a non-smart, non-pointer global variable.

Comment: It will be destructed when the application exits - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246564/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-static-variable-in-a-c-function) for more details

Comment: It's destructor gets called after main() returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will release the allocated memory during the termination of the program. However, it is not a good idea to have smart pointer as global variable.

Answer (score 1):

The memory will remain allocated throughout the life of the program, unless specific action is taken to free the memory. Essentially it will be just as if the scope for the smart pointer is the scope of the function 'main()'. Here is from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/)

> unique_ptr objects automatically delete the object they manage (using a deleter) as soon as they themselves are destroyed, or as soon as their value changes either by an assignment operation or by an explicit call to unique_ptr::reset.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a variable with static duration, the memory will be allocated when this code is loaded, usually that will be on start of your application and freed, when the application finishes.
If you use it in functions it should generally be allocated, unless it has been reset in another function.

Obviously there are some ramifications considering dynamically loaded libraries.

Comment: where it has been told that it is a static variable?

Comment: I'm sorry, you are correct, my answer was Not precise. The variable is not static, but it does have static duration.

Answer (score 0):

The smart pointer will be destroyed at the end of the program as all other objects. So when the destructor is called the pointer will be deleted. Here you get an example which is *not even close* to a real smart pointer, but it gives the idea:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct example {
    T* p_;
    example(T* p): p_{p} {
        cout << "example(T* p)\n";
    }
    ~example() {
        cout << "~example()\n";
        delete p_;
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "start main\n";
    example<int> p{new int};
    cout << "end main\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Try it out here: https://ideone.com/rOtQY9

<del>Anyway, the use of a global smart pointer eludes me</del>. The program is finished so the memory would have been released to the OS anyway. The nice thing is that whatever resource has been acquired during construction will also be released for sure (e.g. a file could be closed correctly, or a bitstream buffer could be flushed).

Comment: So a smart pointer is only needed, if the OS has no virtual memory management system.

Comment: @Tom No, virtual memory has nothing to do with smart pointers. You use a smart pointer when your pointer needs to be deleted in a different context with respect to where it was allocated. If it is a `unique_ptr<>` there is a single owner and you can pass ownership around without worrying about who is in charge of deleting it (the only owner will delete the pointer). If it is a `shared_ptr<>` many objects can share the memory but writing down when they are done with it. When you are the last one, you delete the pointer.

Comment: I know, what a smart pointer is. But will the resource of a global non-smart pointer be deleted at program exit?

Comment: @Tom No, there is no guarantee that it will happen. Specifically, under Linux and Windows, you are sure that any memory allocated by your program will be freed, but its *outside* the C++ competence. The destructor of the object possibly pointed by the global non-smart pointer will not be called.