# Singleton translation unit confusion

Tags: c++, singleton

In `ContainerTest.h` I have the following singleton class defined:

```
    class ContainerTest
    {
    private:
        ContainerTest()
        {
            test = InitializeTest();
        }

        ContainerTest(const ContainerTest&) = delete;
        ContainerTest(ContainerTest&&) = delete;
        ContainerTest& operator=(const ContainerTest&) = delete;
        ContainerTest& operator=(ContainerTest&&) = delete;
    public:
        std::vector<uint32_t> test;

        static ContainerTest& GetInstance()
        {
            static ContainerTest rhc;
            return rhc;
        }
    };
```

I am confused about whether only one instance of ContainerTest will exist throughout my program.

I.e., if two cpp files `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` both include `ContainerTest.h` will there be one instance of ContainerTest created, or two instances? Can someone explain this? And if there's two instances created (one for A and B's translation unit) how can I prevent this?

Comment: There will be only one instance. ```static ContainerTest rhc``` will be shared throughout a single executable.

Comment: @Steve Thanks, is there any good resource that will let me brush up on translation unit rules for C++? I'm also assuming if GetInstance is not inlined by the compiler it will exist in only one place in memory?

Comment: Can't find a really good straight to the point answer, but see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246568/425871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `static` variable in the function will get a unique symbol name that is used by the linker to ensure there is only a single instance. It will generate a so called weak symbol, which may occur in multiple translation units. The Linker then will use only one instance. This will even work, when embedded in a dynamic library/shared object.

I used the following small test program: (mostly your code)

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>



class ContainerTest
{
private:
    ContainerTest()
    { }

    ContainerTest(const ContainerTest&) = delete;
    ContainerTest(ContainerTest&&) = delete;
    ContainerTest& operator=(const ContainerTest&) = delete;
    ContainerTest& operator=(ContainerTest&&) = delete;
public:
    std::vector<uint32_t> test;

    static ContainerTest& GetInstance()
    {
        static ContainerTest rhc;
        return rhc;
    }
};


int main(int, char**)
{
    ContainerTest& ct = ContainerTest::GetInstance();
}
```

and compiled with gcc then I called:

```
nm -a libContainerTestSingleton.so |grep rhc| c++filt
```

Which provides the following output:

```
0000000000000000 b .bss._ZGVZN13ContainerTest11GetInstanceEvE3rhc
0000000000000000 b .bss._ZZN13ContainerTest11GetInstanceEvE3rhc
0000000000000000 u guard variable for ContainerTest::GetInstance()::rhc
0000000000000000 u ContainerTest::GetInstance()::rhc
```

A symbol, than is marked with an `u` means following: (nm manpage)

```
"u" The symbol is a unique global symbol.  This is a GNU extension to the
    standard set of ELF symbol bindings.  For such a symbol the dynamic 
    linker will make sure that in the entire process there is just one
    symbolwith this name and type in use.
```