# C++: Redefinition of a const variable inside a function

Tags: c++, namespaces, qualifiers

I'm learning the modifiers of variable in C++. I see this code in the tutorial:

```
int func()
{
    static int number = 1;
    return ++number;
}

int main()
{
    int i = func();
    printf("i is %d", i); //This gives 2
    i = func();
    printf("i is %d", i); //This gives 3
    return 0;
}
```

From my understanding, I think the first time `func()` is called, it defines the variable in the global space. However, the next time `func()` is called, it will try to do the same thing in the global space, but why it doesn't result in a redefinition error?

Comment: @S.M. Sorry but I'm a little confused. Since from what I learned, static means the variable has the same duration as the program. So the conflict is still there?

Comment: [Static local variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) are special. Such a variable is initialized exactly once, when execution passes over its definition for the first time.

Comment: *However, the next time func() is called, it will try to do the same thing in the global space...* Nope, the next time it re-uses the first one which has maintained its state from the prior call.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This answers my question. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's much better to get some textbooks, not online tutorials.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the lifetime of a static variable in a C++ function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246564/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-static-variable-in-a-c-function)