# How do I use extern to share variables between source files?

Tags: c++, c, global-variables, extern

I know that global variables in C sometimes have the `extern` keyword. What is an `extern` variable? What is the declaration like? What is its scope?

This is related to sharing variables across source files, but how does that work precisely? Where do I use `extern`?

Answer (score 2173):

Using `extern` is only of relevance when the program you're building
consists of multiple source files linked together, where some of the
variables defined, for example, in source file `file1.c` need to be
referenced in other source files, such as `file2.c`.

It is important to [understand the difference between *defining* a
variable and *declaring* a
variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563):

- A variable is **declared** when the compiler is informed that a
  variable exists (and this is its type); it does not allocate the
  storage for the variable at that point.
- A variable is **defined** when the compiler allocates the storage for
  the variable.

You may declare a variable multiple times (though once is sufficient);
you may only define it once within a given scope.
A variable definition is also a declaration, but not all variable
declarations are definitions.

### Best way to declare and define global variables

The clean, reliable way to declare and define global variables is to use
a header file to contain an `extern` *declaration* of the variable.

The header is included by the one source file that defines the variable
and by all the source files that reference the variable.
For each program, one source file (and only one source file) defines the
variable.
Similarly, one header file (and only one header file) should declare the
variable.
The header file is crucial; it enables cross-checking between
independent TUs (translation units — think source files) and ensures
consistency.

Although there are other ways of doing it, this method is simple and
reliable.
It is demonstrated by `file3.h`, `file1.c` and `file2.c`:

#### file3.h

```c
extern int global_variable;  /* Declaration of the variable */
```

#### file1.c

```c
#include "file3.h"  /* Declaration made available here */
#include "prog1.h"  /* Function declarations */

/* Variable defined here */
int global_variable = 37;    /* Definition checked against declaration */

int increment(void) { return global_variable++; }
```

#### file2.c

```c
#include "file3.h"
#include "prog1.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void use_it(void)
{
    printf("Global variable: %d\n", global_variable++);
}
```

That's the best way to declare and define global variables.

---

*The next two files complete the source for `prog1`:*

The complete programs shown use functions, so function declarations have
crept in.
Both C99 and C11 require functions to be declared or defined before they
are used (whereas C90 did not, for good reasons).
I use the keyword `extern` in front of function declarations in headers
for consistency — to match the `extern` in front of variable
declarations in headers.
Many people prefer not to use `extern` in front of function
declarations; the compiler doesn't care — and ultimately, neither do I
as long as you're consistent, at least within a source file.

#### prog1.h

```c
extern void use_it(void);
extern int increment(void);
```

#### prog1.c

```c
#include "file3.h"
#include "prog1.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    use_it();
    global_variable += 19;
    use_it();
    printf("Increment: %d\n", increment());
    return 0;
}
```

- `prog1` uses `prog1.c`, `file1.c`, `file2.c`, `file3.h` and `prog1.h`.

The file `prog1.mk` is a makefile for `prog1` only.
It will work with most versions of `make` produced since about the turn
of the millennium.
It is not tied specifically to GNU Make.

#### prog1.mk

```
# Minimal makefile for prog1

PROGRAM = prog1
FILES.c = prog1.c file1.c file2.c
FILES.h = prog1.h file3.h
FILES.o = ${FILES.c:.c=.o}

CC      = gcc
SFLAGS  = -std=c11
GFLAGS  = -g
OFLAGS  = -O3
WFLAG1  = -Wall
WFLAG2  = -Wextra
WFLAG3  = -Werror
WFLAG4  = -Wstrict-prototypes
WFLAG5  = -Wmissing-prototypes
WFLAGS  = ${WFLAG1} ${WFLAG2} ${WFLAG3} ${WFLAG4} ${WFLAG5}
UFLAGS  = # Set on command line only

CFLAGS  = ${SFLAGS} ${GFLAGS} ${OFLAGS} ${WFLAGS} ${UFLAGS}
LDFLAGS =
LDLIBS  =

all:    ${PROGRAM}

${PROGRAM}: ${FILES.o}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${FILES.o} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}

prog1.o: ${FILES.h}
file1.o: ${FILES.h}
file2.o: ${FILES.h}

# If it exists, prog1.dSYM is a directory on macOS
DEBRIS = a.out core *~ *.dSYM
RM_FR  = rm -fr

clean:
    ${RM_FR} ${FILES.o} ${PROGRAM} ${DEBRIS}
```

---

### Guidelines

Rules to be broken by experts only, and only with good reason:

- A header file only contains `extern` declarations of variables — never
  `static` or unqualified variable definitions.
- For any given variable, only one header file declares it (SPOT —
  Single Point of Truth).
- A source file never contains `extern` declarations of variables —
  source files always include the (sole) header that declares them.
- For any given variable, exactly one source file defines the variable,
  preferably initializing it too.  (Although there is no need to
  initialize explicitly to zero, it does no harm and can do some good,
  because there can be only one initialized definition of a particular
  global variable in a program).
- The source file that defines the variable also includes the header to
  ensure that the definition and the declaration are consistent.
- A function should never need to declare a variable using `extern`.
- Avoid global variables whenever possible — use functions instead.

<sup>*The source code and text of this answer are available in my
[SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions)
repository on GitHub in the
[src/so-0143-3204](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-0143-3204)
sub-directory.*</sup>

<sup>*If you're not an experienced C programmer, you could (and perhaps
should) stop reading here.*</sup>

### Not so good way to define global variables

With some (indeed, many) C compilers, you can get away with what's
called a 'common' definition of a variable too.
'Common', here, refers to a technique used in Fortran for sharing
variables between source files, using a (possibly named) COMMON block.
What happens here is that each of a number of files provides a tentative
definition of the variable.
As long as no more than one file provides an initialized definition,
then the various files end up sharing a common single definition of the
variable:

#### file10.c

```c
#include "prog2.h"

long l;   /* Do not do this in portable code */

void inc(void) { l++; }
```

#### file11.c

```c
#include "prog2.h"

long l;   /* Do not do this in portable code */

void dec(void) { l--; }
```

#### file12.c

```c
#include "prog2.h"
#include <stdio.h>

long l = 9;   /* Do not do this in portable code */

void put(void) { printf("l = %ld\n", l); }
```

This technique does not conform to the letter of the C standard and the
'one definition rule' — it is officially undefined behaviour:

> **[J.2 Undefined behavior](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2)**

> An identifier with external linkage is used, but in the program there
> does not exist exactly one external definition for the identifier, or
> the identifier is not used and there exist multiple external
> definitions for the identifier (6.9).

> **[§6.9 External definitions ¶5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9p5)**

> An *external definition* is an external declaration that is also a
> definition of a function (other than an inline definition) or an
> object.
> If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an
> expression (other than as part of the operand of a `sizeof` or
> `_Alignof` operator whose result is an integer constant), somewhere in
> the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for
> the identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than
> one.<sup>161)</sup>

> <sup>161)</sup> Thus, if an identifier declared with external linkage
> is not used in an expression, there need be no external definition for
> it.

However, the C standard also lists it in informative Annex J as one of
the [Common extensions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5).

> [J.5.11 Multiple external definitions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5.11)

> There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of
> an object, with or without the explicit use of the keyword extern; if
> the definitions disagree, or more than one is initialized, the
> behavior is undefined (6.9.2).

Because this technique is not always supported, it is best to avoid
using it, *especially if your code needs to be portable*.
Using this technique, you can also end up with unintentional type
punning.

If one of the files above declared `l` as a `double` instead of as a
`long`, C's type-unsafe linkers probably would not spot the mismatch.
If you're on a machine with 64-bit `long` and `double`, you'd not even
get a warning; on a machine with 32-bit `long` and 64-bit `double`,
you'd probably get a warning about the different sizes — the linker
would use the largest size, exactly as a Fortran program would take the
largest size of any common blocks.

Note that GCC 10.1.0, which was released on 2020-05-07, changes the
default compilation options to use
[`-fno-common`](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/porting_to.html), which means
that by default, the code above no longer links unless you override the
default with `-fcommon` (or use attributes, etc — see the link).

---

*The next two files complete the source for `prog2`:*

#### prog2.h

```c
extern void dec(void);
extern void put(void);
extern void inc(void);
```

#### prog2.c

```c
#include "prog2.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    inc();
    put();
    dec();
    put();
    dec();
    put();
}
```

- `prog2` uses `prog2.c`, `file10.c`, `file11.c`, `file12.c`, `prog2.h`.

---

#### Warning

As noted in comments here, and as stated in my answer to a similar
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490693), using multiple
definitions for a global variable leads to undefined behaviour (J.2;
§6.9), which is the standard's way of saying "anything could happen".
One of the things that can happen is that the program behaves as you
expect; and J.5.11 says, approximately, "you might be lucky more often
than you deserve".
But a program that relies on multiple definitions of an extern variable
— with or without the explicit 'extern' keyword — is not a strictly
conforming program and not guaranteed to work everywhere.
Equivalently: it contains a bug which may or may not show itself.

### Violating the guidelines

There are, of course, many ways in which these guidelines can be broken.
Occasionally, there may be a good reason to break the guidelines, but
such occasions are extremely unusual.

#### faulty_header.h

```c
int some_var;    /* Do not do this in a header!!! */
```

Note 1: if the header defines the variable without the `extern` keyword,
then each file that includes the header creates a tentative definition
of the variable.
As noted previously, this will often work, but the C standard does not
guarantee that it will work.

#### broken_header.h

```c
int some_var = 13;    /* Only one source file in a program can use this */
```

Note 2: if the header defines and initializes the variable, then only
one source file in a given program can use the header.
Since headers are primarily for sharing information, it is a bit silly
to create one that can only be used once.

#### seldom_correct.h

```c
static int hidden_global = 3;   /* Each source file gets its own copy  */
```

Note 3: if the header defines a static variable (with or without
initialization), then each source file ends up with its own private
version of the 'global' variable.

If the variable is actually a complex array, for example, this can lead
to extreme duplication of code.  It can, very occasionally, be a
sensible way to achieve some effect, but that is very unusual.

---

### Summary

Use the header technique I showed first.
It works reliably and everywhere.
Note, in particular, that the header declaring the `global_variable` is
included in every file that uses it — including the one that defines it.
This ensures that everything is self-consistent.

Similar concerns arise with declaring and defining functions —
analogous rules apply.
But the question was about variables specifically, so I've kept the
answer to variables only.

#### End of Original Answer

<sup>*If you're not an experienced C programmer, you probably should stop reading here.*</sup>

---

*Late Major Addition*

## Avoiding Code Duplication

One concern that is sometimes (and legitimately) raised about the
'declarations in headers, definitions in source' mechanism described
here is that there are two files to be kept synchronized — the header
and the source.  This is usually followed up with an observation that a
macro can be used so that the header serves double duty — normally
declaring the variables, but when a specific macro is set before the
header is included, it defines the variables instead.

Another concern can be that the variables need to be defined in each of
a number of 'main programs'.  This is normally a spurious concern; you
can simply introduce a C source file to define the variables and link
the object file produced with each of the programs.

A typical scheme works like this, using the original global variable
illustrated in `file3.h`:

#### file3a.h

```c
#ifdef DEFINE_VARIABLES
#define EXTERN /* nothing */
#else
#define EXTERN extern
#endif /* DEFINE_VARIABLES */

EXTERN int global_variable;
```

#### file1a.c

```c
#define DEFINE_VARIABLES
#include "file3a.h"  /* Variable defined - but not initialized */
#include "prog3.h"

int increment(void) { return global_variable++; }
```

#### file2a.c

```c
#include "file3a.h"
#include "prog3.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void use_it(void)
{
    printf("Global variable: %d\n", global_variable++);
}
```

---

*The next two files complete the source for `prog3`:*

#### prog3.h

```c
extern void use_it(void);
extern int increment(void);
```

#### prog3.c

```c
#include "file3a.h"
#include "prog3.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    use_it();
    global_variable += 19;
    use_it();
    printf("Increment: %d\n", increment());
    return 0;
}
```

- `prog3` uses `prog3.c`, `file1a.c`, `file2a.c`, `file3a.h`, `prog3.h`.

---

### Variable initialization

The problem with this scheme as shown is that it does not provide for
initialization of the global variable.  With C99 or C11 and variable argument
lists for macros, you could define a macro to support initialization too.
(With C89 and no support for variable argument lists in macros, there is no
easy way to handle arbitrarily long initializers.)

#### file3b.h

```c
#ifdef DEFINE_VARIABLES
#define EXTERN                  /* nothing */
#define INITIALIZER(...)        = __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define EXTERN                  extern
#define INITIALIZER(...)        /* nothing */
#endif /* DEFINE_VARIABLES */

EXTERN int global_variable INITIALIZER(37);
EXTERN struct { int a; int b; } oddball_struct INITIALIZER({ 41, 43 });
```

<sup>Reverse contents of `#if` and `#else` blocks, fixing bug identified by
[Denis Kniazhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369317/denis-kniazhev)</sup>

#### file1b.c

```c
#define DEFINE_VARIABLES
#include "file3b.h"  /* Variables now defined and initialized */
#include "prog4.h"

int increment(void) { return global_variable++; }
int oddball_value(void) { return oddball_struct.a + oddball_struct.b; }
```

#### file2b.c

```c
#include "file3b.h"
#include "prog4.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void use_them(void)
{
    printf("Global variable: %d\n", global_variable++);
    oddball_struct.a += global_variable;
    oddball_struct.b -= global_variable / 2;
}
```

Clearly, the code for the oddball structure is not what you'd normally
write, but it illustrates the point.  The first argument to the second
invocation of `INITIALIZER` is `{ 41` and the remaining argument
(singular in this example) is `43 }`.  Without C99 or similar support
for variable argument lists for macros, initializers that need to
contain commas are very problematic.

<sup>Correct header `file3b.h` included (instead of `fileba.h`) per
[Denis Kniazhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369317/denis-kniazhev)</sup>

---

*The next two files complete the source for `prog4`:*

#### prog4.h

```c
extern int increment(void);
extern int oddball_value(void);
extern void use_them(void);
```

#### prog4.c

```c
#include "file3b.h"
#include "prog4.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    use_them();
    global_variable += 19;
    use_them();
    printf("Increment: %d\n", increment());
    printf("Oddball:   %d\n", oddball_value());
    return 0;
}
```

- `prog4` uses `prog4.c`, `file1b.c`, `file2b.c`, `prog4.h`, `file3b.h`.

---

### Header Guards

Any header should be protected against reinclusion, so that type
definitions (enum, struct or union types, or typedefs generally) do not
cause problems.  The standard technique is to wrap the body of the
header in a header guard such as:

```
#ifndef FILE3B_H_INCLUDED
#define FILE3B_H_INCLUDED

...contents of header...

#endif /* FILE3B_H_INCLUDED */
```

The header might be included twice indirectly.  For example, if
`file4b.h` includes `file3b.h` for a type definition that isn't shown,
and `file1b.c` needs to use both header `file4b.h` and `file3b.h`, then
you have some more tricky issues to resolve.  Clearly, you might revise
the header list to include just `file4b.h`.  However, you might not be
aware of the internal dependencies — and the code should, ideally,
continue to work.

Further, it starts to get tricky because you might include `file4b.h`
before including `file3b.h` to generate the definitions, but the normal
header guards on `file3b.h` would prevent the header being reincluded.

So, you need to include the body of `file3b.h` at most once for
declarations, and at most once for definitions, but you might need both
in a single translation unit (TU — a combination of a source file and
the headers it uses).

### Multiple inclusion with variable definitions

However, it can be done subject to a not too unreasonable constraint.
Let's introduce a new set of file names:

- `external.h` for the EXTERN macro definitions, etc.
- `file1c.h` to define types (notably, `struct oddball`, the type of `oddball_struct`).
- `file2c.h` to define or declare the global variables.
- `file3c.c` which defines the global variables.
- `file4c.c` which simply uses the global variables.
- `file5c.c` which shows that you can declare and then define the global variables.
- `file6c.c` which shows that you can define and then (attempt to) declare the global variables.

In these examples, `file5c.c` and `file6c.c` directly include the header
`file2c.h` several times, but that is the simplest way to show that the
mechanism works.  It means that if the header was indirectly included
twice, it would also be safe.

The restrictions for this to work are:

1. The header defining or declaring the global variables may not itself
   define any types.
2. Immediately before you include a header that should define variables,
   you define the macro DEFINE_VARIABLES.
3. The header defining or declaring the variables has stylized contents.

#### external.h

```c
/*
** This header must not contain header guards (like <assert.h> must not).
** Each time it is invoked, it redefines the macros EXTERN, INITIALIZE
** based on whether macro DEFINE_VARIABLES is currently defined.
*/
#undef EXTERN
#undef INITIALIZE

#ifdef DEFINE_VARIABLES
#define EXTERN              /* nothing */
#define INITIALIZE(...)     = __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define EXTERN              extern
#define INITIALIZE(...)     /* nothing */
#endif /* DEFINE_VARIABLES */
```

#### file1c.h

```c
#ifndef FILE1C_H_INCLUDED
#define FILE1C_H_INCLUDED

struct oddball
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

extern void use_them(void);
extern int increment(void);
extern int oddball_value(void);

#endif /* FILE1C_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### file2c.h

```c
/* Standard prologue */
#if defined(DEFINE_VARIABLES) && !defined(FILE2C_H_DEFINITIONS)
#undef FILE2C_H_INCLUDED
#endif

#ifndef FILE2C_H_INCLUDED
#define FILE2C_H_INCLUDED

#include "external.h"   /* Support macros EXTERN, INITIALIZE */
#include "file1c.h"     /* Type definition for struct oddball */

#if !defined(DEFINE_VARIABLES) || !defined(FILE2C_H_DEFINITIONS)

/* Global variable declarations / definitions */
EXTERN int global_variable INITIALIZE(37);
EXTERN struct oddball oddball_struct INITIALIZE({ 41, 43 });

#endif /* !DEFINE_VARIABLES || !FILE2C_H_DEFINITIONS */

/* Standard epilogue */
#ifdef DEFINE_VARIABLES
#define FILE2C_H_DEFINITIONS
#endif /* DEFINE_VARIABLES */

#endif /* FILE2C_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### file3c.c

```c
#define DEFINE_VARIABLES
#include "file2c.h"  /* Variables now defined and initialized */

int increment(void) { return global_variable++; }
int oddball_value(void) { return oddball_struct.a + oddball_struct.b; }
```

#### file4c.c

```c
#include "file2c.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void use_them(void)
{
    printf("Global variable: %d\n", global_variable++);
    oddball_struct.a += global_variable;
    oddball_struct.b -= global_variable / 2;
}
```

#### file5c.c

```c
#include "file2c.h"     /* Declare variables */

#define DEFINE_VARIABLES
#include "file2c.h"  /* Variables now defined and initialized */

int increment(void) { return global_variable++; }
int oddball_value(void) { return oddball_struct.a + oddball_struct.b; }
```

#### file6c.c

```c
#define DEFINE_VARIABLES
#include "file2c.h"     /* Variables now defined and initialized */

#include "file2c.h"     /* Declare variables */

int increment(void) { return global_variable++; }
int oddball_value(void) { return oddball_struct.a + oddball_struct.b; }
```

---

*The next source file completes the source (provides a main program) for `prog5`, `prog6` and `prog7`:*

#### prog5.c

```c
#include "file2c.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    use_them();
    global_variable += 19;
    use_them();
    printf("Increment: %d\n", increment());
    printf("Oddball:   %d\n", oddball_value());
    return 0;
}
```

- `prog5` uses `prog5.c`, `file3c.c`, `file4c.c`, `file1c.h`, `file2c.h`, `external.h`.
- `prog6` uses `prog5.c`, `file5c.c`, `file4c.c`, `file1c.h`, `file2c.h`, `external.h`.
- `prog7` uses `prog5.c`, `file6c.c`, `file4c.c`, `file1c.h`, `file2c.h`, `external.h`.

---

This scheme avoids most problems.  You only run into a problem if a
header that defines variables (such as `file2c.h`) is included by
another header (say `file7c.h`) that defines variables.  There isn't an
easy way around that other than "don't do it".

You can partially work around the problem by revising `file2c.h` into
`file2d.h`:

#### file2d.h

```c
/* Standard prologue */
#if defined(DEFINE_VARIABLES) && !defined(FILE2D_H_DEFINITIONS)
#undef FILE2D_H_INCLUDED
#endif

#ifndef FILE2D_H_INCLUDED
#define FILE2D_H_INCLUDED

#include "external.h"   /* Support macros EXTERN, INITIALIZE */
#include "file1c.h"     /* Type definition for struct oddball */

#if !defined(DEFINE_VARIABLES) || !defined(FILE2D_H_DEFINITIONS)

/* Global variable declarations / definitions */
EXTERN int global_variable INITIALIZE(37);
EXTERN struct oddball oddball_struct INITIALIZE({ 41, 43 });

#endif /* !DEFINE_VARIABLES || !FILE2D_H_DEFINITIONS */

/* Standard epilogue */
#ifdef DEFINE_VARIABLES
#define FILE2D_H_DEFINITIONS
#undef DEFINE_VARIABLES
#endif /* DEFINE_VARIABLES */

#endif /* FILE2D_H_INCLUDED */
```

The issue becomes 'should the header include `#undef DEFINE_VARIABLES`?'
If you omit that from the header and wrap any defining invocation with
`#define` and `#undef`:

```
#define DEFINE_VARIABLES
#include "file2c.h"
#undef DEFINE_VARIABLES
```

in the source code (so the headers never alter the value of
`DEFINE_VARIABLES`), then you should be clean.  It is just a nuisance to
have to remember to write the the extra line.  An alternative might be:

```
#define HEADER_DEFINING_VARIABLES "file2c.h"
#include "externdef.h"
```

#### externdef.h

```c
/*
** This header must not contain header guards (like <assert.h> must not).
** Each time it is included, the macro HEADER_DEFINING_VARIABLES should
** be defined with the name (in quotes - or possibly angle brackets) of
** the header to be included that defines variables when the macro
** DEFINE_VARIABLES is defined.  See also: external.h (which uses
** DEFINE_VARIABLES and defines macros EXTERN and INITIALIZE
** appropriately).
**
** #define HEADER_DEFINING_VARIABLES "file2c.h"
** #include "externdef.h"
*/

#if defined(HEADER_DEFINING_VARIABLES)
#define DEFINE_VARIABLES
#include HEADER_DEFINING_VARIABLES
#undef DEFINE_VARIABLES
#undef HEADER_DEFINING_VARIABLES
#endif /* HEADER_DEFINING_VARIABLES */
```

This is getting a tad convoluted, but seems to be secure (using the
`file2d.h`, with no `#undef DEFINE_VARIABLES` in the `file2d.h`).

#### file7c.c

```c
/* Declare variables */
#include "file2d.h"

/* Define variables */
#define HEADER_DEFINING_VARIABLES "file2d.h"
#include "externdef.h"

/* Declare variables - again */
#include "file2d.h"

/* Define variables - again */
#define HEADER_DEFINING_VARIABLES "file2d.h"
#include "externdef.h"

int increment(void) { return global_variable++; }
int oddball_value(void) { return oddball_struct.a + oddball_struct.b; }
```

#### file8c.h

```c
/* Standard prologue */
#if defined(DEFINE_VARIABLES) && !defined(FILE8C_H_DEFINITIONS)
#undef FILE8C_H_INCLUDED
#endif

#ifndef FILE8C_H_INCLUDED
#define FILE8C_H_INCLUDED

#include "external.h"   /* Support macros EXTERN, INITIALIZE */
#include "file2d.h"     /* struct oddball */

#if !defined(DEFINE_VARIABLES) || !defined(FILE8C_H_DEFINITIONS)

/* Global variable declarations / definitions */
EXTERN struct oddball another INITIALIZE({ 14, 34 });

#endif /* !DEFINE_VARIABLES || !FILE8C_H_DEFINITIONS */

/* Standard epilogue */
#ifdef DEFINE_VARIABLES
#define FILE8C_H_DEFINITIONS
#endif /* DEFINE_VARIABLES */

#endif /* FILE8C_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### file8c.c

```c
/* Define variables */
#define HEADER_DEFINING_VARIABLES "file2d.h"
#include "externdef.h"

/* Define variables */
#define HEADER_DEFINING_VARIABLES "file8c.h"
#include "externdef.h"

int increment(void) { return global_variable++; }
int oddball_value(void) { return oddball_struct.a + oddball_struct.b; }
```

---

*The next two files complete the source for `prog8` and `prog9`:*

#### prog8.c

```c
#include "file2d.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    use_them();
    global_variable += 19;
    use_them();
    printf("Increment: %d\n", increment());
    printf("Oddball:   %d\n", oddball_value());
    return 0;
}
```

#### file9c.c

```c
#include "file2d.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void use_them(void)
{
    printf("Global variable: %d\n", global_variable++);
    oddball_struct.a += global_variable;
    oddball_struct.b -= global_variable / 2;
}
```

- `prog8` uses `prog8.c`, `file7c.c`, `file9c.c`.
- `prog9` uses `prog8.c`, `file8c.c`, `file9c.c`.

---

However, the problems are relatively unlikely to occur in practice,
especially if you take the standard advice to

## Avoid global variables

---

Does this exposition miss anything?

<sup>_Confession_: The 'avoiding duplicated code' scheme outlined here was
developed because the issue affects some code I work on (but don't own),
and is a niggling concern with the scheme outlined in the first part of
the answer.  However, the original scheme leaves you with just two
places to modify to keep variable definitions and declarations
synchronized, which is a big step forward over having exernal variable
declarations scattered throughout the code base (which really matters
when there are thousands of files in total).  However, the code in the
files with the names `fileNc.[ch]` (plus `external.h` and `externdef.h`)
shows that it can be made to work.  Clearly, it would not be hard to
create a header generator script to give you the standardized template
for a variable defining and declaring header file.</sup>

*NB* These are toy programs with just barely enough code to make them
marginally interesting.  There is repetition within the examples that
could be removed, but isn't to simplify the pedagogical explanation.
(For example: the difference between `prog5.c` and `prog8.c` is the name
of one of the headers that are included.  It would be possible to
reorganize the code so that the `main()` function was not repeated, but
it would conceal more than it revealed.)

Comment: Are you sure that having tentative definitions spread across multiple translation units is blessed by C? The C99 TC3 draft says " If a translation unit contains one or more tentative deﬁnitions for an identiﬁer, and the translation unit contains no external deﬁnition for that identiﬁer, then the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that identiﬁer, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to 0."

Comment: That seems to mean that each such translation unit contains an external definition for it, and violate "somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external deﬁnition for the identiﬁer; otherwise [if the identifier isn't used], there shall be no more than one.". As i understood the COMMON blocks, they are non-standard extensions.

Comment: @litb: see Annex J.5.11 for the common definition - it is a common extension.

Comment: @litb: and I agree it should be avoided - that's why it is in the section on 'Not so good way to define global variables'.

Comment: Indeed it's a common extension, but it's undefined behavior for a program to rely on it. I just wasn't clear whether you were saying that this is allowed by C's own rules. Now i see you are saying it's just a common extension and to avoid it if you need your code to be portable. So i can upvote you without doubts. Really great answer IMHO :)

Comment: In your example of `file3a.h`, should the `extern` keyword come on the `if` instead of the `else`?

Comment: @Zak: No. The conditional code in `file3a.h` is `#ifdef DEFINE_VARIABLES /
#define EXTERN /
#else /
#define EXTERN extern /
#endif`, removing comments and using slashes to mark the ends of lines.  If `DEFINE_VARIABLES` is specified, then the variables should not have the `extern` prefix which would mark them as declarations instead of definitions.  That, in turn, means that the compiler will allocate space for the variables, rather than simply recording their existence.

Comment: If you stop at the top, it keeps simple things simple.  As you read further down, it deals with more nuances, complications and details.  I've just added two 'early stopping points' for less experienced C programmers — or C programmers who already know the subject.  There's no need to read it all if you already know the answer (but let me know if you find a technical fault).

Comment: Is there any reasonable pattern for a scenario in which code in numerous modules needs to make use of the same initialized array *and know its size*?  At least some compilers will regard `extern int foo[] = {1,2,3};` as equivalent to `extern int foo[3];`, so it's possible to use some preprocessor logic to selectively omit the "extern" when the file is included from within its main source file.  I haven't figured out any way to make that not look really ugly, though.

Comment: @supercat: I would create a file `foo.c` to contain the definition of the array and a variable to hold its size: `#include "foo.h"` plus `int foo[] = { 1, 2, 3}; size_t foo_size = sizeof(foo) / sizeof(foo[0]);`, and a header `foo.h` which would contain `#include <stddef.h` (to get the definition of `size_t`) plus `extern int foo[]; extern size_t foo_size;`. You'd then put `foo.o` into a suitable library, and `foo.h` in a suitable directory of headers, and compile and link against the header and library. You can add header guards, and maybe use the 'avoid repetition' ideas from the main answer.

Comment: @supercat: I'd add `const` to the `size_t` 'variable' since the size of the array doesn't change.  The major downside of this is that you don't have an integer constant (as opposed to a constant integer) which you can use in contexts where an integer constant is needed.  Realistically, it is unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: For embedded systems, the differences between constants and never-written variables can be significant.  It's really too bad that C never defined a means of defining link-time constants other than addresses, since I think linker systems even when C was designed could support such a concept at least for things that weren't larger than `int`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: BTW, on many embedded systems, there can also be a substantial speed and code size penalty for separating parts of a program into different compilation unit.  For example, on a typical ARM, `void setVariables(int a,b,c) {x=a;y=b;z=c;}` could be 14 bytes if x-z are in the same compilation unit as the method, but would require 26 bytes if they're in another compilation unit.  Some people may despise the idea of using `#include` to join together C files that could also run as separate compilation units, but there can be some *major* efficiency advantages to doing so.

Comment: @supercat: It occurs to me that you can use C99 array literals to get an enumeration value for the array size, exemplified by (`foo.h`): `#define FOO_INITIALIZER { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` to define the initializer for the array, `enum { FOO_SIZE = sizeof((int [])FOO_INITIALIZER) / sizeof(((int [])FOO_INITIALIZER)[0]) };` to get the size of the array, and `extern int foo[];` to declare the array.  Clearly, the definition should be just `int foo[FOO_SIZE] = FOO_INITIALIZER;`, though the size doesn't really have to be included in the definition.  This gets you a integer constant, `FOO_SIZE`.

Comment: +1 for the idea of using an `enum`, though I'm not sure how compilers would handle the aforementioned syntax.  I've used great big monster macros for a variety of purposes in a style similar to this, but I think using `[extern] int foo[] = {..data..}` is a bit cleaner since it uses the size of the *actual* created array.  BTW, one really nasty hack which works on some embedded compilers would be to have `foo.c` contain the array and then `int[] FOO_SIZE_AS_ADDR @(sizeof(foo))`, and then have the `.h` file `#define foo_size ((int)(FOO_SIZE_AS_ADDR))`.  The thing the hack is doing...

Comment: ...(allowing an `int` value to be used as a link-time constant) would be the cleanest way to share the array content and size among different compilation units [note that the FOO_SIZE_AS_ADDR doesn't point to anything meaningful, but on some platforms its *address* can be used as a link-time constant].  Of course, many platforms don't provide an `@` syntax for forcing addresses, so the only way to declare such addresses would be in an assembly-language file.  Further, on many platforms there would be no guarantee that all `int` values will be accepted by the linker as addresses.

Comment: @supercat: You need to be careful to decide when you give up on using what the standard promises will work.  It is a legitimate, but in my experience fraught, decision to make.  The fraughtness comes because people don't realize they're going outside the standard and the information is not documented in the code, and when you move it to a new environment or a new version of the compiler or whatever, the behaviour changes because it was not standard behaviour.  Your judgement call.  My judgement errs on the side of caution and following the standard for maximum portability.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I would not use the aformentioned hack with array sizes, because there is a standard-compliant means of handling the concept that, while clunky, is workable. I have used that sort of hack for some other purposes, however--typically with constants that are defined in an assembly-language file.  For example, in one case an assembly-language method needed to be passed an array of a certain size, but the assembly code could be adapted to change that size (the code would need to be modified according to the array size, but such modification would not be difficult). In that case...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I figured that having the `.h` file contain a hacky expression to convert a pointer to an integer was safer than having it specify a number. If the code needed to be ported to a platform where that wouldn't work, the assembly file would almost certainly need to be changed for other reasons anyhow.  PS--I wonder how much "portable" code would work on a platform where `int` was 64 bits?  I would expect a lot of code which is thought to be portable would end up working most of the time but end up with obscure little bugs because of C's unfortunate type-promotion rules.

Comment: This is a good answer to return to as you learn C/Objective-C/C++ but header guards should be noted much earlier. Reason being, if you do anything with any *nix it's unavoidably standard practice.

Comment: why do you use extern when declaring functions?

Comment: Because I only ever write such declarations in headers, and any variables declared in headers must be prefixed with `extern`, so for symmetry, I also declare functions prefixed with `extern`.  Other people don't do it — it's a point of difference in style.

Comment: I am a complete amateur to this. How do I write a makefile for the very first section before the guidelines? Can you provide a sample makefile? Thanks. Edit: I realized that we can use gcc file1.c file2.c prog1.c -o final_working to make it work. But if I were to write a formal make file, how do I do it for this case? I wrote one, but it doesn't seem to work. Your response will be quite helpful to check against mine.

Comment: @Shubashree: Hmmm – interesting.  OK; I've added `prog1.mk` to show you the 'minimal' makefile.  It isn't completely minimal, of course.  That allows me to tune the build if necessary, but covers most of the bases, leaving a very stringent set of compilation options.  Not that some of the `xFLAGS` names used have other uses in standard Make (notably `GFLAGS` — related to SCCS, but you probably don't use SCCS, so it probably doesn't matter).  Beware!

Comment: Hello, Sir. I have one confusion. My question is you said "we may declare a variable multiple times (though once is sufficient);" So, Can we write "extern int bar;" multiple times? I like to beg pardon for my ignorance. I'm here for clearing my confusion over "variable defining".

Comment: @naasif: Yes; you may use: `extern int bar; extern int bar; …other code…; extern int bar; extern int bar;` and all you're doing is wasting the compiler's time processing unnecessary declarations, and causing people to doubt your sanity.  You could even have `int bar = 97;` somewhere to define the variable; you can only have one such initialized definition anywhere in your program.  Writing `int bar;` several times is also legitimate but extremely unorthodox; these tentative definitions are finalized at the end of the translation unit (TU) into a single uninitialized variable definition.

Comment: @naasif: See also C11 [§6.9.2 External object definitions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.2) which includes an example with annotations on what's allowed and not allowed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sir one more thing to be cleared. "extern" keyword is suitable while using header file because if we declare a variable "int i" without "extern" keyword that would  conflict in coding if we use "int i" in our program. So, it is wise to always use extern while declaring a golbal variable inside a header file. Am I right, sir?

Comment: @naasif: Almost invariably, when written inside a header, variable declarations should be prefixed with `extern` so as not to define the variable in multiple TUs.  There are options on some systems (`-Wl,-relax` on Linux, for example) to allow multiple definitions — but it isn't good practice to need it.  The standard has a fairly strict 'one definition' rule, but some (many) compilers relax the rules (see the 'common extensions' stuff — C11 [Annex J.5 Common extensions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5) etc.).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Sir, Last thing to know. When I run prog3.c(containing main) it first runs "use_it()" there is no chance to get initialized I see. But it some somehow initialized with value 37 which was defined in file1.c . But when the function was invoked there were no chance to meet file1.c . I think it has been done because of "extern keyword" and someone during compiler processing was looking for the value of "global_variable" and stored it. This could be the reason of perfectly working of "use_it();" variable. I'm just wondering who did this? I'm sorry for bothering you but I need it.

Comment: @naasif — in `prog3`, the `global_variable` is default initialized to 0 when at program startup. When `use_it()` is called, it is printed (as 0) then incremented.  Then the main code adds 19, to save 20. The next call to `use_it()` therefore prints 20 and increments the variable to 21. The call to `increment()` returns 21 (but increments the variable to 22, too). That's what I get from the GitHub [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-0143-3204) repository code for this question. That links `progr3.o`, `file1a.o` and `file2a.o`, though; it doesn't use `file1.c` at all.

Comment: Why does the "safe" way actually work?  The conventional pattern for declaring and defining global_variable is as shown in the first example, where file3.h declares `extern global_variable`, and then file1.c defines the variable with `int global_variable = 37;`  As noted in the comment, file1.c also _#includes_ file3.h to allow the compiler to check the declaration.  
But why does the compiler not detect this as an error? Having seen in the included header that global_variable is supposed to be extern, here it is being defined, clearly not extern. What rule makes this OK?

Comment: @gwideman: What is the error that the compiler should be detecting?  That the TU contains `extern int global_variable;` and also (later) `int global_variable = 37;`?  There's no error because the first says "there is global variable of type `int` called `global_variable` that is defined somewhere", and the second says "this is the definition of the global variable of type `int` called `global_variable` and it is initialized to `37`.   The compiler will report an error if one type is `int` and the other `long`, for example.  But there's no harm done with the two self-consistent declarations.

Comment: @gwideman: See also [§6.9.2 External object definitions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.2) and the example provided there.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the link -- I had seen that page before and found it inscrutable. Your explanation makes sense -- evidently extern does not literally mean "external", but rather it's a forward declaration to be resolved by the linker. With error or other consequences if the linker finds more than one actual definition, or definition that doesn't match the extern declaration.

Comment: Old stuff, but my take on the global variables are that by the time you're passing a puck around from one function to another to avoid having a global configuration variable, you might as well as give up and make it a global. I like using global structs instead of global variables, you're far less likely to reuse struct.variable naming accidentally than you'd be reusing just "variable". And of course use functions to get/set the values. Enums with a switch statement work fine here.. Globals are very useful when you've got 64kB uCU or something.

Comment: I can't clarify from this nice (and I mean it) answer if the inclusion (type definition) is needed when I have *file_my_type.h* (with let's say `struct foo { ... };` definition) and *file_x.h* (with `extern struct foo bar;`). Can you clarify this? (I.o.w. does the *file_x.h* have to include *file_my_type.h* strictly speaking, and note **h** in both files)

Comment: @0andriy — If you have `extern struct foo bar;`, then if you access elements of the structure, the compiler requires the definition of the structure.  OTOH, this code compiles OK under GCC with excruciating warning options: `#include <stdio.h>` — `struct foo; extern struct foo bar;` — `extern int function(struct foo *data); extern int consumer(void);` — `int consumer(void) { int i = function(&bar); printf("%d\n", i); return i; }`.  It works because generating the address of the structure doesn't require knowledge of its size, etc.

Comment: "Excruciating options" means `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic -pedantic-errors -c xs41.c` with GCC 13.2.0.

Comment: Seems you didn’t get my question. The idea is that one strict is defined in one **header**, while external declaration in another **header**. Does the latter require the former to be included (if we consider the headers relation)? (In the answer there is `struct oddball`, but with over engineered macros that made code harder to read and understand, hence the question)

Comment: @0andriy — it depends on how you use it.  Sometimes, the answer will be yes (if you use the details of the structure body, you need the definition of the type visible).  Sometimes, the answer will be no (if you only use pointers to the structure type).   I demonstrated a slightly surprising example of 'no' — even though `bar` is declared as a structure type, the details don't matter (so you don't need the header defining the details of the structure).

Comment: If you need an array of `struct foo[]`, would it be yes or no? (For the accessing members it’s obviously yes, I am talking about different use cases)

Comment: @0andriy — To do anything much with an array, you need the size of the elements of the array, which in turn means you need the details of the structure.  When I add the line `extern struct foo baz[];` to the prior test code, I get the error `array type has incomplete element type ‘struct foo’`.  And it isn't tagged with a particular warning — it's just an error (even if I don't specify `-Werror`).

Comment: I'm not talking about VLA, sorry for the confusion, I meant that array size is constant, i.e. `extern struct foo baz[10];`.

Comment: @0andriy — I wasn't talking about either VLA (variable-length array) or FAM (flexible array member) either.  I was talking about a straight-forward `extern struct foo baz[];` external variable declaration stating that the array would be defined somewhere else.  Adding the dimension doesn't change things.  You should be able to experiment with the information I've given you — it will be quicker than asking me questions in this comment chain. There's an argument that you should have created a new question in the first place; there's another that I should have told you to do so earlier.

Comment: I don't want to spread the same Q over two or more question. Your answer suits very well, just misses these details (from my p.o.v.). Hence the comment chain here. Anyway, thanks for your answers, I got it now.

Answer (score 143):

An `extern` variable is a declaration (thanks to sbi for the correction) of a variable which is defined in another translation unit. That means the storage for the variable is allocated in another file.

Say you have two `.c`-files `test1.c` and `test2.c`. If you define a global variable `int test1_var;` in `test1.c` and you'd like to access this variable in `test2.c` you have to use `extern int test1_var;` in `test2.c`.

Complete sample:

```
$ cat test1.c 
int test1_var = 5;
$ cat test2.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int test1_var;

int main(void) {
    printf("test1_var = %d\n", test1_var);
    return 0;
}
$ gcc test1.c test2.c -o test
$ ./test
test1_var = 5
```

Comment: There's no "pseudo-definitions". It's a declaration.

Comment: In the above example, if I change the `extern int test1_var;` to `int test1_var;`, the linker (gcc 5.4.0) still passes. So, is `extern` really needed in this case?

Comment: @radiohead: In my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/15168), you will find the information that dropping the `extern` is a common extension that often works — and specifically works with GCC (but GCC is far from being the only compiler that supports it; it is prevalent on Unix systems).  You can look for "J.5.11" or the section "Not so good way" in my answer (I know — it _is_ long) and the text near that explains it (or tries to do so).

Comment: An extern declaration certainly doesn't have to be defined in another translation unit (and commonly is not). In fact, declaration and definition can be one and the same.

Answer (score 43):

Extern is the keyword you use to declare that the variable itself resides in another translation unit.

So you can decide to use a variable in a translation unit and then access it from another one, then in the second one you declare it as extern and the symbol will be resolved by the linker.

If you don't declare it as extern you'll get 2 variables named the same but not related at all, and an error of multiple definitions of the variable.

Comment: In other words the translation unit where extern is used knows about this variable, its type etc. and hence allows the source code in the underlying logic to use it, but it does not _allocate_ the variable, another translation unit will do that.   If both translation units were to declare the variable normally, there would be effectily two physical locations for the variable, with the associated "wrong" references within the compiled code, and with the resulting ambiguity for the linker.

Answer (score 36):

```
                 declare | define   | initialize |
                ----------------------------------

extern int a;    yes          no           no
-------------
int a = 2019;    yes          yes          yes
-------------
int a;           yes          yes          no
-------------
```

Declaration won't allocate memory (the variable must be defined for memory allocation) but the definition will. 
This is just another simple view on the extern keyword since the other answers are really great.

Answer (score 31):

I like to think of an extern variable as a promise that you make to the compiler.

When encountering an extern, the compiler can only find out its type, not where it "lives", so it can't resolve the reference.

You are telling it, "Trust me.  At link time this reference will be resolvable."

Comment: More generally, a *declaration* is a promise that the name will be resolvable to a exactly one definition at link time. An extern declares a variable without defining.

Answer (score 18):

extern tells the compiler to trust you that the memory for this variable is declared elsewhere, so it doesnt try to allocate/check memory.

Therefore, you can compile a file that has reference to an extern, but you can not link if that memory is not declared somewhere.

Useful for global variables and libraries, but dangerous because the linker does not type check.

Comment: The memory isn't declared. See the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/ for more details.

Answer (score 17):

Adding an `extern` turns a variable *definition* into a variable *declaration*. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/) as to what's the difference between a declaration and a definition.

Comment: What difference between `int foo` and `extern int foo` (file scope)? Both are declaration, isn't it?

Comment: @user14284: They are both declaration only in the sense that every definition is a declaration, too. But I linked to an explanation of this. ("See this thread as to what's the difference between a declaration and a definition.") Why don't you simple follow the link and read?

Answer (score 12):

The correct interpretation of extern is that you tell something to the compiler. You tell the compiler that, despite not being present right now, the variable declared will somehow be found by the linker (typically in another object (file)). The linker will then be the lucky guy to find everything and put it together, whether you had some extern declarations or not.

Answer (score 8):

In C a variable inside a file say example.c is given local scope. The compiler expects that the variable would have its definition inside the same file example.c and when it does not find the same , it would throw an error.A function on the other hand has by default global scope . Thus you do not have to explicitly mention to the compiler "look dude...you might find the definition of this function here". For a function including the file which contains its declaration is enough.(The file which you actually call a header file). 
   For example consider the following 2 files :
 example.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int a;
main(){
       printf("The value of a is <%d>\n",a);
}
```

example1.c

```
int a = 5;
```

Now when you compile the two files together, using the following commands :

step 1)cc -o ex example.c example1.c
step 2)./ex

You get the following output : The value of a is <5>

Answer (score 8):

***extern keyword is used with the variable for its identification as a global variable.***

> It also represents that you can use the variable declared using extern
>   keyword in any file though it is declared/defined in other file.

Answer (score 8):

**GCC ELF Linux implementation**

Other answers have covered the language usage side of view, so now let's have a look at how it is implemented in this implementation.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int not_extern_int = 1;
extern int extern_int;

void main() {
    printf("%d\n", not_extern_int);
    printf("%d\n", extern_int);
}
```

Compile and decompile:

```
gcc -c main.c
readelf -s main.o
```

Output contains:

```
Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
 9: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 not_extern_int
12: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND extern_int
```

The [System V ABI Update ELF spec](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/2003-12-17/contents.html) "Symbol Table" chapter explains:

> SHN_UNDEF This section table index means the symbol is undefined. When the link editor combines this object file with another that defines the indicated symbol, this file's references to the symbol will be linked to the actual definition.

which is basically the behavior the C standard gives to `extern` variables.

From now on, it is the job of the linker to make the final program, but the `extern` information has already been extracted from the source code into the object file.

Tested on GCC 4.8.

**C++17 inline variables**

In C++17, you might want to use inline variables instead of extern ones, as they are simple to use (can be defined just once on header) and more powerful (support constexpr). See: [What does 'const static' mean in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177437/what-does-const-static-mean-in-c-and-c/53883715#53883715)

Comment: It's not my down-vote, so I don't know. However, I'll proffer an opinion. Although looking at the output of `readelf` or `nm` can be helpful, you've not explained the fundamentals of how to make use of `extern`, nor completed the first program with the actual definition.  Your code doesn't even use `notExtern`.  There's a nomenclature problem, too: although `notExtern` is defined here rather than declared with `extern`, it is an external variable that could be accessed by other source files if those translation units contained a suitable declaration (which would need `extern int notExtern;`!).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the feedback! The standard behavior and usage recommendations have already been done in other answers, so I decided to show the implementation a bit as that really helped me grasp what is going on. Not using `notExtern` was ugly, fixed it. About nomenclature, let me know if you have a better name. Of course that would not be a good name for an actual program, but I think it fits the didactic role well here.

Comment: As to names, what about `global_def` for the variable defined here, and `extern_ref` for the variable defined in some other module?  Would they have suitably clear symmetry?  You still end up with `int extern_ref = 57;` or something like that in the file where it is defined, so the name isn't quite ideal, but within the context of the single source file, it is a reasonable choice.  Having `extern int global_def;` in a header isn't as much of a problem, it seems to me.  Entirely up to you, of course.

Answer (score 5):

`extern`
allows one module of your program to access a global variable or function declared in another module of your program.
You usually have extern variables declared in header files.

If you don't want a program to access your variables or functions, you use `static` which tells the compiler that this variable or function cannot be used outside of this module.

Answer (score 4):

First off, the `extern` keyword is not used for defining a variable; rather it is used for declaring a variable. I can say `extern` is a storage class, not a data type.

`extern` is used to let other C files or external components know this variable is already defined somewhere. Example: if  you are building a library, no need to define global variable mandatorily somewhere in library itself. The library will be compiled directly, but while linking the file, it checks for the definition.

Answer (score 4):

`extern` simply means a variable is defined elsewhere (e.g., in another file).

Answer (score 3):

`extern` is used so one `first.c` file can have full access to a global parameter in another `second.c` file.

The `extern` can be declared in the `first.c` file or in any of the header files `first.c` includes.

Comment: Note that the `extern` declaration should be in a header, not in `first.c`, so that if the type changes, the declaration will change too.  Also, the header that declares the variable should be included by `second.c` to ensure that the definition is consistent with the declaration.  The declaration in the header is the glue that holds it all together; it allows the files to be compiled separately but ensures they have a consistent view of the type of the global variable.

Answer (score 2):

With xc8 you have to be careful about declaring a variable
as the same type in each file as you could , erroneously,
declare something an `int` in one file and a `char` say in another.
This could lead to corruption of variables.

This problem was elegantly solved in a microchip forum some 15 years ago
    /* See "http:www.htsoft.com"                                          */
    /*  "forum/all/showflat.php/Cat/0/Number/18766/an/0/page/0#18766"

But this link seems to no longer work...

So I;ll quickly try to explain it;
make a file called global.h.

In it declare the following

```
#ifdef MAIN_C
#define GLOBAL
 /* #warning COMPILING MAIN.C */
#else
#define GLOBAL extern
#endif
GLOBAL unsigned char testing_mode; // example var used in several C files
```

Now in the file main.c

```
#define MAIN_C 1
#include "global.h"
#undef MAIN_C
```

This means in main.c the variable will be declared as an `unsigned char`.

Now in other files simply including global.h will
have it declared as an extern *for that file*.

```
extern unsigned char testing_mode;
```

But it will be correctly declared as an `unsigned char`.

The old forum post probably explained this a bit more clearly.
But this is a real potential `gotcha` when using a compiler
that allows you to declare a variable in one file and then declare it extern as a different type in another. The problems associated with
that are if you say declared testing_mode as an int in another file
it would think it was a 16 bit var and overwrite some other part of ram, potentially corrupting another variable. Difficult to debug!

Answer (score 0):

A very short solution I use to allow a header file to contain the extern reference or actual implementation of an object. The file that actually contains the object just does `#define GLOBAL_FOO_IMPLEMENTATION`. Then when I add a new object to this file it shows up in that file also without me having to copy and paste the definition.

I use this pattern across multiple files. So in order to keep things as self contained as possible, I just reuse the single GLOBAL & GLOBALINIT macros in each header. My headers look like this:

```
//file foo_globals.h
#pragma once  
#include "foo.h"  //contains Foo typedef
#include <atomic>

#ifdef GLOBAL  
#undef GLOBAL  
#endif  

#ifdef GLOBALINIT
#undef GLOBALINIT
#endif

#ifdef GLOBAL_FOO_IMPLEMENTATION  
#define GLOBAL  
#define GLOBALINIT(x) = x
#else  
#define GLOBAL extern  
#define GLOBALINIT(x)
#endif  

GLOBAL Foo foo1 GLOBALINIT({2, 3, 4})
GLOBAL std::atomic_bool flag1 GLOBALINIT(true);
GLOBAL std::atomic_uint counter1 GLOBALINIT(5);


//file main.cpp
#define GLOBAL_FOO_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "foo_globals.h"

//file uses_extern_foo.cpp
#include "foo_globals.h
```

Comment: Do you have a way to extend this idea to assigning an initial value to, say, foo1?

Comment: Updated the answer to show my updated header which has the initial value assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In short `extern` means that variable is defined in other module and its address will be known at link time. The compiler does not reserve memory in current module and knows the variable type. To understand `extern` is good to have at least little experience with assembler.

Answer (score 0):

extern keyword before a symbol (a var or function) tells the linker that it(the source file) uses an external symbol. This can be seen by running nm -a on such an object file (.o) which uses or assigns a value to a extern var (remember to declare a extern symbol on top like this extern int x or still better, use a header file with extern before vars and functions can be without extern; then in main assign a value to it like this x=5;), i find  undefined bss info (letter B written) against such an extern var(symbol). This means x is still unresolved and will be resolved when ld is run (during link-time).

why always use extern in headers?
If i don't use extern, just declare int x, the declaration becomes sort-of strong and without extern, and this redifines the same variable in every source that includes the header, effectively shadowing the original variable. therefore with just int x in a.h header, I redefine a new global variable x in every source that include this a.h. This var in the source, this without-extern var decl in headers shadows(it doesn't shadow exactly, it's redifining a global variable x in every source code that includes the header with just int x, without extern, when i include such header and try to compile .o from such files, every .o has its own definition of this global variable x which was included in the header without extern, and at the time of linking, I get the error multiple definition of variable or symbol x) an important variable defined somewhere of  somewhere else in the source files.
Important! it is necessary to use extern before vars in headers.
Functions are already extern by-default.