# ios - How to declare static variable?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, variables, static

Static Variable declared in C# like this :

```
private const string Host = "http://80dfgf7c22634nbbfb82339d46.cloudapp.net/";
private const string ServiceEndPoint = "DownloadService.svc/";
private const string ServiceBaseUrl = Host + ServiceEndPoint;
public static readonly string RegisteredCourse = ServiceBaseUrl + "RegisteredCourses";
public static readonly string AvailableCourses = ServiceBaseUrl + "Courses";
public static readonly string Register = ServiceBaseUrl + "Register?course={0}";
```

How to call this static variable in another class ?

Comment: As "static variable" is not a well defined term in Objective-C and different meanings are often confused it's not clear what you are asking here. Do you want a class variable with access through the class interface? Or is it about static storage duration?

Comment: And here I was thinking that "static variable" is extremly well defined in Objective-C, with exactly the same meaning as in C.

Answer (score 12):

**Answer :** use the `static` keyword.

**Syntax :** `static ClassName *const variableName = nil;` ( Updated **[ Added `const`]** as per the Comment by **Abizern** )

---

**Reason for update ( As per the comments by "Till " )** :
`static` when being used on a variable within a function/method will preserve its state even when the scope of that variable is left. When being used outside any function/method, it will make that variable invisible to other source files - it will be visible within that implementation file only when being used outside any function/method.
Hence a `const` with `static` helps the compiler to optimize it accordingly.

If you need more explanation on use of `const` with `static`, I found one beautiful link here : [const static](https://stackoverflow.com/q/177437/1603072).

---

**Use:**

You might have seen the use of **"static"** keyword in your tableview's delegate `- cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

`static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"reuseStaticIdentifier";`

Comment: I'd write `static NSString * const staticURL = @"something";`

Comment: @Abizern: Can you explain me the reason behind `const` ?

Comment: @Vin that variable will never be changed during runtime, hence a const helps the compiler to optimize it accordingly.

Comment: @Till: If that is the case then "What'll be the role of `static` in that line ?" or "`const` with `static` is just more optimum way to use `static`".

Comment: @Vin `static` when being used on a variable within a function/method will preserve its state even when the scope of that variable is left. When being used outside any function/method, it will make that variable invisible to other source files - it will be visible within that implementation file only when being used outside any function/method.

Comment: @Till: Ah... Thanks for the Explanation. I'm Editing my Answer with **Abizern**'s line and your Explanation.

Comment: The way you used `const` makes the pointee const (an object of type `ClassName`), not the pointer. That's a concept in C++, yet it does not exist in Objective-C. If you want to do what you described (help the compiler to optimize usage of the variable you have to put the `const` to the right of the *: `static ClassName * const variableName = nil;`. That does not make sense either because it would prevent the variable of ever having another value than `nil`;

Answer (score 5):

```
static NSString *aString = @""; // Editable from within .m file
NSString * const kAddressKey = @"address"; // Constant, visible within .m file

// in header file
extern NSString * const kAddressKey; // Public constant. Use this for e.g. dictionary keys.
```

To my knowledge public statics aren't a built-in feature of Objective-C. You can work around this by making a public class method that returns the static variable:

```
//.h
+ (NSString *)stringVariable;

//.m
static NSString * aString;
+ (NSString *)stringVariable
{
    return aString;
}
```

Most static objects can't be initialized at compile time (I think only strings actually). If you need to initialize them, you can do so in the `+ (void)initialize` method, which lazily gets called whenever that class is first referenced.

```
static UIFont *globalFont;
+ (void)initialize
{
    // Prevent duplicate initialize http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-05-22-objective-c-class-loading-and-initialization.html
    if (self == [ClassName class]) {
        globalFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Objective C is super set of C/C++ , so for static it follows C++/C convention, you should be able to use it

```
static <<datatype>> <<variableName>> = initialization
```

Hoping you would have tried this way , have you got any error, if yes, please add more clarity in your question

if thats case with `NSString` use following,

```
static NSString *pString = @"InitialValue";
```

and if you have to modify `NSString` in your code, make sure it must be `NSMutableString`.

Hope that's help ...

Comment: If its a static why would you want to modify it?

Comment: You have to explain more on this: to modify the string. Because this is valid also: `myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Add string %@", myString]`;

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C, no C++ involved. Actually the semantics of `static` slightly differ between C and C++.