# c++ - difference between const and static keyword in function header

Tags: c++, static, constants, qualifiers

Consider the following code:

```
class Test
{
public:
   //1
   int kon1() const;

   //2
   const int kon2();

   //3
   static int kon3();
};
```

As far as I know, the difference between function 1 and 2 is that :

1. Function 1 says that the function will not be able to change any data member's value
2. Function 2 says that it will return a const int

(If I have wrong understanding, please correct me)

My question is :
**As we can see there, if we want to make a function to be const function, the const keyword is placed behind. But why in function 3, the static function, the static keyword is placed in front?**

Comment: Because that's how the language is defined?  (Specifically, this is inherited from C.)

Comment: Function 1 says that none of variables or rather state of object shouldn't change but it can change state for mutable variables.

Comment: Your code answers your own question - it can't be at the front or you couldn't tell the difference between a `const` function returning `int` and a non-`const` function returning `const int`.  The choices really can seem pretty arbitrary though... e.g. `virtual` is in front while `override` is after....

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I do know that format is defined, but I am just not so satisfied by that answer

Comment: @TonyD Thanks for clarifying my understanding, but I am asking the difference between function 1 2 3, as bold in my question :)

Comment: I suppose it is because defining a static function in global space uses this form (from C), so they keep it for classes as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [const static](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177437/const-static)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `const` member functions must have the `const` keyword afterwards to avoid ambiguity with the return type.

For `static`, `virtual` and other keywords having a dramatic effect on how the function works, it's desirable to list it first so it's easier to see in the class definition.  For example, we can quickly scan through a list of member functions and spot all the `static` functions, or all the `virtual` ones - aiding our understanding of the overall use of the function.

Marking a member function `const` (or e.g. an `override`) is a less crucial distinction - if you have a non-`const` object you can invoke functions whether they're `const` or not, the appropriate `const`-ness is often obvious to the reading developer as they absorb the function return type and identifier, and in some corporate/project coding standards mutating functions are grouped above `const`-accessors, or `const` and non-`const` versions of the same member function are side by side to emphasise their similarities - then the differet `const`-ness stands out more.

All these factors combine to make the actual choices in C++ optimal for development, but you're right in observing that they're a bit inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `static` does not modify the variable's type. It modifies the memory address in which it will be located. It is used identically for function-type variables, and for data-type variables:

```
static int n;     // data
static int n ();  // function
```

The keyword `const` does modify the variable's type. For function-type variables, this keyword has two possible meanings:

1. modify the function's return value as type `const`:

   const int n ();   // function can be invoked from non-const objects only, and returns a const value
2. modify how this function may be invoked

   int n () const;   // function can be invoked const and non-const objects alike, and returns a non-const value`

Comment: In the second point " function can be invoked only from const objects". Think this can be confusing or my concept is not clear. I think it can be invoked from an object which was not declared const. Only it will act as a const object because no member variable can be modified inside that function except mutable variables.

Comment: It doesn't "modify the memory address". When used in a function, it modifies the lifetime of the object. When used outside of a function, it modifies the visibility of the object or function.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two concepts i.e. Storage Class with Storage Type.

C++ have following kind of storage classes

auto, register, static, extern & mutable

And following kind of storage type (based on what u can do with on storage)

read only (can be initialized ) --> this is const

read and write --> this is non const.

So when u define a variable/function u have tell in advance what kind of storage type u want to associate. Thats why u put static as first keyword in ur code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int kon1() const;
```

This function is readonly function intended to work on const data only.

```
   const int kon2();
```

This function can work on modifiable object but it returns type is readonly and caller can not modify this.