# Two variables in seperate translation units are violating the one definition rule?

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I have a variable `const char * FILENAME = "a/file/name"` defined in two .cpp files, called `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`.  Nothing includes these files directly, and they only include `a.h` and `b.h` respectively into themselves.  Both of those header files are then included in `main.cpp`

My problem is that I'm getting the following linker error:

`a.obj : error LNK2005: "char const * const FILENAME" (?FILENAME@@3PBDB) already defined in b.obj`

I don't use file scope variables very often, so I thought this would be okay...  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Yes this violates the one definition rule. You have two definitions of `FILENAME`. An easy fix is to make it `static const char FILENAME[] = "a/file/name";`

Comment: @Morlacke no it isn't. `FILENAME` is not `const` in OP's code.  The `const` applies to the things being pointed to.

Comment: Having said that, the error message shows `char const * const FILENAME` so maybe you made one of them `const` and the other one not `const`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they represent the same file, then you should declare one of them as `extern` to reference the definition in the other module.

`File1.cpp`

```
const char * FILENAME = "a/file/name";
```

`File2.cpp`

```
extern const char * FILENAME;
```

If they are two individual variables which happen to have the same name, then you should declare them as static so they are visible only inside the compilation unit.

```
static const char * FILENAME = "a/file/name";
```

The reason why this happens is, because the implicit static applies only to const objects. Your pointer is not const though, only the referenced object is const.

To achieve this you would have to write:

```
const char * const FILENAME = "a/file/name";
```

Comment: they are the second.  I guess I mistakenly assumed `static` was inplicit when defined at the file scope.  Thanks!

Comment: In C++ static const and const is the same declaration.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177437/what-does-const-static-mean-in-c-and-c

Comment: Personally I would discourage the usage of global variables when not really neccessary, but that depends on the usage of course.

Comment: @Morlacke Only for top-level `const` which Devolus's example mistakenly omits. `const char *const FILENAME = "a/file/name";` would do the job.  There's no harm in including `static` anyway though.

Comment: @M.M, can you explain what you mean by top-level const?

Comment: @Devolus a `const` which qualifies the variable.  `const int x` - top level, `x` cannot be modified.  `const int *y;` - not top level, we can write `y = z;`

Comment: @M.M, OK, I see what you mean. Yes, that's right, because FILENAME is not const, only the content of FILENAME is considered const here.

Comment: @Morlacke Oviously not with his compiler/linker, or he wouldn't have gotten the error message.

Comment: Oh, so that's what it was.  Morlacke is right, but I needed to define the pointer as constant as well.  So with the definition `const char *const FILENAME` it being static is then implied.  I get mixed up by that sometimes