# C/C++: static const vs simply const in .h/.hpp

Tags: c++, c, static, constants, extern

While having a polemic discussion with a colleague regarding the use of **static** for data declared within h/hpp files whenever you choose to put the data in there, I was surprised to discover that:

```
const float a[100] = {1};
```

declared in a h/hpp **does NOT throw a linker error** if the header file is included by different translation units. At first I thought that it's because **a** is not used in either of them or because of some linker optimization, but even if I use **a** and build the debug configuration, still no linker error. I don't know why but I was sure that omitting static would throw a linker error in this scenario (I'm arguing it's always good practice to use **static** for data defined in headers and it's *even better practice* instead to **not define big data (e.g. arrays) in headers in the first place**, to avoid memory waste).

Am I remembering this wrong?

Comment: Also see "const is implicitly static" and can be inlined in C++17: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177437/what-does-const-static-mean-in-c-and-c

Comment: There are **two** languages called C and C++ that are **distinct** languages, and within implementations there is some leeway to how this is handled... Which language do you want to ask about, and which implementation?!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I thought it was clear from the title I was asking about both. I expected the behavior to be the same regarding this, it seems like my C background mislead me