# Why is extern required for const int but not for const char*

Tags: c++, c++17, extern

I'm confused about why I need `extern` or not for `int` vs `char*` in the definition in my extern.cpp file. I have the following test program:

```
// extern.cpp
extern const int my_int = 1;
const char* my_str = "FOO";
```

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

extern const int my_int;
extern const char* my_str;

int main() {
  std::cout << my_int;
  std::cout << my_str;
  return 0;
}
```

If I remove the `extern` from `extern const int my_int = 1;` then I get `undefined reference to 'my_int'`. If I add extern to `const char* my_str = "FOO";` then I get a warning `'my_str' initialized and declared 'extern'`. Why do I need `extern` on `my_int` but adding it to `my_str` generates a warning?

This is C++17 on gcc 10.1.0. The specific commands are:

```
/usr/bin/g++-10  -g -std=gnu++17 -o main.cpp.o -c main.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-10  -g -std=gnu++17 -o extern.cpp.o -c extern.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-10  -g main.cpp.o extern.cpp.o -o TestExtern
```

Comment: `my_str` is not `const`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use extern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c)

Comment: I was wrong actually @Trovor explains why `const` has issue with `extern`

Comment: `extern` is never intended to be used with initialization. Use `extern` in header files and then in some `c` or `cpp` file define the actual variable, without using `extern`. The `extern` declaration from the header file can be in scope and its types will have to match.

Comment: So if you change `my_str` to `const char * const my_str` then you will have the same issue.

Comment: Not sure the duplicate is good. This question is really about a misunderstanding of `const` not about `extern`.

Comment: @john there is an answer provided by Trovor which address exactly this issue

Comment: @Slava Not really because I think the OP misunderstanding is about the meaning of `const` when applied to a pointer. But Andrey deals with this point below, so I guess it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is caused by different [linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage) of `my_int` and `my_str` variables.

`my_int` is a `const`-qualified variable in namespace scope, which means it has internal linkage by default. In other words, its visibility is limited to the current translation unit, unless you mark it `extern`. Additionally, internal linkage constants must have an initializer.

`my_str`, on the other hand, is *not* `const`-qualified. Don't be confused by the `const` qualifier in the pointer type, as that qualifier is part of the pointed type. The pointer itself is mutable, and you could assign it a different value in run time. Since this is a non-`const` variable in namespace scope, it has external linkage, and as such refers to a single pointer object in the scope of the whole program.

Comment: You've got your internal linkage a bit wrong. Constants are not necessarily internal. You can declare an `extern const int` but don't try to set it to anything. That will create a linker reference to the actual definition of the `const int`. It will not be able to inline the const int into the code unless you use LTO but it will be able to reference it via its memory location.

Comment: @ZanLynx I've updated the wording. I was talking about constants not explicitly marked as `extern`.

Comment: This is also important: https://stackoverflow.com/a/178259/1387438

Comment: This is a great reason to write `char const *` instead. It's the same type, but makes it clearer that the pointed-to value is what is const. The syntax `const X` should IMO never be used. `const` always goes to the right of the part of the type it applies to; it's allowed on the left in some cases for historical reasons, but this creates confusion. In this case the example types would be `int const` and `char const *` and now we can much more clearly see that the pointer value is not const because `const` is not the last token in the type.

Comment: @cdho west const worst const east const best const

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont [One const, two const, red const, blue const](https://genius.com/Dr-seuss-one-fish-two-fish-red-fish-blue-fish-annotated).

Comment: @cdhowie unfortunately there are already too many bad habits in C++ from C. Constants in UPPERCASE, `const` is usually placed wrong place, `*` binds to variable not to type etc.