# When to use static string vs. #define

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

I am a little confused as to when it's best to use:

```
static NSString *AppQuitGracefullyKey = @"AppQuitGracefully";
```

instead of

```
#define AppQuitGracefullyKey    @"AppQuitGracefully"
```

I've seen questions like this for C or C++, and I think what's different here is that this is specifically for Objective C, utilizing an object, and on a device like the iPhone, there may be stack, code space or memory issues that I don't yet grasp.

One usage would be:

```
appQuitGracefully =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: AppQuitGracefullyKey];
```

Or it is just a matter of style?

Thanks.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you use a static, the compiler will embed exactly one copy of the string in your binary and just pass pointers to that string around, resulting in more compact binaries. If you use a #define, there will be a separate copy of the string stored in the source on each use. Constant string coalescing will handle many of the dups but you're making the linker work harder for no reason.

Comment: Constant string coalescing is the work of the compiler, not the linker.

Comment: This is not right. Objective-c uses [String Interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) as described [here](http://nshipster.com/equality/). `#define` does _not_ store a copy of the string for each use. And @kennytm is right, the compiler does that, not the linker

Comment: @AndréFratelli In point of fact, constant string coalescing is a linker optimisation, and it is implemented by the static linker in OS X/macOS for both C and CF/NSStrings. It is not done using string interning, and it is not done by the compiler (though the compiler may coalesce strings itself before writing out the object file its generating). You can see the code that does this in [the linker sources](http://opensource.apple.com/source/ld64/ld64-264.3.102/). So no, kennytm is not right; it really is the linker.

Comment: @alastair I guess it makes sense, as the linker needs to resolve the symbols from all the object files. Back then I found some source (don't remember which) explaining that the compiler does implement interning, so maybe it makes sense that both are doing it. Anyway, the point being that `#define` does not create copies, that still holds regardless.

Answer (score 15):

See ["static const" vs "#define" vs "enum"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c). The main advantage of `static` is type safety.

Other than that, the `#define` approach introduces a flexibility of inline string concatenation which cannot be done with static variables, e.g.

```
#define ROOT_PATH @"/System/Library/Frameworks"
[[NSBundle bundleWithPath:ROOT_PATH@"/UIKit.framework"] load];
```

but this is probably not a good style :).

Comment: I'm so surprised. I had no idea `@"one string"@" another string"` was valid.

Comment: From your comment to cdespinosa's answer, does it mean using #define will not produce duplicatation?

Comment: @user523234 it does. The compiler uses [String Interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)

Answer (score 5):

I actually would recommend neither, you should use `extern` instead. Objective-c already defines `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` which is [more portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953221/foundation-export-vs-extern) than `extern`, so a global `NSString` instance would look something like this:

.h

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const AppQuitGracefullyKey;
```

.m

```
NSString * const AppQuitGracefullyKey = @"AppQuitGracefully";
```

I usually put these in declaration files (such as `MyProjectDecl.h`) and import whenever I need.

There are a few differences to these approaches:

- *#define* has several downsides, such as not being type safe. It is true that there are workarounds for that (such as `#define ((int)1)`) but what's the point? And besides, there are debugging disadvantages to that approach. Compilers prefer constants. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153156/define-vs-const-in-objective-c) discussion.
- *static* globals are [visible in the file they are declared.](http://nshipster.com/c-storage-classes/)
- *extern* makes the variable visible to all files. That contrasts with static.

Static and extern differ in visibility. It's also notable that neither of these approaches duplicates the string (not even `#define`) as the compiler uses [String Interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) to prevent that. In [this NSHipster post](http://nshipster.com/equality/) they show proof:

```
NSString *a = @"Hello";
NSString *b = @"Hello";
BOOL wtf = (a == b); // YES
```

The operator `==` returns `YES` only if the two variables point at the same instance. And as you can see, it does.

The conclusion is: use `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` for global constants. It's debug friendly and will be visible allover your project.

Answer (score 4):

After doing some search ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032375/difference-between-nsstring-literals) question/answer among other things) I think it is important to say that anytime when you are using string literal `@"AppQuitGracefully"` constant string is created, and no matter how many times you use it it will point to the **same** object.

So I think (and I apologize me if I'm wrong) that this sentence in above answer is wrong: `If you use a #define, there will be a separate copy of the string stored in the source on each use.`

Answer (score 3):

I use `static` when I need to export NSString symbols from a library or a framework. I use `#define` when I need a string in many places that I can change easily. Anyway, the compiler and the linker will take care of optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

**USING #define :**

you can't debug the value of identifier

work with #define and other macros is a job of Pre-Processor,
When you hit Build/Run first it will preprocess the source code, it will work with all the macros(starting with symbol #),

Suppose, you have created,

```
#define LanguageTypeEnglish @"en"
```

and used this at 2 places in your code.

```
NSString *language = LanguageTypeEnglish;
NSString *languageCode = LanguageTypeEnglish;
```

it will replace **"LanguageTypeEnglish"** with `@"en"`, at all places.
So 2 copies of `@"en"` will be generated.
i.e

```
NSString *language = @"en";
NSString *languageCode = @"en";
```

Remember, till this process, compiler is not in picture.

After preprocessing all the macros, complier comes in picture, and it will get input code like this,

```
NSString *language = @"en";
NSString *languageCode = @"en";
```

and compile it.

**USING static :**

it respects scope and is type-safe.
you can debug the value of identifier

During compilation process if compiler found,

```
static NSString *LanguageTypeRussian = @"ru";
```

then it will check if the variable with the same name stored previously,
if yes, it will only pass the pointer of that variable,
if no, it will create that variable and pass it's pointer, next time onwards it will only pass the pointer of the same.

So using static, only one copy of variable is generated within the scope.