# Why are these two NSString pointers the same?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

When I `alloc` and `init` two `NSString` variables and compare their pointers, they are the same. Here's a snippet that shows this:

```
NSString *s1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello world"];
NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello world"];

if (s1 == s2) {
    NSLog(@"==");
}else {
    NSLog(@"!=");
}
```

Why are `s1` and `s2` the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between NSString literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032375/difference-between-nsstring-literals)

Comment: In your if statement, you are not comparing the pointers, but the data they point to, and looking at the code, I'd say "hello world" is 100% equal to "hello world".

Comment: @NSArray: No, that's pointer comparison. You need to send a message (`isEqual:` or `isEqualToString:`) to compare the values.

Comment: @NSArray He _is_ comparing pointers. Comparing objects would entail using "*s1 == *s2" (which has no meaning for strings - you can't overload == in Objective-C). String contents are compared with `-isEqualToString:`, as pointed by @Josh. It will return `YES` provided the contents match, even if you are comparing two different instances.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are three things going on here:

Firstly, the two identical string literals you're passing in to `initWithString:` will have the same address to start. This is an obvious optimization for constant data.

Secondly, when you nest alloc and init with strings, the runtime performs an optimization, the alloc call essentially becomes a no-op. This is done using the `NSPlaceholderString` class. This means the pointer you get back here will be coming from `initWithString:`, not from alloc.

Thirdly, under the hood, `initWithString:` is calling `CFStringCreateCopy`, which as you may find, has the following behavior: Since this routine is for creating immutable strings, it has an optimization. It simply calls `CFRetain()` and returns the same object that was passed in.

Thanks for the very interesting question. I had fun figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

@"hello world" strings are of class `NSConstantString`.if you use @"hello world" in two places, they will be referencing the very same object.

From [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000148-SW1).

> The simplest way to create a string object in source code is to use
>   the Objective-C @"..." construct:
>
> NSString *temp = @"/tmp/scratch"; Note that, when creating a string
>   constant in this fashion, you should use UTF-8 characters. Such an
>   object is created at compile time and exists throughout your program’s
>   execution. **The compiler makes such object constants unique** on a
>   per-module basis, and they’re never deallocated, though you can retain
>   and release them as you do any other object. You can also send
>   messages directly to a string constant as you do any other string:
>
> BOOL same = [@"comparison" isEqualToString:myString];