# Why aren't these NSString instance variables allocated?

Tags: ios, objective-c

first post here. I was reading through an Objective-C tutorial earlier, and I saw that they had made a couple of NSString instance variables like this:

```
@implementation MyViewController {
NSString *stringOne;
NSString *stringTwo;
NSString *stringThree;
NSString *stringFour;
NSString *stringFive;
}
```

And then simply used them in ViewDidLoad like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

stringOne = @"Hello.";
stringTwo = @"Goodbye.";
stringThree = @"Can't think of anything else to say.";
stringFour = @"Help...";
stringFive = @"Pheww, done.";
}
```

How have they done this without instantiating the string? Why does this work? Surely you'd have to do something like `stringOne = [NSString stringFromString:@"Hello."];` to properly alloc and init the object before you could simply do `stringOne= @"Hello.";`.

Sorry if this a dumb question, but I find these little things throw me.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: They are instantiating them via an assignment to a string literal.

Comment: Never use `stringWithFormat` unless you actually have a string that you need to format.

Comment: It took me too long to get supporting link on mobile to edit last comment. Compiler actually allocates those strings see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032375/difference-between-nsstring-literals

Comment: Also, people who do stuff like `NSObject *object = [[NSObject alloc] init]; object = somethingElse;` are doing it wrong so don't follow their example :)

Comment: Thank you guys. I had no idea that I didn't have instantiate NSString when using `@"..."`.

Comment: Thanks Carl. So instead of that it should be `NSObject *object = somethingElse`, as that `somethingElse` is already instanced, `object` doesn't need to be, right?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8032375/581994

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Apple String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html):

> ### Creating Strings
>
> The simplest way to create a string object in source code is to use the Objective-C  @"..." construct:

```
NSString *temp = @"Contrafibularity";
```

> Note that, when creating a string constant in this fashion, you should use UTF-8 characters. Such an object is created at compile time and exists throughout your program’s execution. The compiler makes such object constants unique on a per-module basis, and they’re never deallocated. You can also send messages directly to a string constant as you do any other string:

```
BOOL same = [@"comparison" isEqualToString:myString];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's nice and concise. That bit at the bottom is very useful; it's going to be strange thinking of `@"..."` as something that can receive messages.

Comment: the @ in objective-c is an object operator, everything starting with it is an object, for example `@11` is a `NSNumber` that *store* the value 11, not an `int`. On the other hands, if you think this is the right answer to your question please accept it

Answer (score 3):

String constants like `@"Hello"` are already allocated and initialized for you by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if `@"..."` is allocated and initialised, I never have to instantiate NSString, correct?

Comment: Right, it is a preallocated `NSString*` object (technically a `const NSString* const`).  You can use a string literal (such as `@"...:"`) anywhere that takes an `NSString*` object.  (Except of course that it's a constant and can't be modified)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much :) All clear. I've been instantiating NSString unnecessarily far too often in my code... Seems like a massive clean up is in order.

Answer (score 2):

actually this can be said "syntactic sugar". there are some other type of NS object that can be creatable without allocation or formatting. 
e.g:

```
NSNumber *intNumber1 = @42;
NSNumber *intNumber2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:42];

NSNumber *doubleNumber1 = @3.1415926;
NSNumber *doubleNumber2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:3.1415926];

NSNumber *charNumber1 = @'A';
NSNumber *charNumber2 = [NSNumber numberWithChar:'A'];

NSNumber *boolNumber1 = @YES;
NSNumber *boolNumber2 = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

NSNumber *unsignedIntNumber1 = @256u;
NSNumber *unsignedIntNumber2 = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:256u];

NSNumber *floatNumber1 = @2.718f;
NSNumber *floatNumber2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.718f];

// an array with string and number literals
NSArray *array1 = @[@"foo", @42, @"bar", @3.14];

// and the old way
NSArray *array2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo", 
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:42], 
                                            @"bar", 
                                            [NSNumber numberWithDouble:3.14], 
                                            nil];

// a dictionary literal
NSDictionary *dictionary1 = @{ @1: @"red", @2: @"green", @3: @"blue" };

// old style
NSDictionary *dictionary2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"red", @1, 
                                                                       @"green", @2, 
                                                                       @"blue", @3, 
                                                                       nil];
```

for more information, see "[Something wonderful: new Objective-C literal syntax](http://blog.ablepear.com/2012/02/something-wonderful-new-objective-c.html)".

Comment: Where does this answer address the question about `NSString`?

Comment: You Sir, have blown my mind. I've added this to my little book of syntax as it's comprehensive and helps me to realise when to alloc/init and when to not. Thanks. By the way, sorry I can't +1 as I don't have enough rep apparently.

Comment: @rmaddy i explained that this is just a syntax issue and give other examples. did you read my answer?

Comment: @rmaddy I think he realised that I had understood the NSString problem and was providing further examples to help me understand the concept.

Comment: I get all of that. I'm just pointing out that this answer doesn't answer the question. It only provides unrelated, but useful, information.

Answer (score 2):

Just remember this basic thing:-

```
NSString *string = ...
```

This is a pointer to an object, "not an object"!

Therefore, the statement: `NSString *string = @"Hello";` assigns the address of `@"Hello"` object to the pointer `string`.

`@"Hello"` is interpreted as a constant string by the compiler and the compiler itself allocates the memory for it.

Similarly, the statement

```
NSObject *myObject = somethingElse;
```

assigns the address of `somethingElse` to pointer `myObject`, and that `somethingElse` should already be allocated and initialised.

Therefore, the statement: `NSObject *myObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];` allocates and initializes a `NSObject` object at a particular memory location and assigns its address to `myObject`.

Hence, `myObject` contains address of an object in memory, for ex: 0x4324234.

Just see that we are not writing `"Hello"` but `@"Hello"`, this @ symbol before the string literal tells the compiler that this is an object and it returns the address.

I hope this would answer your question and clear your doubts. :)