# Passing an object between view controllers, does the object become null in new controller?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, oop

I am new to Objective C and trying to get my head around OOP in apps as opposed to web OOP.

Lets say I have a class `theDay.h` and `theDay.m`

setDay is a class which in one view controller it takes in a value, say a integer, via a set method, and then in another view controller using a get method you can get the value example: (if my syntax is wrong sorry,  very new!)

```
[theDay setDay:1];
```

then to get it:

```
int day;
day = [theDay getDay];
```

Is this correct and is the object available throughout the views?

Comment: setDay is a class or a method?

Comment: Ahh oops, let me edit sorry!

Comment: `setDay.h` and `setDay.m` are the same "class". Moreover, I think you want it to be a method (not a class).

Comment: Sorry! My mistake, I think I have corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the object will be available! You are passing reference to that object, not the object!! But you have to allocate that object somewhere in the code!

[This Link would help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732399/why-arent-these-nsstring-instance-variables-allocated/15733204#15733204)