# "FOUNDATION_EXPORT" vs "extern"

Tags: objective-c, extern

I would like to ask what's the reason behind using `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` instead of `extern` in *Objective C* projects.

I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c) and using `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` has earned whopping 340 points (1st place) whereas using `extern` only 74 points (2nd place).

Could anybody explain why? Is there any practical reason for using `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` instead of `extern`?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't really take votes on those answers to be votes for or against the techniques they mention. For one thing, the answer with `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` is nearly two years older than the other!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668018/when-to-use-uikit-extern-vs-just-extern/17669269#17669269

Answer (score 178, accepted):

If you look in NSObjCRuntime.h (in Foundation) you will see that `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` compiles to `extern` in C, `extern "C"` in C++, and other things in Win32. So, it's more compatible across languages and operating systems. For many projects, this won't make any difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will keep using `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` then.