# #define negative numbers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor

Simple question, but I cannot seem to find the answer. Is it okay to use `#define` to define a negative number, as in:

```
#define kGravity -9.8
```

XCode is changing the 9.8 to the color of my numbers I have set (purple), but the `-` is being shown as the same color as the define statement (orange).

Is this legal? Will it compile?

Comment: Usually better to have `()` around any definitions like that just in case the expression they end up in causes confusion because of a sequence of operators. Can't think of an example right now... Did you try to compile it? What happened?

Comment: It did build successfully. I just want to make sure that when I use code like `float v = vo + (kGravity*time);` that kGravity will be substituted as `-9.8` instead of `+9.8`

Comment: You could always try to `printf("my number is %f\n", kGravity)` to see what happens. Not sure why you need to ask the community?

Comment: @Floris My philosophy about asking questions like this is that it will now show up in search results for anyone else with a similar question, helping others, not just myself; that's why I asked it here. As you can see by my reputation, I am not a newbie user here. I'm just trying to help the community with what I thought to be a reasonable question.

Comment: Fair points - I accept your reasons. But the way you asked the question ("will it compile?") suggested you didn't do any research. As a "not a newbie" you should know better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try it? It should work fine.

However, I would encourage you to not use pre-processor macros, but instead use real constants.

```
static const float kGravity = -9.8f;
```

Preprocessor directives are a bit frowned upon, in general. Here's some more info on the subject: [#define vs const in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153156/define-vs-const-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 4):

It is absolutely legal to define negative constants with `#define`. What you discovered is most likely a bug in Xcode's code coloring, which will probably be fixed in one of the future revisions.

Comment: Grammatically, the `-` is not part of the number.  It is a unary operator.  Hence the “Numbers” coloring doesn't apply.  It is colored according to the “Preprocessor Statements” or “Plain Text” setting, depending on the context.