# Global variables in my Constants file

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, global

Until now if I needed access to a global variable across my app i just added

```
#define PATH [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.url.com"]
```

To my `Constants.h` file.

I need to fetch the `PATH` value from my server.
How can i assign the value I'm getting from a server to a macro \string like the above and still be able to use just the variable `PATH` anywhere in my app? (Without naming the class like a property use such as `class.PATH`

This works:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSString* PATH;

@interface Constants : NSObject
+(void)getPathFromServer;

@end
```

And `PATH` is accessible from anywhere in my app but I'm not sure if that should be the way to go.

Comment: why not define macro directly like `#define PTAH @"www.url.com"`.

Comment: @johnMa There's a chance it will change in the future and I'd like to keep it dynamic without updating the app just for the url.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand so far, you need to define a macro which dynamic change it's url content.
If I'm right , you may need a `Vararg Macros` which takes a variable.

```
#define PATH(...) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",__VA_ARGS__]
```

Comment: Hmm, I only need to set PATH once per app lunch, not every time I call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extern keyword
Example :

```
//Header file
extern NSString * const path;

// .m file under implementation
NSString * const Ppath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.url.com"];
```

Have a look at these 
[Constants in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)
[#define vs const in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153156/define-vs-const-in-objective-c)

Comment: I need to set it in compile time, for example under the method `getPathFromServer` in the m file I mentioned above. Trying to place `NSString * const Ppath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.url.com"];` inside a method gave me a link error. (Is it even possible to set const inside a method?)