# What does "const" mean in return types, in function parameters, and after member functions?

Tags: c++, constants

```
const int* const Method3(const int* const&) const;
```

Can someone explain the usage of each of the const?

Comment: I really like this method for deciphering complicated declarations: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Read this: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness

The final `const` means that the function `Method3` does not modify the non mutable members of its class.

`const int* const` means a constant pointer to a constant int: i.e. a pointer that cannot be changed, to an int that cannot be changed: the only difference between this and `const int&` is that it can be `null`

`const int* const&` means a reference to a constant pointer to a constant int. Usually pointers are not passed by reference; `const int* &` makes more sense because it would mean that the pointer could be changed during the method call, which would be the only reason I can see to pass a pointer by reference, `const int* const&` is to all intents and purposes the same as `const int* const` except that it is probably less efficient as pointers are plain old data (POD) types and these should, in general be passed by value.

Comment: "const int* const means a constant pointer to a constant int: i.e. a pointer that cannot be changed, to an int that cannot be changed" Slight correction. Things pointed to by a `const int*` can still be changed, just not via that pointer. `int x = 1; const int* p = &x; x = 2;` succeeds, while `*p = 2` fails.

Answer (score 113):

It's easier to understand if you rewrite that as the completely equivalent

```
// v───v───v───v───v───v───v───v───v───v───v───v─┬┐
//                                               ││
//  v──#1    v─#2             v──#3    v─#4      #5
   int const * const Method3(int const * const&) const;
```

then read it from right to left.

#5 says that the entire function declaration to the left is `const`, which implies that this is necessarily a member function rather than a free function.

#4 says that the pointer to the left is `const` (may not be changed to point to a different address).

#3 says that the `int` to the left is `const` (may not be changed to have a different value).

#2 says that the pointer to the left is `const`.

#1 says that the `int` to the left is `const`.

Putting it all together, you can read this as a `const` member function named `Method3` that takes a reference to a `const` pointer to an `int const` (or a `const int`, if you prefer) and returns a `const` pointer to an `int const` (`const int`).

(N.b. #2 [is entirely superfluous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12051274/636019).)

Answer (score 23):

First of all `const T` is equivalent to `T const`.

`const int* const` is therefore equivalent to `int const * const`.

When reading expressions with lots of `const` tokens and pointers in them, always try to **read them from right to left** (after applying the transformation above). So in this case the return value is a *const pointer to a const `int`*. Making the pointer itself `const` makes no sense here since the return value isn't a lvalue that could be modified. Making the pointee `const`, however, guarantees that the caller may not modify the `int` (or array of `int`s) returned by `Method3`.

`const int*const&` becomes `int const*const&`, so it is a *reference to a const pointer to a const `int`*. Passing a const pointer by references male no sense either - you can't modify the referenced value since the pointer is `const` and references and pointers occupy equal storage so there aren't any space savings either.

The last `const` indicates that the method does not modify the `this` object. The `this` pointer within the method body will have the (theoretical) declaration `T const * const this`. This means that a `const T*` object will be able to call `T::Method3()`.

Comment: Voting up this (and the similar answer of ildjarn), in part for making the point that the whole thing makes more sense if you don't put the first `const`s at the head of the phrase. This is precisely why I think it is bad practice to put `const` there, even though the language allows it, and it is the most common usage.

Answer (score 12):

An easy way to remember the rules of `const` is to think about it this way: `const` applies to the thing on its left, unless there's nothing on its left.

So in the case of `const int * const`, the first const has nothing on its left, so it applies to `int` and the second one does have something on its left, so it applies to the pointer.

This rule also tells you what would happen in the case where you have `const int const *`. Since both const's apply to `int` this expression is redundant and therefore invalid.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use the ["clock" or "spiral" method](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) where starting from the identifier name (in this case `Method3`) you read back-and-forth from left-to-right-back-to-left, etc. in order to decode naming conventions.  So `const int* const Method3(const int* const&) const` is a class method that doesn't change any class members (of some un-named class) and takes a constant reference to a pointer that points to a constant `int` and returns a constant pointer to a constant `int`.

Hope this helps,

Jason

Answer (score 3):

```
const /* don't modify the int or array of ints' value(s) */
int* const /* as a retval, ignored. useless declaration */
Method3(const /* don't modify the int or array of ints' value(s) */
int* const /* don't modify the pointer's value, the address to which `pointer` points to. e.g. you cannot say `++pointer` */
&) const; /* this method does not modify the instance/object which implements the method */
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to remember the const in C++ is when you see some code in form like:

```
XXX const;
const YYY;
```

XXX, YYY will be a constant component,
`XXX const` form:

```
function ( def var ) const;    ------#1
* const;                       ------#2
```

`const YYY` form:

```
const int;                     ------#3
const double;
```

People usually use these types. When you see `"const&"` somewhere, don't feel confused, const is describing something before itself.
so the answer of this problem is self-evident now.

```
const int* const Method3(const int* const&) const;
  |          |             |          |       |
  #3         #2            #3         #2      #1
```

Answer (score 2):

I only want to mention that `const int* const&` is indeed a constant reference to `const int*`. For example:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 1;
int* p = &i;
int* q = &j;
const int* const& cpref = p;
cpref = q; //Error: assignment of read-only reference 'cpref'
```

It's also the case for `int* const&`, Which means:"A constant reference to `int*`".
But `const int*&` is a non-constant reference to `const int*`.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Reading from right to left makes understanding modifiers easier.

A const method that takes a reference to a const pointer to a const int called `Method3` which returns a const pointer to a const int.

1. A const method can't modify members
   (unless they are expicitly
   `mutable`)
2. A const pointer can't be
   changed to point to something else
3. A const int (or any other type) can't
   be modified

Answer (score 1):

const #1:  The pointer returned by Method3 refers to a const int.

const #2:  The pointer value returned by the function, itself, is const.  This is a useless const (though gramatically valid), because the return value from a function cannot be an l-value.

const #3:  The pointer type passed by reference to the function points to a const int.

const #4:  The pointer value passed by reference to the function is, itself, a const pointer.  Declaring a value that is passed to a function as const would normally be pointless, but this value is passed by reference, so it can be meaningful.

const #5:  The function (presumably a member function) is const, meaning that it is not allowed to (a) assign new values to any members of the object of which it is part or (b) call a non-const member function on the object or any of its members.

Answer (score 0):

- `const` at the end of the method is the qualifier signifying the state of the object is n't going to be changed.
- `const int*const&` signifies receiving by reference a const pointer to a const location.
  It can neither change to point to a different location nor change the value it is pointing at.
- `const int*const` is the return value which is also a constant pointer to a constant location.

Answer (score 0):

A few examples might be nice to demonstrate this concept, the more the better imho.

```
class TestClass
{
private:
   int iValue;
   int* oValuePtr;
   int& oValueRef;

public:
   int TestClass::ByValMethod1(int Value)
   {
      // Value can be modified
      Value++;

      // iValue can be modified
      iValue = Value;
      iValue += 1;

      // Return value can be modified
      return ++iValue;
   }

   int TestClass::ByValMethod2(const int Value)
   {
      // Value *cannot* be modified
      // Variable is const variable
      Value++;

      // iValue can be modified
      iValue = Value;
      iValue += 1;

      // Return value can be modified
      return ++iValue;
   }

   const int TestClass::ByValMethod3(int Value)
   {
      // Value can be modified
      Value++;

      // iValue can be modified
      iValue = Value;
      iValue += 1;

      // Return value can be modified
      return ++iValue;
   }

   const int TestClass::ByValMethod4(const int Value)
   {
      // Value *cannot* be modified
      // Variable is const variable
      Value++;

      // iValue can be modified
      iValue = Value;
      iValue += 1;

      // Return value can be modified
      return ++iValue;
   }

   const int TestClass::ByValMethod5(const int Value) const
   {
      // Value *cannot* be modified
      // Variable is const variable
      Value++;

      // iValue *cannot* be modified
      // Access through a const object
      iValue = Value;
      iValue += 1;

      // Return value *cannot* be modified
      // Access through a const object
      return ++iValue;
   }

   int& TestClass::ByRefMethod1(int& Value)
   {
      // Value can be modified
      Value++;

      // oValueRef can be modified
      oValueRef = Value;
      oValueRef += 1;

      // Return value can be modified
      return ++oValueRef;
   }

   int& TestClass::ByRefMethod2(const int& Value)
   {
      // Value *cannot* be modified
      // Variable is const variable
      Value++;

      // oValueRef can be modified
      oValueRef = Value;
      oValueRef += 1;

      // Return value can be modified
      return ++oValueRef;
   }

   const int& TestClass::ByRefMethod3(int& Value)
   {
      // Value can be modified
      Value++;

      // oValueRef can be modified
      oValueRef = Value;
      oValueRef += 1;

      // Return value can be modified
      return ++oValueRef;
   }

   const int& TestClass::ByRefMethod4(const int& Value)
   {
      // Value *cannot* be modified
      // Variable is const variable
      Value++;

      // oValueRef can be modified
      oValueRef = Value;
      oValueRef += 1;

      // Return value can be modified
      return ++oValueRef;
   }

   const int& TestClass::ByRefMethod5(const int& Value) const
   {
      // Value *cannot* be modified
      // Variable is const variable
      Value++;

      // oValueRef can be modified
      oValueRef = Value;
      oValueRef += 1;

      // Return value can be modified
      return ++oValueRef;
   }

   int* TestClass::PointerMethod1(int* Value)
   {
      // Value can be modified
      Value++;

      // oValuePtr can be assigned
      oValuePtr = Value;

      // oValuePtr can be modified
      oValuePtr += 1;

      // Return value can be modified
      return ++oValuePtr;
   }

   int* TestClass::PointerMethod2(const int* Value)
   {
      // Value can be modified
      Value++;

      // oValuePtr cannot be assigned
      // const int* to int*
      oValuePtr = Value;

      // oValuePtr can be modified
      oValuePtr += 1;

      // Return value can be modified
      return ++oValuePtr;
   }

   const int* TestClass::PointerMethod3(int* Value)
   {
      // Value can be modified
      Value++;

      // oValuePtr can be assigned
      oValuePtr = Value;

      // iValue can be modified
      oValuePtr += 1;

      // Return value can be modified
      return ++oValuePtr;
   }

   const int* TestClass::PointerMethod4(const int* Value)
   {
      // Value cannot be modified
      Value++;

      // oValuePtr *cannot* be assigned
      // const int* to int*
      oValuePtr = Value;

      // oValuePtr can be modified
      oValuePtr += 1;

      // Return value can be modified
      return ++oValuePtr;
   }

   const int* TestClass::PointerMethod5(const int* Value) const
   {
      // Value can be modified
      ++Value;

      // oValuePtr *cannot* be assigned
      // const int* to int* const
      // Access through a const object
      oValuePtr = Value;

      // oValuePtr *cannot* be modified
      // Access through a const object
      oValuePtr += 1;

      // Return value *cannot* be modified
      return ++oValuePtr;
   }
};
```

I hope this helps!