# Should I return const objects?

Tags: c++

In `Effective C++` Item 03, Use const whenever possible.

```
class Bigint
{
  int _data[MAXLEN];
  //...
public:
  int& operator[](const int index) { return _data[index]; }
  const int operator[](const int index) const { return _data[index]; }
  //...
};
```

`const int operator[]` does make difference from `int& operator[]`.

But what about:

```
int foo() { }
```

and

```
const int foo() { }
```

Seems like that they're the same.

My question is, why we use `const int operator[](const int index) const` instead of `int operator[](const int index) const` ?

Comment: Good question - though in this case, wouldn't the method usually return a reference in both cases?

Comment: Good question. I suggest you change it to `int operator[](int i)` versus `const int operator[](const int i)`.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde, nope. The method called depends on whether we have a `Bigint&` or `a const Bigint&`.

Comment: @AlexanderChertov no: he's asking about the return type, not about the argument type, so the question should focus on that only

Comment: Why? I personally wonder why would someone have a `const int i` argumnent.

Comment: Well, in readaction, that i found, there `const int&`, not `const int`

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde: If there's some persistent value to return a reference to, then yes; but that's not always the case, and sometimes you do need to return a value.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Top level cv-qualifiers on return types of non class type are ignored.
Which means that even if you write:

```
int const foo();
```

The return type is `int`.  If the return type is a reference, of course,
the `const` is no longer top level, and the distinction between:

```
int& operator[]( int index );
```

and

```
int const& operator[]( int index ) const;
```

is significant.  (Note too that in function declarations, like the above,
any top level cv-qualifiers are also ignored.)

The distinction is also relevant for return values of class type: if you
return `T const`, then the caller cannot call non-const functions on the
returned value, e.g.:

```
class Test
{
public:
    void f();
    void g() const;
};

Test ff();
Test const gg();

ff().f();             //  legal
ff().g();             //  legal
gg().f();             //  **illegal**
gg().g();             //  legal
```

Comment: ff and gg are declared as functions returning Test. If so, the invokations should be ff().f() etc... If ff is an instance of Test class, the parentheses should be removed from declaration (+1 however :)

Comment: @user396672 (and BJ...) Yes.  I forgot the `()` after `ff` and `gg`.  I'll add them.  Thank you for the correction.

Comment: **−1** “Top level cv-qualifiers on return types of non class type are ignored” is incorrect. They're still part of the function type. However, cv-qualification of a prvalue of non-class type, is ignored, so that a call of a function returning `int const`, say, is equivalent to a call of that function modified to return `int`. Standardese in C++11 §3.10/4, “Class prvalues can have cv-qualified types; non-class prvalues always have cv-unqualified types”.

Answer (score 44):

You should clearly distinguish between the const usage applying to return values, parameters and the function itself.

**Return values**

- If the function returns *by value*, the const doesn't matter, as the copy of the object is being returned. It will however matter in C++11 with move-semantics involved.
- It also never does matter for basic types, as they are always copied.

Consider `const std::string SomeMethod() const`. It won't allow the `(std::string&&)` function to be used, as it expects non-const rvalue. In other words, the returned string will always be copied.

- If the function returns *by reference*, `const` protects the returned object from being modified.

**Parameters**

- If you pass a parameter *by value*, the const prevents the modification of given value by function *in function*. The original data from parameter can't be modified anyway, as you only have copy.
- Note that since the copy is always created, the const has only meaning for *function body*, thus, it's checked only in function definition, not in declaration(interface).
- If you pass a parameter *by reference*, the same rule as in return values applies

**Function itself**

- If the function has `const` at the end, it can only run other `const` functions, and can't modify or allow modification of class data. Thus, if it returns by reference, the reference returned must be const. Only const functions can be called on object or reference to object which is const itself. Also the mutable fields can be changed.
- The behavior created by the compiler changes `this` reference to `T const*`. The function can always `const_cast` `this`, but of course this shouldn't be done and is considered unsafe.
- It's of course sensible to only use this specifier on class methods; global functions with const at the end will raise compilation error.

**Conclusion**

If your method doesn't and never will modify the class variables, mark it as const and be sure to meet all the critieria needed. It will allow more cleaner code to be written, thus keeping it *const-correct*. However, putting `const` everywhere without giving it any thought certainly isn't the way to go.

Comment: Two corrections: first, for return by value, top-level `const` is ignored **for non-class types**.  It does matter for class types.  And for parameters passed by value, top-level `const` is ignored in function declarations.  It only has meaning in the definition.

Comment: I will incorporate this comment into my answer, if you don't mind. I think it will be much clearer then.

Comment: As for `const` on a function: it modifies the type of `this`, which is `T const*`, rather than `T*`.  All of the other effects stem from this.  (And it doesn't prevent all modification of the object: `mutable` data can still be changed, and the function can legally cast away const, and change anything it wishes.)

Answer (score 31):

There is ***little value*** in adding `const` qualifications to non-reference/non-pointer rvalues, and ***no point*** in adding it to built-ins.

In the case of ***user-defined types***, a `const` qualification will prevent callers from ***invoking a non-`const` member function*** on the returned object. For example, given

```
const std::string foo();
      std::string bar();
```

then

```
foo().resize(42);
```

would be forbidden, while

```
bar().resize(4711);
```

would be allowed.

For built-ins like `int`, this makes no sense at all, because such rvalues cannot be modified anyway.

(I do remember *Effective C++* discussing making the return type of `operator=()` a `const` reference, though, and this is something to consider.)

---

***Edit:***

It seems that ***Scott did indeed give that advice***. If so, then due to the reasons given above, ***I find it questionable even for C++98 and C++03***. ***For C++11, I consider it plainly wrong***, as Scott himself seems to have discovered. In the [errata for *Effective C++, 3rd ed.*](http://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/ec++3e-errata.html), he writes (or quotes others who complained):

> The text implies that all by-value returns should be const, but cases where non-const by-value returns are good design are not difficult to find, e.g., return types of std::vector where callers will use swap with an empty vector to "grab" the return value contents without copying them.

And later:

> Declaring by-value function return values const will prevent their being bound to rvalue references in C++0x. Because rvalue references are designed to help improve the efficiency of C++ code, it's important to take into account the interaction of const return values and the initialization of rvalue references when specifying function signatures.

Comment: I love the mention of errata with Scott's advice. Really helps shed some light on what could otherwise be confusing for people new to Effective C++

Comment: @sehe: I sent Scott a mail asking about this issue, and his reply was that those errata comments reflect his current thinking on the issue.

Answer (score 18):

You might miss the point of Meyers' advice.
The essential difference is in `const` modifier for the method.

This one is a non-const method (notice no `const` at the end) which means it is allowed to modify the state of the class.

```
int& operator[](const int index)
```

This one is a const method (notice `const` at the end)

```
const int operator[](const int index) const
```

What about types of the parameter and the return value, there is a minor difference between `int` and `const int`, but it is not relevant to the point of the advice. What you should pay attention to that the non-const overload returns `int&` which means you can assign to it, e.g. `num[i]=0`, and the const overload returns non-modifiable value (no matter if the return type is `int` or `const int`).

In my personal opinion, if an object is passed **by value**, `const` modifier is superfluous. This syntax is shorter and achieves the same

```
int& operator[](int index);
int operator[](int index) const;
```

Comment: Actually, the question is about returning a `const` value.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I doubt OP meant exactly that. Compare his `foo` example with `operator[]` example. He might miss the point that `const` modifier for the method makes the difference, not the return type.

Answer (score 16):

The primary reason for returning values as const is so that you can't say something like `foo() = 5;`. This isn't actually an issue with primitive types, since you can't assign to rvalues of primitive types, but it *is* an issue with user-defined types (like `(a + b) = c;`, with an overloaded `operator+`).

I've always found the justification for that rather flimsy. You can't stop someone who's intent on writing awkward code, and this particular type of coercion has no real benefit in my opinion.

With C++11, there's actually a good deal of *harm* this idiom is doing: Returning values as const prevents move optimisations and should thus be avoided whenever possible. Basically, I'd now consider this an anti-pattern.

Here's a [tangentially related article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) concerning C++11.

Comment: what about saying that it is pointles to modify return value? Like MyClass.isInitialized().If caller changes return value I would go WTF in code review.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Who am I to know what's pointless? For all we know, the assignment operator could modify a global state, or order pizza...

Comment: I added example. To my past comment. And you are designer of the class so you understand operator  =  of your return types  :D. So you know if it is meaningless for caller to change result of your methods.

Answer (score 9):

When that book was written, the advice was of little use, but did serve to prevent the user writing, for example, `foo() = 42;` and expecting it to change something persistent.

In the case of `operator[]`, this can be slightly confusing if you don't also provide a non-`const` overload that returns a non-`const` reference, although you can perhaps prevent that confusion by returning a `const` reference or a proxy object instead of a value.

These days, it's bad advice, since it prevents you from binding the result to a (non-`const`) rvalue reference.

(As pointed out in the comments, the question is moot when returning a primitive type like `int`, since the language prevents you from assigning to an `rvalue` of such a type; I'm talking about the more general case that includes returning user-defined types.)

Comment: His example returned `int`.  `foo() = 42;` is illegal, regardless of whether the return type is declared `int` or `int const`.   I don't think Scott was arguing for the use of `const` in places like return types and parameters in function declarations, where it is ignored by the compiler.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks for pointing that out; I should have made it clear that I was talking more generally.

Answer (score 2):

For primitive types (like `int`), the const-ness of the result does not matter. For classes, it might change the behaviour. For example, you might not be able to call a non-const method on the result of your function:

```
class Bigint {
    const C foo() const { ... }
     ...
}

Bigint b;
b.foo().bar();
```

The above is forbidden if `bar()` is not a const member function of `C`.
In general, choose whichever makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Look on that:

```
const int operator[](const int index) const
```

the `const` on end of statement. It describe that this method can be called on constants.

In the other hand when you write only

```
int& operator[](const int index)
```

it can be called only on non-const instances and also provide:

```
big_int[0] = 10;
```

syntax.

Answer (score 0):

One of your overloads is returning a **reference** to an item in the array, which you are then able to change.

```
int& operator[](const int index) { return _data[index]; }
```

The other overload is returning a value for you to use.

```
const int operator[](const int index) const { return _data[index]; }
```

Since you call each of these overloads in the same way, and one will never change the value when it's used.

```
int foo = myBigInt[1]; // Doesn't change values inside the object.
myBigInt[1] = 2; // Assigns a new value at index `
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example of the array-indexing operator (`operator[]`) it does make a difference.

With

```
int& operator[](const int index) { /* ... */ }
```

you can use the indexing to directly change the entry in the array, e.g. using it like this:

```
mybigint[3] = 5;
```

The second, `const int operator[](const int)` operator is used to fetch the value only.

However, as return value from functions, for simple types like e.g. `int` it doesn't matter. When it does matter is if you are returning more complex types, say a `std::vector`, and don't want the caller of the function to modify the vector.

Answer (score 0):

The `const` return type is not so important here. Since int temporaries are not modifiable, there's no observable difference in using `int` vs `const int`. You would see a difference if you used a more complex object which could be modified.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers revolving around the technicality of the two versions. For a primitive value, it doesn't make a difference.

**However**, I've always considered `const` to be there for the programmer rather than the compiler. When you write `const`, you're explicitly saying "this shouldn't change". Let's face it, `const` can usually be circumverted anyway, right?

When you return a `const`, you're telling the programmer that uses that function that the value shouldn't change. And if he is changing it, he's probably doing something wrong, because he/she shouldn't have to.

EDIT: I also think "use `const` whenever possible" is bad advice. You should use it where it makes sense.