# What does & = in C& operator=(const C&) & = default; do?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

A few questions on SO use a particular syntax for declaring default assignment operators.

[Rule-of-Three becomes Rule-of-Five with C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)

```
class C {
  C(const C&) = default;
  C(C&&) = default;
  C& operator=(const C&) & = default;
  C& operator=(C&&) & = default;
  virtual ~C() { }
};
```

I'm confused by the & = used for the assignment operators. After a quick test, default assignment operator declarations seem to compile and give the expected behavior with or without the additional ampersand.

I don't see the & = syntax on cppreference.

Comment: It is not `&=`. The `&` forms part of the signature.

Comment: See also the following answer for the usage with the assignment operator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099942/should-i-still-return-const-objects-in-c11/13099997#13099997

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` there is a [ref qualifier](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2819.html).

In that particular case it makes it so that the instance of C you want to assign to must be a non-const lvalue.

Comment: So without the `&` you could assign to rvalues of the class?