# How to define an embedded class's method that returns an enum hack outside the outer class?

Tags: c++, enums

I am trying to implement a class `vec` which looks like `class vector` everything is ok until I tried to defined an `embedded class method` that returns an `enum hack` value outside the Outer class.

Here is my interface:

```
#define MAX  1000

template <class T>
class vec{
    public:
        // ctors, dtor, oper. over...
        // Exeption handling
        class CExcep {
            public:
                virtual void what()const = 0;
        };

        class COutBound : public CExcep {
            public:
                enum RANGE_ERROR {
                    NEGATIVE, TOO_BIG
                };

                COutBound(const int, const RANGE_ERROR);

                const int getIndex()const;// { return index};
                const RANGE_ERROR getError()const;// { return or ; }

                virtual void what()const;
            private:
                const int index;
                const RANGE_ERROR or;
        };

    private:
        // some member data here
};
```

Above I embedded the `CExcep` base class inside my class `vec` and I used inheritance to use `catch` easily to catch exceptions through a `base class` reference.

- I didn't provide implementation for the sake of brevity.

So The problem:

How can I define `COutBound::getError` outside class `vec`?

To do something like that `COutBound::getIndex` I managed to do that:

```
// ok
template<class T> 
const int vec<T>::COutBound::getIndex()const{
    return index;
}
```

But:

```
// Error here?
template<class T>
const vec<T>::COutBound::RANGE_ERROR
vec<T>::COutBound::getError()const{
    return or;
}
```

Simply `getError` returns an `enum hack` value of type `RANGE_ERROR`. If I define it inside the interface it is ok. But I want to do that outside. (separate interface from implementation).

Comment: Do you really need to include *all* of your classes members just to ask about the nested exception classes?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Should I remove them?

Comment: Your example should be a [mcve]. Make it small, and make every line of code help describe the problem, instead of being irrelevant noise. That increases the chance of people taking the time to go over it and help you.

Comment: You should consider moving those nested exception classes outside, because otherwise each `vec` specialization will spawn its own exceptions incompatible with the rest. Also it would be a good idea to derive from `::std::exception` or just use appropriate standard exceptions such as `bad_alloc` `out_of_range`.

Comment: @VTT: Thank for the advice. In fact I'll do that next (deriving from std::exception).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `typename` for `RANGE_ERROR` because it is a dependent type:

```
template<class T>
typename vec<T>::COutBound::RANGE_ERROR
vec<T>::COutBound::getError()const{
    return or;
}
```

or C++ 11 trailing return:

```
template<class T> auto
vec<T>::COutBound::getError()const -> RANGE_ERROR {
   return orx;
}
```

Also `const` qualifiers on simple return types are not useful and `or` is a reserved operator name.

Comment: The trailing return type can also be simply `RANGE_ERROR`. Since the scopes are looked from the inside out. Making it even more concise. Anyway, +1.

Comment: Thanks that saved the day. Only you missed `const`:  in: `typename const vec<T>::COutBound::RANGE_ERROR...`

Comment: @WonFeiHong I've removed it intentionally. I've explained why I've omitted it at the last sentence.

Comment: @WonFeiHong You need to update function declaration so it will match the definition.

Comment: @WonFeiHong - That's sage advice VTT gave you. You can lean more about whether or not you should return by const value by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099942/should-i-still-return-const-objects-in-c11).