# C++ type_traits template to add reference if not const

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

I have a class template that accepts a type `T`. It has a method. I want this method to return type `T` if it is `const` and `T&` if it is non-`const`.

```
template<typename T>
class C
{
    static typename add_reference_if_non_const<T>::type method();
};

int main()
{
    assert( is_same<result_of<C<int>::method()>::type, int&>::value );
    assert( is_same<result_of<C<const int>::method()>::type, const int>::value );
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the return type of `C<int const>::method()` to be `int const`, but [top-level cv qualifiers are ignored on function return types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12051274/241631). In any case, since `method()` returns a copy of `T`, do you really care that you return `T const` and not `T`?

Given that, I think what you want is the following

```
using add_reference_if_non_const =
    typename std::conditional<std::is_const<T>{},
                              typename std::remove_const<T>::type,
                              typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type
                >::type;
static add_reference_if_non_const method();
```

You can replace `typename std::remove_const<T>::type` with `T` if you want to return `T const` when `T` is a class type.

---

The next problem is with [`result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) which works with type arguments; what you have in the question is a function call of `C::method`. You need to use

```
result_of<decltype(&C<int>::method)()>::type
```

But since you need to use `decltype` anyway, you can completely do away with `result_of`.

```
decltype(C<int>::method())
```

---

Finally, you don't need to `assert` at runtime when you can make the checks at compile time using [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)

```
static_assert( is_same<decltype(C<int>::method()),       int&>::value, "");
static_assert( is_same<decltype(C<int const>::method()), int>::value,  "" );
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f14f219908c91a6)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
template <typename T>
struct add_reference_if_non_const
{
    using type = std::conditional<std::is_const<T>::value, T, std::add_lvalue_reference<T>>::type;
};
```