# Getting a hash table of a class member from outside: pointer or reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, return, shared-ptr

I have a `iNode` class which has a member `_nodeState`. The functions outside of the class want to access the member `_nodeState`. So I need to design a `getState` function in `iNode` class to pass this information. `_nodeState` is dynamically allocated before the `getState` function called. I want to use `iSharedPtr<iStateHash>` for _nodeState instead of raw pointer. However, the current implementation of `iStateHash` is of "intrusive pointer" type, so I have to use raw pointer for `_nodeState`.

```
class iNode{

public: return_type getState(input_type){}
        void initializeState(){_nodeState = new iStateHash;}

private:
   typedef iHashMap<int ikey, iSharedPtr<iValue>> iStateHash;
   iStateHash* _nodeState;
};
```

Since the _nodeState points to a large amount of data, passing by pointer or passing by reference seems to be better than passing by value.

If it's passing by reference, then the `return_type` of the `getState` function should be reference type (const reference return seems not be recommended after c++11). So I have the design 1:

```
iStateHash* & iNode::getState(){return _nodeState;}
```

So in a block outside of the class:

```
iNode newNode;
newNode.initializeState();
iStateHash &myNodeState = newNode.getState();
```

If it's passing by pointer, then could return a pointer or set a pointer as the function argument:

```
iStateHash * iNode::getState(){return _nodeState;}
```

or

```
void iNode::getState(iStateHash* outputState){outputState = _nodeState;}
```

then

```
iNode newNode;
newNode.initializeState();
iStateHash *myNodeState = NULL;
getState(myNodeState);
```

Since shared pointer cannot be used in this case, the raw pointer usage is not recommended? Or if the raw pointer is still better than returning a reference?
Or is there a better way to get the `_nodeState`information outside of the class?

Moreover, how about using `iStateHash _nodeState;` as a member variable instead of using a pointer type (`iStateHash* _nodeState;`)? This would be better?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: `const reference return seems not be recommended after c++11` what makes you think so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051012/should-i-return-const-objects
it seems the const return will disable the move-semantics

Comment: the question you linked to is about returning by `const value` instead of `const reference`

Comment: `iStateHash* &` returning a reference to a pointer doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: `getState(iStateHash* outputState){outputState = _nodeState;}` this function is a no-op. It only changes a local variable.

Comment: getState passes the _nodeState information to the outside (a local variable). That's what I want

Comment: The key piece of information is what you want to happen if somebody calls `getState()` followed by `initializeState()`. If you return a reference to `_nodeState`, then the state returned by `getState()` will refer to the new `_nodeState`. If you return the raw pointer, then the state returned by `getState()` will refer to the old `_nodeState`.

Comment: So, how about using `iStateHash _nodeState;` as a member variable instead of using a pointer type? This would be better?