# What effect does const at the beginning of a non-member function declaration have?

Tags: c++, constants, function-declaration, non-member-functions

Digging through MSDN, I ran into just another curious line:

```
// This function returns the constant string "fourth".
const string fourth() { return string("fourth"); }
```

The full example is buried here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293668.aspx Refined to bare minimum, it looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

const int f() { return 0; }

int main() {
    std::cout << f() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

A few other tests with different return types demonstrated that both Visual Studio and g++ compile lines like this without a warning, yet const qualifier seems to have no effect on what I can do with the result. Can anyone provide an example of where it matters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I return const objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051012/should-i-return-const-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of the return type. The functions return `const string` and `const int`.

In the case of `const int`, this indeed makes no difference compared to `int`, because the only thing you can do with an `int` return value is to copy the value somewhere (in fact, the standard explicitly says that `const` has no effect here).

In the case of `const string`, it does make a difference, because a return value of class type can have member functions called on it:

```
fourth().erase(1);
```

will fail to compile in the case that `fourth()` returns a `const string`, because `erase()` is not a `const` method (it tries to modify the `string` it is called on).

Personally, I never make value-returning functions return a `const` value, as it unnecessarily constrains the caller (although some people feel that it is useful to prevent writing things like `string s = fourth().erase(1);`).

Answer (score 3):

you can not modify the returned object

example:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const string foo(){return "123";}
string bar(){return "123";}

int main(){
    //foo().append("123"); //fail
    bar().append("123"); //fine
}
```

---

This is almost the same as const variable

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const string foo = "123";
string bar = "123";

int main(){
    //foo.append("123"); //fail
    bar.append("123"); //fine
}
```