# QList::at() returns a reference to a constant?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a method defined like this in the documentation.

```
const T & QList::at(int i) const
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598804/1214214)  I described it at as:

> QList::at returns a reference to a const object T, and doesn't modify the QList.

But if this interpretation is correct, it's returning a reference to an object that i shouldn't be able to change. However this is compiled without error passes (*currentTime()* modifies the attribute *returnedStation.time*):

```
T referenceToReturnedObject = myQlist.at(1);
    referenceToReturnedObject.time.currentTime();
```

What does the first `const` refere to, and what limitations does it post on the returned `T &`?

Comment: what is `returnedStation` and how does it relate to the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What does the first const refere to, and what limitations does it post on the returned T &?

In:

```
T referenceToReturnedObject = myQlist.at(1);
    referenceToReturnedObject.time.currentTime();
```

you are creating a *copy* of the value returned by reference from `at` and you are modifying that copy. Not the object inside the list.

> So my interpretation was correct? How I'm I to change the exact object in the Qlist?

In order to modify the actual object of the list you are going to need to use:

```
T& operator[](int)
```

instead:

```
list[x] = y;
```

Comment: Hm, I failed to find the `non const` version of `QList::at()` function in the documentation.

Comment: So my interpretation was correct? How I'm I to change the exact object in the Qlist?

Comment: @Alan, with `operator[]`.

Comment: The only big problem with using `[]` instead of `at()` is that no out-of-bounds check is done when `[]` is used. So the dev has to manually make sure that the index used is within the allowed range for the given list.

Answer (score 6):

When you do this:

```
T referenceToReturnedObject = myQlist.at(1);
```

`referenceToReturnedObject1` is a **copy** made from the reference returned from the value. You can do whatever you want to this copy.

If you wanted a reference, you would have to say

```
const T& referenceToReturnedObject = myQlist.at(1);
```

If you wanted a non-const reference,

```
T& referenceToReturnedObject = myQlist[1];
```

or just

```
myQlist[1].someNonConstMethod();
```