# The meaning of "const" in a function declaration

Tags: c++, constants

I have a function with 3 const's in it:

```
const std::string at(const unsigned int index) const;
```

To my understanding, the parameter (**const** unsigned int index ) means that index will not be changed. What about the other two const's? Why are they there?

Answer (score 1):

The first const says that the return type is const, the second const says the parameter is const, and the third const says that the function is a const function...

This question is actually a duplicate... follow this link

[C++ Const Usage Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598703/c-const-usage-explanation)

Comment: The const on the end of a member function does *not* mean the function is read only (is there even such a thing as a non-read-only function?).  It means that the instance object for which the function is called is const.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` keywoard in C++ indicates that a particular object or variable is not modifiable. It can be used in various contexts:

### Const variables

Declaring a variable as `const` inside of a function indicates that the variable will not be modified inside the function.

### Const member functions

Declaring a member function as `const`, which is done by appending `const` to the end of the function prototype, indicates that the function is a "read-only" function that does not modify the object for which it is called.

---

The rule for `const` viability is that `const`-ness can be applied to a non-`const` variable or member function, but once applied it cannot be removed.

Answer (score 0):

**const** std::string at(**const** unsigned int index) **const**;
in this example, the first const from left side is a constant for return type, which means whatever value it will return that can be saved in a const variable only (even type casting is possible which will change the property of data).
second const as you said it is correct.
third const says that the function is constant function. that means inside that function you are not modifying any variables which will change the state of objects.
if you are modifying any class or global variable inside const function then compiler will throw error.