# vector::push_back conversion from const Type* to type*

Tags: c++, vector, constants, const-cast

The signature of `vector::push_back` is:

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
```

which means it is responsible for not corrupting `val`.

My function is:

```
Result User::addFriend(const User* newFriend)
{
    // check that newFriend is valid and is not already a friend
    if (newFriend == NULL || isFriend(newFriend)) return FAILURE;
    friends_.push_back(newFriend);
    friendsNum_++;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

when I compile the .c file I get compilation error:

```
invalid conversion from 'const User*' to 
std::vector User*::value_type
```

1. Why do we get this error if **push_back** promises not to change **val**?
2. What is the correct and clean way to overcome the error? maybe by **const_cast**?

thank you!

User.h:

```
class User {
...
public:
    vector<User*> friends_;
...
}
```

Comment: Can you show more code? In particular, what is the type of `friends_`?

Comment: Are you storing a vector of pointers …?

Comment: This much code is not enough...

Comment: what else should I add?

Comment: You're trying to push a `const User*` into a vector of `User*`, which isn't possible; if this were allowed, you would be removing the const-ness of `newFriend`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a logical issue with your code. Namely, you are storing pointers to modifiable objects:

```
vector<User*> friends_;
```

And yet your addFriend() method takes a pointer to a const object:

```
Result User::addFriend(const User* newFriend) 
//                     ^^^^^
{
    // stuff..
    friends_.push_back(newFriend);
}
```

Those don't line up. As is, `push_back` would have to convert your `const User*` to a `User*`, hence the compile error. One or the other of those types should be changed. Either `friends_` needs to be a `vector<const User*>` (if you really have no intention of modifying these objects) or `addFriend` needs to take a `User*` (if you do). Don't use `const_cast`!

Comment: if I declare the vector as you suggested: vector<const User*>, it means that the pointers in the vector are const or the object that are pointed to?

Comment: @Day_Dreamer `const User*` is a pointer to a `const User`, the object pointed to is `const`. The other way, `User* const`, would be a `const` pointer to a mutable `User`... which you can't have a `vector` of.

Answer (score 6):

You're storing a vector of pointers:

```
std::vector<User*> friends_;
```

There's a problem with this approach, however.  Notice that these pointers are not `const User*`: anyone with access `friends_` should be free to modify the `User`.

The type parameter in `vector` here is `User*`, not `User`, which means `value_type ≡ User`.  Therefore, this line

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
```

should be interpreted like this:

```
void push_back (const User*& val);
```

Note that [the syntax is a bit misleading here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5598703/440302); a clearer way to look at it is this:

```
void push_back (User *const &val);
```

*The `const` modifies what is on the left side:* it prevents the pointer from being changed, but it does nothing to prevent the underlying `User` itself from being altered.

Because of the `const` affects only the pointer but not the `User`, passing in a `const User*` would violate the contract:

```
Result User::addFriend(const User* newFriend){
    …
    friends_.push_back(newFriend);
    …
}
```

You can't do this.  Since `addFriend` promises to not prevent the `User` from being altered, storing it into a vector of *non-const* `User*` would allow anyone with access to the vector to modify the `User` however they please.

Possible solutions:

- Let `addFriend` take `User*` instead of `const User*`.  Even better: use a reference unless you have really good reason not to.
- Change `friends_` to use `const User*` instead of `User*`.  Even better: store the `User`s directly instead of as pointers.
- Make a copy of the `User`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, thanks to Collin Dauphinee.
It is not possible to add a User* to a vector of non const User*.

the declaration should be updated in the .h file:

```
class User{
...
public:
    vector<const User*> friends_;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's advised to use shared ptr or uniquer ptr for your friends_ member . So a best practice is to declare friends_ (if the friends will be shared) to be :

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<User> sharedUsers;
std::vector< sharedUsers> friends_
```

or if your friends will not be shared :

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<User> sharedUsers;
std::vector<sharedUsers> friends_
```

by this way all the memory management will be delegated to your smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion arises because the signature:

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
```

does NOT translate to this (when instantiating the vector with `User*`).

```
void push_back (const User * & val); //wrong. but visually looks same!
```

Rather, it translates to

```
void push_back (User * const & val);  //right. but visually looks different
```

Now it becomes slightly clearer why object of type `const User*` cannot be passed to this function, because :

- `const User *` means the object being pointed to by the pointer is const. The pointer itself is non-const.
- whereas `User *const` means the object being pointed to by the pointer is non-const. It is the pointer itself which is const.

Note that `const User*` and `User const*` mean exactly the *same* thing.

It is one of the reason why I prefer to write `const` after the type-name in templates. If programmers make this habit, then `push_back` function would look like this:

```
void push_back(value_type const & val);
```

which when instantiating with `User*`, can be easily translated by us, programmers, into this:

```
void push_back(User * const & val); //right. visually similar as well.
```

which is exactly what it should be.

Hope that helps.