# A few questions about const methods in my class

Tags: c++, constants

I'm new to using C++ to write enterprise software at my company and the usage of const in member functions has been quite confusing to me. For example, I have the following method:

`string DAC::impulse_find(int i)`

There will be no modification of the variable i. My code compiles perfectly when I use these three variants of adding const to the above method:

`const string DAC::impulse_find(const int i) const`

`const string const DAC::impulse_find(const int i) const`

`string const DAC::impulse_find(const int i) const`

So what exactly is the difference between these three? I looked at some past answers and say "It applies to whatever is to the left" but that is still confusing. Does it apply to anything, such as the name of the class as well?

Comment: Returning a constant variable, that is not a reference, is worthless.  There is no need for `const` as the function returns a copy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598703/c-const-usage-explanation

Comment: You may use `const string& DAC::impulse_find(int i) const`, instead

Comment: It seems unlikely that you're writing "enterprise software in C++" when you don't know the lexical rules for `const`... Also, programming by guessing does not work. Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm a college student working as a summer intern, so I'm learning C++ as I work on my project. My bad for trying to learn the rules of C++ so I can be a better programmer.

Comment: @TheSalamander *"My bad for trying to learn"* that's a rather nonsensical take on what you're reading here.

Comment: @TheSalamander We just don't understand why you're trying to add a const modifier to the return value. The return value is a temporary copy, which means you can't modify it anyway

Comment: @TheSalamander: Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not using any book, I'm just learning as I go by looking at past Stack Overflow threads. So far it has been helpful. I've learned a lot but const has been rather confusing for me.

Comment: @TheSalamander: You really need to at least skim over a C++ book, even if it is online. At *least* learn the syntax rules and the keywords.

Comment: @TheSalamander I'm speculating here, but I bet someone at the place you're interning at would have a book that they would lend you.  This site does many things well, but is not a good replacement for an introductory book.

Comment: @TheSalamander: You should really get [a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). As I've said, you cannot program by guesswork. You certainly can't learn by randomly "skimming" random threads on the internet!!! _Study_, like we did in the olden days. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between

```
const std::string  
std::string const
```

The order of `const` is irrelevant since you are not dealing with pointers.

Having many `const` as a qualifier doesn't make sense.  Did you turn up the warning level on your compiler to maximum?

**Edit 1: Pointers and Const**
Since you are returning a copy of a variable the effectiveness of `const` is worthless.  The original item from the function can't be modified because you are returning a copy.

Maybe you are confused with the *pointer* syntax, where the placement of `const` matters:

```
string const * const -- constant pointer to a constant (read-only string).  Pointer cannot be modified.
string const *       -- Mutable pointer to a constant (read-only) string.  Pointer value can change.
string       * const -- Constant pointer to a read/write string.  Pointer value cannot be changed.
string       *       -- Mutable pointer to a read/write string.  Pointer value can be changed.
```

The `const` for read-only data may be placed before or after the type:

```
const string *  
string const *
```

Both of the above are equivalent.

Comment: @TheSalamander:  If the answer helped, click on the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

All three version

```
const string …
const string const …
string const …
```

are **identical**.

The placement of `const` doesn't matter here. The duplicate `const` in the second version is redundant and your compiler should give a warning about it.

Moreover, the `const`s don't make sense here because the string is returned **as a copy**. Returning a `const` value brings you nothing (see [KABoissonneault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2356414/kaboissonneault)'s comment), only *references or pointers* to `const` make sense as a return type.

Comment: The Visual Studio 2010 compiler isn't giving me any warnings when I use the second version.

Comment: It's an _error_ with GCC trunk. MSVS may be non-standardly lenient here.

Comment: @TheSalamander Then I would strongly recommend turning all your warnings on to help write better code.

Comment: **`[C++14: 7.1.6.1/1]:` *[..]* Each *cv-qualifier* shall appear at most once in a *cv-qualifier-seq*. *[..]***