# Does const keyword go before or after Type?

Tags: c++

I wrote something like this:

```
#define Parent C*
class C{
public:
    Parent parent;
    C():parent(NULL){}
};
void fun(Parent &p){
    //condition..return;
    fun(p->parent);
}
```

Something wired happened when I was trying to make the reference parameter constant to avoid any unintended changes to the referenced object.

**first:**

I added `const` befor `Parent`, like this: `void fun(const Parent &p)`. But it does not compile on this line `fun(p->parent);`.
error message is:

> Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void fun(const C * &) '

**then:**

I changed the position of `const` like this: `void fun(Parent const &p)` and all of a sudden, the problem was gone.
Why??? What's the difference?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598703/c-const-usage-explanation ?

Comment: Just make the job of the preprocessor yourself and replace Parent with C*. The look at the resulting code will make it clear!

Comment: It would have worked if you had used a `typedef` instead of a `#define`. Now `C` and `*` are separate items and your `const` to the left only affects  `C`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How does `const` work? It is always applied to what comes right before it. However, when there is nothing before, it applies to what comes right after it. In other words, `const Type&` is the same as `Type const&`.

Now, do not ever use preprocessor macros to define type aliases. There are two ways of doing that in C++: `using` and `typedef`. The fact you used a macro is the reason why you observe this peculiar behaviour. The code that fails to compile is expanded to the following:

```
void fun(const C*& p); // The pointee is const, but the pointer itself is not
```

I suppose you are then doing things on the object pointed by `p`... But this object is `const`! In the second example, the expansion results in:

```
void fun(C* const& p); // The pointee is not const, but the pointer itself is
```

Then, you are doing stuff on the pointee but this time it's the pointer, not the pointee, that is `const`, so everything is fine. If you had used an alias or a typedef, it would have gone perfectly fine in both cases: see [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47cb35860fe221bd).

As a rule of thumb, you should always put `const` on the right of the thing you want it to be applied to. This would allow you to read types the way they are meant to be read: from right to left.

Answer (score 5):

`const` works from right to left, making the previous part const,

```
int * const p; // makes constant pointer to int
```

except for `const type` and `type const` at the beginning, which are the same:

```
int const * p; // pointer to const int
const int * p; // ditto
```

so if parent is e.g. `struct Parent{}`, then `Parent const & p` and `const Parent & p` should be the same; if however `Parent` is a macro, e.g. `C*`, they are different.