# C++ static variable multiple instances

Tags: c++, templates, static, linker, g++

I have encountered the following strange situation: I have managed to have a global static variable with two instances ... Is this normal or is this a bug in the compiler or is this a hidden realm of C++? The following reproduction is an extract from a larger project (where the behaviour is the same), obviously the names were changed to protect the culprit (and yes, I know there are memory leaks in this code).

Here comes the code:

```
// other.h
#ifndef _OTHER_H_
#define _OTHER_H_

struct other
{
    long longer;
    int inter;
    char charer;
};

void dosomething();

#endif
```

And

```
// other.cpp
#include "other.h"
#include "util.h"

void dosomething()
{
  other* something = alloc_mem(other, 4);
}
```

And

```
// util.h
#ifndef _UTIL_H_
#define _UTIL_H_

#include <memory.h>
#include <string>

#include "test_class.h"

template <class T> T* allocate(size_t count, const char* f, long l, const char* sth)
{
    T* tmp = new T[count];
    memset(tmp, 0, count * sizeof(T));
    test_class<T*>::instance().throwIn(tmp, f, l, sth, count);

    return tmp;
}

#define alloc_mem(type,count) allocate<type>(count, __FILE__, __LINE__, (char*)0)

#endif
```

And

```
// main.cpp
#include "other.h"  
#include "util.h"

int main()
{
  int* i = alloc_mem(int, 1);
  int* i1 = alloc_mem(int, 20);
  char* c = alloc_mem(char, 1);

  dosomething();
  int* i3 = alloc_mem(int, 1);
}
```

And the main part:

```
// test_class.h
#ifndef test_class_H
#define test_class_H
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>

static long int all_alloc = 0; // THIS will get linked in two times!

template <typename T>
class test_class
{
private:
    test_class() {}
    static test_class<T>* pinstance;

public:
    ~test_class() {}
    static test_class& instance() {
        if(pinstance == NULL) {
            pinstance = new test_class();
        }
        return *pinstance;
    }

    void throwIn(T item, const char* file, long line, const char* _compiler, long count) {
        int status;
        char* s = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(T).name(), 0, 0, &status) ;
        std::cout << "request:" << sizeof(T) * count << " bytes, type:" << s << " @ "<< 
                 file << ":" << line << " global_addr:" << &all_alloc << std::endl;
        all_alloc += sizeof(T) * count ;
        free(s);
        std::cout<<"All memory:" << all_alloc << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T> test_class<T>*  test_class<T>::pinstance = NULL;

#endif
```

So, you have to compile this as:

```
g++ main.cpp other.cpp -o test
```

and the run it, and:

```
$ ./test
request:8 bytes, type:int* @ main.cpp:6 global_addr:0x6022d8
All memory:8
request:160 bytes, type:int* @ main.cpp:7 global_addr:0x6022d8
All memory:168
request:8 bytes, type:char* @ main.cpp:8 global_addr:0x6022d8
All memory:176
request:32 bytes, type:other* @ other.cpp:6 global_addr:0x6022f8
All memory:32
request:8 bytes, type:int* @ main.cpp:11 global_addr:0x6022d8
All memory:184
```

so, as I could see with a pretty big surprise, I have two global addresses for `all_alloc`... Indeed, `nm -C test` shows:

```
00000000006022d8 b all_alloc
00000000006022f8 b all_alloc
```

So, obviously the questions:

Why? How is this possible? Is there something allowing this kind of behaviour or is this a bug somewhere in the compiler or linker?

Comment: This "test_class.h" directly above the static you question is a fairly strong indicator this is in a header, and your command line suggests two source files are including it, each getting their own `all_alloc`. Each file that includes `test_class.h` is going to get their own `all_alloc`.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_OTHER_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, I don't think you want to declare your `all_alloc` static. In this case, it means that the linkage is internal. In your case, you get two copies since two files include the header.

If you remove `static`, then you will have two copies that *clash*, and result in a linker error. Which is not good.

I believe what you want to do is to change `static` to `extern`, then in *one* cpp file, define the variable and its value.

header:

```
extern long int all_alloc;
```

cpp:

```
long int all_alloc = 0;
```

This will provide one copy of `all_alloc` that is shared among your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you have global variable it already has static duration, so `static` keyword means something different for it. As you have class definition in the file you define your global static variable I assume that is a header. Why it is bad idea to use static global variable in header and what you will get you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c)
So answer is: it is expected behavior and not a bug.