# Variable lifetime in static list

Tags: c++, list, object-lifetime, lifetime, lifetime-scoping

this code adds a new object to a static list, within a function. **the list is passed by reference to the function.**

what in the lifetime of the new object in the list?

code sample:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct MyStruct
{
    int x;
    string str;
};

void addStructToList(list<MyStruct> &myStructlist, int _x, string _str)
{
    MyStruct newStruct;
    newStruct.x = _x;
    newStruct.str = _str;
    myStructlist.push_back(newStruct);
}

void main()
{
    list<MyStruct> myStructlist;
    addStructToList(myStructlist, 111, "aaa");
    addStructToList(myStructlist, 222, "bbb");
    addStructToList(myStructlist, 333, "ccc");

    for (auto it = myStructlist.begin(); it != myStructlist.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it->x << " " << it->str << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

output:

```
111 aaa
222 bbb
333 ccc
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Question:**

Is this code safe in terms of memory usage?

What is "newStruct" lifetime? addStructToList() or Main() ?

Comment: I don't see any static list in your code.

Comment: Suggested reading: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this code safe in terms of memory usage?

Yes it is safe. `list` und `string` take care of memory management automatically. You may get an out of memory error if you would add really many items to your list (like 100000000).

> What is "newStruct" lifetime? addStructToList() or Main() ?

`newStruct` only exists in the function `addStructToList`. But a copy is created and put into `myStructlist`. The copy lives on in `Main`.

Small additional remark: Always pass `string` by const reference and not by value:

```
void addStructToList(list<MyStruct> &myStructlist, int _x, const string& _str) { ... }
```

Another remark: You use the word "static" misleadingly. See [The static keyword and its various uses in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c) for explanation what static means in C++.