# Static variables in C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, static

I have a question:
let's say we have this function: (in C++)

```
int& f() {
    static int x = 0;
    return x;
} // OK
```

and

```
int& h() {
    int x=0;
    return x;
} // ERROR
```

Why does `h` give an error? Is it because of the keyword `static`? I found `static` keyword lets my `x` variable live after my function is terminated. So I still can access at that memory location from the outside (another function or main? right?). Instead int `x = 0` is lost after `h` terminates. Right? I'm not sure I really got it!

And what about Java? I read I cannot declare `static` variables in methods but only in classes.

Thank you.

Comment: That isn't an error unless you use `-Werror`. But http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Comment: C++: yes. Java: one question at a time!

Comment: One at a time. Ask for C++ or Java. And yes, `static` keyword has a different meaning in Java.

Comment: Regarding static in C++ : [The static keyword and its various uses in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c)

Comment: _"Right?"_  Right.  You've answered your own question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In C++, `static` is one of the most overloaded keywords of the language. The meaning you're using here is this:

A variable which is defined inside a function with the `static` specifier has static storage duration - it occupies the same space for the entire runtime of the program, and keeps its value between different calls to the function. So you can safely return a reference to it, as the variable is always there to back the reference.

A normal (non-`static`) function-local variable is destroyed when the function call returns, and so the reference becomes dangling - it doesn't refer to anything valid. Using it results in Undefined Behaviour.

Java simply doesn't have function-scope `static` variables (it doesn't have that meaning of the keyword `static`). That's why you can't declare it there.

Both C++ and Java have the "class-scope" meaning of the `static` keyword. When a member of a class is declared with the `static` keyword, it means the member is not bound to any instance of the class, but is just a global variable whose identifier lives in the class's scope.

Comment: I would give a precision on C++ (or C) static variables. As the have only one space all along the program, they are non re-entrant : in multithreaded programs, they share a common value between all threads. And if you want to call the function in a recursive manner, they are neither pushed to stack nor popped.

Comment: @SergeBallesta What exactly does a "re-entrant variable" mean? I always understood *code* to be re-entrant or thread-safe, not *data.* But you're of course right that a `static` local variable is just a global variable with funny name access rules.

Comment: I agree with you an re-entrant variable does not mean anything. But when you have a static variable in a function, the function will have re-entrance problems ...

Answer (score 3):

Static keyword is used for almost same purpose in both C++ and Java. There are some differences though.

**1)  Static Data Members:** Like C++, static data members in Java are class members and shared among all objects.

**2) Static Member Methods:** Like C++, methods declared as static are class members and have following restrictions:

- (i) They can only call other static methods.
- (ii) They must only access static data.
- (iii) They cannot access `this` or `super`

Like C++, static data members and static methods can be accessed without creating an object. They can be accessed using class name.

**3) Static Block:** Unlike C++, Java supports a special block, called static block (also called static clause) which can be used for static initialization of a class. This code inside static block is executed only once (first time you make an object of that class or the first time you access a static member of that class (even if you never make an object of that class)).

**4) Static Local Variables:** Unlike C++, Java doesn’t support static local variables. If used , Java program fails in compilation.

**5) Static class:** Classes can also be made static in Java.In java, we can’t make Top level class static. Only nested classes can be static.

- Nested static class doesn’t need reference of Outer class, but Non-static nested class or Inner class requires Outer class reference.
- Inner class(or non-static nested class) can access both static and
  non-static members of Outer class. A static class cannot access
  non-static members of the Outer class. It can access only static
  members of Outer class.

Ref : [www.geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-in-java/)

Comment: Verbatim repetition of this webpage: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-in-java/ Are you the author of this article or have you plagiarized? If the former, say so in your post so we will know.

Comment: agreed - possible plagiarism

Answer (score 0):

Static variables in C++ in functions are persistant varibles in the scope of a function. In Java, you can't have static variables in methods. Static variables are variables of the class, not its instances.

Comment: @jaunchopanza, it's sort-of right for the case of variables declared `static` at function scope. It's incomplete, however, since it ignores other uses of the heavily overloaded `static` keyword to qualify variables in other scopes.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry, I specified that that's only when declared in a function. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

For the Java side you are correct. Static variables in Java must be declared at the class level not inside a method.

If you need to scope the static variables then you probably have some seriously broken architecture but you can do it to a certain extent by using inner classes to store the static variables in.