# When to use static variable C++

Tags: c++, static, global-variables, extern

I got a little confused of the usage of `static` / `global` / `global static` / `extern` variables.

I would like a counter variable to get increased in any creation of a class instance.

Would highly appreciate if someone can post a clarification of the appropriate usage for each.

Comment: The first two paragraphs seem unrelated ? You would just need a `static` counter variable in your class which gets incremented in your constructor(s) and decremented in your destructor.

Comment: @PaulR, why not global?

Comment: Duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c

Comment: A static class variable is somewhat like a global, in that there is one instance and it has the same lifetime as the program.

Comment: @PaulR, LOL! This is what get me confused....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to OO concept, you should **NEVER** use `global static` variables.
You can instead define a `static` variable in your `class` for the instance count of your `class`.
Make it `private`, so that no one else except your constructor can increase the count.
Provide a `public` function to get the counter. See example below:

yourclass.h:

```
class YourClass {
private:
    static int instanceCount_;
public:
    YourClass() {++YourClass::instanceCount_;}  // constructor
    ~YourClass() {--YourClass::instanceCount_;} // destructor
    static int instanceCount() {return instanceCount_;}
};
```

yourclass.cpp:

```
int YourClass::instanceCount_ = 0;
```

As far as the concept of `static` / `global` / `global static` / `extern`

1. `static`:

1a)  `global static`:
A static variable created as given: `static int numberOfPersons;`

This kind of variable can only be seen in a file (will not have name collision with other variable having same name in other files)

1b) `class static`: (already has an example in the instance count above)
A class may have `static` members, which are visible to that class (accessed only by `Class::VarName` syntax) only (instead of 'file only' as said above).  It will not have name collision with variables of same name in other class.  It only has one copy per class (not per instance).

1c) Both `global static` and `class static` are `global`(since they can be globally accessed, either with class qualifier `Class::` or not.

So, 1a., 1b. and 1c. partially explain `static`, `global`, and `global static`

2. Another form of global variable, is just define a variable without `static`
   syntax: `int numberOfPersons;`

Without `static`, this variable can be seen by other file, using `extern` keyword.  And it will have name collision with the variables having same name in other files.  So, globally, you can only define it **ONCE** across all your source files.

3. `extern`:  *Declare a variable/function which is defined in somewhere else.* It is normally seen in a header file. We can have some variables defined in other file, and declare this variable as `extern`, like below, in another source file which uses it.

```
extern int numberOfPersons;

    int addPersonCount()
    {
         numberOfPersons++;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @RoninHsh, Thanks. What does the `inline` mean?

Comment: Don't forget the copy constructor and move constructor. Maybe not relevant here, but the use of an atomic may be better for thread safety.

Comment: But C++ is not an OO language; it is multi-paradigm. Thus not only is this answer woefully incomplete but it may also be said to miss the point of the question entirely.

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention the destructor, to decrement the count.

Comment: Updated.  Anything defined in header file is already inline.  Thus the `inline` is redundant, and is removed.  `inline` means optimized it as if it is written in the context of the caller of the function, without really calls it. (`inline` to the place it is called).