# How does static variable and how is it used as counter?

Tags: c++

I was reading c++ code. I saw a static variable has been used as a counter and it has been initialized in the constructor as below :

```
 class Order{
 int Number;

public:
    Order(){
     int static i=0;
     Number=++i;
     }

   int getNumber(){
      return Number;
   }
    .
    .
```

So if we instantiate the "Order" class as below :

```
    Order *o1 = new Order();
    o1.getNumber();
    Order *o2 = new Order();
    o2.getNumber();
    Order *o3 = new Order();
    o3.getNumber();
    //Result :  1 ,2 ,3
```

I am wondering how the static variable work in this case. Because each time we instantiate the **Order** class, actually we are setting **int static i=0;** so I expect a result like this :

```
1,1,1
```

but it seems the process behind static variables is different! So, what is going on behind this static variable and how it works?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `static` class variable has a single instance across all instances of that class. With standard variables each instance of a class creates an instance of that variable, but with a `static` variable they all share the same instance. If you were to print the memory address for `static int i` you'd see that regardless of which `Order` you were using, that the memory address would be the same.

Someone already mentioned this in a comment, but in case others miss it, read up on `static` in C++: [The static keyword and its various uses in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c)

Your question was likely downvoted because you could've read about the static keyword and its use very easily by searching for it instead of asking a question.