# Why does static vector appear to have different contents in different classes?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
namespace GameStatus{

    static std::vector<SavePoint>savePoints;
}
```

A `SavePoint` is :

```
class SavePoint{

public:
    int distance;
    int score;

    SavePoint(int d,int s){
        distance = d;
        score = s;
    };
};
```

The problem is, that even though `GameStatus::savePoints` is `static`, the vector appears to either contain elements or not, depending on who the calling class is.

For example, if I have a class which adds a save point:

```
class Game{

    void addSavePoint(){
        SavePoint savepoint(12,10);
        GameStatus::savePoints.push_back(savepoint);
    }

    void testView(){
       if(!GameStatus::savePoints.empty()){
          Log("There is a save point"); // Can see that savePoints is not empty in the debugger. Everything looks ok here.
       }
    }

}
```

But if I have some other class:

```
class Foo{
    void something(){
         if(GameStatus::savePoints.empty()){  // In this class it appears that the vector is empty.
              //..do something.
         }
    }
}
```

I have a game loop which alternately executes code in Game and Foo, and it appears that in `Game`  `GameStatus::savePoints` has a savePoint(is not empty), while in Foo it doesn't (appears empty). It makes no sense to me, because `savePoints` is static. So both classes should be accessing the same object.

Why does `GameStatus::savePoints` appear to have different values if different classes ?

Comment: Does the method something() runs before addSavepoints()?

Comment: @user64985 - can you explain ? What is the problem with my code then ?

Comment: Are the classes `Game` and `Foo` in separate source files?

Comment: @Jagannath   something() runs long after addSavePoint() when the game is over, to check if there is a save point.

Comment: @TheDark Yes, GameStatus, Game and Foo are all in separate source files. Can you explain how to fix my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` keyword has two meaning in C++.

- [inside a class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) ( this is an object oriented meaning like in Java or C# )
- [storage specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) ( outside class, this one is also available in C )

Solution: You should put the declaration to the header with `extern` storage specifier instead of `static`, because you want it to be global. After that you should put the definition to one .cpp file, which is one compilation unit/object. This way you will have one instance of the vector, which is accessible from all other compilation units which includes the header.

header file:

```
namespace GameStatus{
    extern std::vector<SavePoint> savePoints;
}
```

cpp file:

```
    std::vector<SavePoint> GameStatus::savePoints;
```

Comment: Can you explain how to do this ? I don't understand "The Dark" answer.

Answer (score 4):

A `static` variable outside of a class is only defined in the current compilation unit (compilation unit is the current source that is being compiled - i.e the current source file and all its included files). When you put a static variable in a header, each source file that includes that header gets its own copy.

There are two ways to fix this:

1 - Don't make it static - change the `static` keyword to 'extern', you will reference a global variable. You will then need to define the global variable in one source file. For example:

Header:

```
 extern std::vector<SavePoint>savePoints;
```

Game.cpp:

```
 std::vector<SavePoint> GameStatus::savePoints;
```

2 - Put it inside a class - static variables inside a class are only created once. Note that if you put it inside a class, you will need to declare it in the header and also define in a single compilation unit, otherwise you will get linker errors. For example:

Header:

```
 class Game {
 public:
     std::vector<SavePoint>savePoints;
 }
```

Game.cpp:

```
 std::vector<SavePoint> Game::savePoints;
```

Comment: But if I remove the static keyword, then compilation fails with a Apple Mach-O Linker error. What do you mean by define in a single compilation unit ? The error is "duplicate symbol" for savePoints and appears many times in many files even though I don't use it anywhere

Comment: But now it says non-static data member defined out of line. I'm confused. Which header should the extern variable be ?

Comment: Also what change should I make to GameStatus ?

Comment: If that is all that is in GameStatus, I would change it to a class. That would use my second example. You would then just need a `std::vector<SavePoint> GameStatus::savePoints;` in some .cpp file.

Comment: I'm confused by your answer. There is nothing else in GameStatus. I made it a class, and not I get Linker errors again.

Comment: What is the error? Did you add the vector definition to one .cpp file?

Comment: Sorry - I missed a namespace - that might have caused your problem

Answer (score 0):

Believe you put your `static vector` in a header file and including in `Game` and `Foo` classes.

So, you need to clearly understand wt is mean by `static` first.

> `static` variables exist for the "lifetime" of the translation unit that it's defined in.

For more refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c).

As you done in hear, when you include header, two separate instance will be initiated on `vector`. So those two instance act distinctly. That's why `GameStatus::savePoints` appear to have different values if different classes.

You can do, two things.

1. define your vector as a a global variable.
2. You a `singleton` class to wrap your vector.

For singleton refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern).

Comment: So how do I share between different source files ?

Comment: @Jhon, methos 1 is quite `c` base. You can defin vector as globle and do `include` or `extern` in your files. I prefer to use method 2.