# Error when using static array in a structure C

Tags: c

I want to use a static array inside the following structure:

```
struct N{
    int id;
    static long history[100];
};
struct N Node[R][C];  // R is # of rows, C is # of coloumns
```

But I got this error:

```
P.c:38:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘static’
                 static long history[100];
```

I don't know why? Does it mean I cannot use static inside structures?

Comment: What do you think this keyword does? This is C, not C++, remember.

Comment: *"Does it mean I cannot use static inside structures ?"*. Yes it means exactly that

Comment: I want to use static because I want to keep the value of the array between function invocations

Comment: My apology. I am new in C ..

Comment: Why not declare, `static struct N Node[R][C];` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike C++ where `struct`s (which are fully equivalent to classes in terms of their functionality) are allowed to have static members, C `struct`s are not allowed to do so.

C allows you to have file-scoped and function-scoped static variables. If `history` needs to be static, make it static in a function where it is accessed, or in a file if it's accessed by more than one function.

However, if you do need `history` to be static, your `struct` becomes functionally equivalent to a single `int`, because `static` means "one array shared among all instances of my `struct`". Good chances are that you needed the array to be non-static, i.e. "each `struct` has its own `history`":

```
struct N{
    int id;
    long history[100];
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In C, a struct member cannot be `static`; you're confusing this with the C++ `static` for classes (and consequently C++ structs), where it means that a property/method is not intended to be unique to a particular instance of the class (object). Note that in C++ it also means everything it meant in C (and more) - see here for details: [The static keyword and its various uses in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c)

In C, the `static` keyword merely specifies the storage class of a symbol - if done locally (in a function), it means roughly that the variable is a global but only visible to that function, and if applied to an actual global variable it restricts its scope to the file where it's declared. For more info, see here: [What does "static" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-a-c-program)

If you "want to keep the value of the array between function invocations", then simply don't write to it in these functions; I suspect your problem is trying to design your program in an object-oriented manner, even though you're using C.

Comment: In fact you are right, I want to "simulate" OO manner as C structure since I understand Java well. Thank you for your reply.