# why c++ does not accepts static keyword in function defnition?

Tags: c++, static

I have a program where a class T has a  static function.

```
static void T::func()
{
    m_i=10;
    cout<<m_i<<endl;
}
```

When I try to add static in function definition, the compiler throws error
error: cannot declare member function ‘static void T::func()’ to have static linkage.
Why is it not accepting static keyword in definition?

Comment: Unrelated, but where is it getting `m_i` from?

Comment: m_i is just a static member part of the class

Comment: The function has to be defined in the class declaration.

Comment: yes, i'hv already declared it as static in class definiton

Comment: I'm trying to understand from compiler's perspective, why it should ever face a problem in linkage as that's not the case in c.

Comment: You must not add `static` before your method definition, because `static` has multiple meanings in `c++` and using it outside a class declaration means that you want static linkage for your function, not that you want your function to be a class member function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c?rq=1

Comment: Because this i C++ and not C. In C++, you define static in the defintion

Comment: thanks for your time guys.

Comment: Unfortunately, grammar doesn't allow to (repeat/)place `static`/`virtual`/`override` for definition of method (outside of the class).

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that the keyword `static` means different things depending on context.

When you declare a member function to be static, like in

```
class T
{
    ...
    static void func();
    ...
};
```

Then the `static` keyword means that `func` is a *class* function, it's not bound to a specific object.

When you define the function in a source file, like

```
static void T::func() { ... }
```

Then you set the function *linkage* which is different from using `static` in a declaration inside a class. What `static` does when defining the function is to say that the function is only available in the current [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29), and that contradicts the declaration that the function is available for all who knows the class.

It's simply not possible to make a member function (declared `static` or not) have static *linkage*.

---

***If*** you want to "hide" the member function from others, so it can't be called, why not simply make it a `private` member function? You could also use things like [the pimpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) or just not have it as a member function to begin with, in which case you can declare it to have `static` *linkage*.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need static in implementation, only in definition.

T.h

```
class T
{  
    int m_i;
    static int s_i;
public:
    static void func();
};
```

T.cpp

```
int T:s_i = 0;

void T::func()
{ 
   // Access only static and local variables

   // I.e this is not allowed
   m_i=10;

   // This is allowed
   s_i=10;
}
```