# Initializing GTest const class members

Tags: c++11, c++14, googletest

I want to achieve something like this:

```
class MyTest: public ::testing::Test {
public:
   const int myConstInt     = 23;
}

TEST_F(MyTest, MyTest1) {... use myConstInt ...}
```

But recollecting from Item 4 of EffectiveCPP, the initialization is not guaranteed in this manner and there is a chance of undefined behavior.

Let's say the above is **Method 1**.

I can think of two other methods to achieve this:

**Method 2**: Initializer list of myConstStr using a MyTest constructor.

**Method 3**: Make it constexpr - since the value is set at compile time I shouldnt face any initialization issues during runtime.

Which would be the correct way to go about this? Also Effective CPP is a relatively old book - Does the discussion of Item 4 still fully apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   const int myConstInt     = 23;
```

is a *non static data member* with a  *default member initializer* 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization

There is absolutely no risk that it is undefined behavior.

The initialization is guaranteed

Answer (score 0):

Post discussion on Cpplang slack , found out that the best solution would be to use a `static const` for any integral/Enum types - can also use `static constexpr` but this is essentially the same except in C++17 where static constexpr data members can also be inlined.

Additioal useful Reference: [constexpr vs. static const: Which one to prefer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125651/constexpr-vs-static-const-which-one-to-prefer)