# constexpr versus anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

What is the difference between the following 2 patterns in creating const values?

```
constexpr int some_val = 0;
```

vs

```
namespace {
   const int some_val = 0;
}
```

I'm used to the 2nd method but is the 1st equivalent?

Comment: *Why* are you using the second method? In particular, what do you think is the effect of using an unnamed namespace here? I suspect that you’re not quite clear on its effect (= nonexistent).

Comment: Unnamed namespaces would compare to `static`, not `constexpr`.

Comment: Why you have put the second alternative in the namespace? Is there any reason behind that? The title of your Q is somehow like comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @Jarod42 that would be my intention with the 2nd method. Is constexpr used primarily by the compiler to substitute the value?

Comment: Similar question: [constexpr vs static const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125651/constexpr-vs-static-const-which-one-to-prefer).

Comment: cheers @1201ProgramAlarm. The answer by AnT was useful

Answer (score 2):

*unnamed namespace* acts as `static`: linkage of the variable.

```
namespace {
   const int some_val = 0;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
static const int some_val = 0;
```

`constexpr` doesn't change that: [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SyqU9PIdN)

Now we can compare `const` vs `constexpr`:

- `constexpr` variable are immutable values known at compile time (and so can be used in constant expression)
- `const` variable are immutable values which might be initialized at runtime.

so you might have

```
int get_int() {
    int res = 0; 
    std::cin >> res;
    return res;
}

const int value = get_int();
```

but not

```
constexpr int value = get_int(); // Invalid, `get_int` is not and cannot be constexpr
```

Finally some `const` values are considered as `constexpr` as it would be for:

```
const int some_val = 0; // equivalent to constexpr int some_val = 0;
```