# A variable/data member of a class declared constexpr in C++17 is also static?

Tags: static, c++17, constexpr

I did not manage to figure out if `constexpr` implies also `static` in C++17.

I found this thread: [constexpr vs. static const: Which one to prefer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125651/constexpr-vs-static-const-which-one-to-prefer)

And I noticed this comment:

```
One more thing, in C++17, constexpr static data member variables will be inline too. That means you can omit the out of line definition of static constexpr variables, but not static const.
```

Does the logic in the comment above imply that `constexpr` also has a `static` property in C++17?

The reason I opened a new thread about this topic is to have something that is clear.

From what I managed to investigate I think `constexpr` and `static` are separated.

Sorry if the problem is not well formulated or good.

Comment: You cannot define non-`static` `constexpr` variables in the class.

Answer (score 2):

The only implicit storage property of a `constexpr` variable is `inline`, and only then if it is a `constexpr static` *member* variable.

You cannot declare a non-static `constexpr` member variable, but `static` is not implied; it is an explicit requirement.

Comment: And for a non-member variable, let's say a global variable `x`:
`constexpr x` and `static constexpr x` are two different things, no?