# static_assert not working inside class template definition

Tags: c++, constexpr, static-assert, class-template

I'm trying to define a static member variable outside the class definition. It works as intended. But the `static_assert` that I placed inside the class definition does not compile for some reason. Why?

The error message is:

```bash
note: 'Foo<unsigned int>::var' was not initialized with a constant expression
```

Commenting out the `static_assert` statement lets the code compile.

The code [(link)](https://godbolt.org/z/Wz8da9hz4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <concepts>

template < std::unsigned_integral size_type >
class Foo
{
public:
    inline static const size_type var;

    static_assert( var <= 20, "Error" ); // note: 'Foo<unsigned int>::var' was not
                                         // initialized with a constant expression
};

template <>
inline constexpr std::uint32_t Foo<std::uint32_t>::var { 10 };

int main( )
{
    return Foo<std::uint32_t>::var;
}
```

Is there a way to fix this? Or should I place the `static_assert` outside the class definition and after the definition of `Foo<T>::var`?

Note: I might have to mention that the reason for `static_assert` being inside the class body is to avoid code duplication. Otherwise, I would have to write that static assert statement after the definition of `var` for every instantiation of `Foo<T>`.

Comment: I'm curious to know: 1. Why do you need to initialize `var` outside the class definition; 2. Why is `var` marked as `inline` if you initialize it outside the class definition?

Comment: @paolo inline is there just to make it look similar to its actual definition outside the class which has the inline keyword too, Also I need to initialize it outside the class because the client will decide on the value. There are many of these variables in my actual class. And I can't pass them to the class template as template arguments because it will look bloated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inline static const size_type var;
```

That's all fine and dandy, but it does not mean that `var` is usable in a constant expression for *every* instantiation. There's the famous (infamous?) [temp.res.general]/8

> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation.
> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, or

That's ill-formed NDR; but a compiler is allowed to check. A specialisation will  not be available *immediately* following the primary definition, so while you *may* specialize to make the member `constexpr`, it doesn't save the primary template from running foul of this condition.

I'd use a trait and invert the order.

```
template<typename T>
inline constexpr T FooSizeTraitValue = 10000;

template<>
constexpr std::uint32_t FooSizeTraitValue<std::uint32_t> = 10;

template < std::unsigned_integral size_type >
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr size_type var = FooSizeTraitValue<size_type>;

    static_assert( var <= 20, "Error" );
};
```

This should give you the same ability to specialise for different types as you wanted, without poisoning the body of the primary template unconditionally.

Comment: I tested this on Compiler Explorer and played around a bit with it. I believe that it is a brilliant solution for the particular problem that I have at hand. It's also very similar to my own code that I have put in the question. Actually, I have been wondering for a while if this problem can be solved using variable templates and there we are, you showed me the correct way! Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 1):

The member `var` should be declared constexpr, and so, it needs to be initialized directly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <concepts>

template < std::unsigned_integral size_type >
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr size_type var = 10;

    static_assert( var <= 20, "Error" );
};

int main( )
{
    return Foo<std::uint32_t>::var;
}
```

See it [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb47e4f56bb491d9).

I removed the `inline` because it is not necessary.
Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41125798/8769985) for a discussion of the difference between `static const` and `constexpr`.

Comment: So you think there's no way of defining `var` outside the class and placing the assert inside the class?