# how to call a function to return a static private int?

Tags: c++, static

everyone. I have problem about the static function.

In the Employee.h, I wrote

```
class Employee

{

public:

static int getCount();

private:


static int count;

}
```

In the Employee.cpp,

```
static int Employee::getCount()

{

    return count;

}
```

But when I compile, the error shows

"error C2724: 'Employee::getCount': 'static' should not be used on member 
functions defined at file scope"

Can somebody show me how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Remove `static` in your cpp and define `count`.

Comment: What about following the instruction in the error message and remove the `static` keyword from the function definition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The static keyword and its various uses in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

The `static` in front of your member function means that "this function is static", not "returned type of this function is static", and there is nothing like "return a static type". You just return an `int` from your member function getCount(). Its value is copied from a static field but this is the implementation detail of this function, which has nothing to do with its signature. You are free to decide whether your member function should be static or not.

And for your code to compile, remove the `static` keyword from your function definition in your Employee.cpp.

```
int Employee::getCount()
{
    return count;
}
```